# Should answers that do not answer a question be preserved

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

While searching for something, I ran into the following question:

[Python - Can I access the object who call me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387756/python-can-i-access-the-object-who-call-me)

The post has a number of answers.

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2387792/2235132) reads:

> Due to a change in the original question
>
> <strike>Maybe if you change the otherFunction method signature</strike>
>
> ```
> class A:
>     def callFunction(self, obj):
>         obj.otherFunction(self)
>
> class B:
>     def callFunction(self, obj):
>         obj.otherFunction(self)
>
> class C:
>     def otherFunction(self,other):
>          print "other called"
> ```

The answer has a couple of upvotes too.

I'm trying to understand what purpose does an answer serve in such case?  Should an obviously incorrect answer that's been striked out by the OP remain there or should it have been deleted?

What should be done in such cases?  Ignore and move on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not an answer & I've deleted it.

You should use the "not an answer" flag which would get processed fairly quickly, but you can't add context. Using the "other" flag will allow you to add context, but will take longer to process.

Either way it should be flagged for removal as there's no point in keeping it around.

You could down-vote to send a message to the user that the answer's not useful, as I suspect that the reason they didn't delete in the first place was to preserve the reputation they earned from the initial version of the answer.

Comment: I thought so.  But since I keep hearing different things regarding NAA from different moderators, thought it's best to check.

Comment: So if I spend a while writing a worthwhile answer to a question as originally posed and then the questioner comes along and says "no I didn't mean that at all, I meant this", the original answer becomes worthless to S.O.?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam - really the question shouldn't have been rewritten. They should have posted a new question, but people often don't do that. However, for historical cases there's not a lot we can do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to keep answers around that answer both the old and new questions? What's the right approach if this happens in a fresh question?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam - Unless the edit is a clarification of the question (which can result in the answer becoming useless) roll back to the previous revision. If the answer is invalidated by a legitimate clarification to the question then it's the answer that has to go.

Comment: Even if the old (and now invalid) answer has merrits, it has no context, as the question has changed, hard to tell "this answer solves the question at history point X"