# Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm seeing a rapid trend towards worse and worse question quality. It gets to the point where I'm asking myself *"Why did I even help this guy? He neither has the will nor the capacity to understand the answer; I have just been wasting my time"*. That happens more and more often lately and is pretty frustrating.

It could be that this is the filter bubble effect of the tags I've chosen on my home page (mostly web development stuff). Maybe other topics aren't overrun by what I perceive as completely clueless people who ask the same basic questions again and again and again and can't be bothered with actively participating in getting their problem solved (searching, researching, posting their code, stating their intentions, listening to advice, and giving feedback).

I'm getting the feeling Stack Overflow has made a big step in the "[Mechanical Turk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk) for programming assignments" direction lately. It's always been something like that, but it's starting to get really bad now.

What's your view on the state of affairs in Stack Overflow - is your perception similar to mine? If yes, how are you dealing with it, other than retreating? If no, what do you do against creeping cynicism (because that's what *really* worries me here)?

Comment: Some of the answers to this question (though it's not the same question) is quite relevant and worth a read - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late. Personally, I do feel the quality is quite low of late.

Comment: You may be right,  but it's worth keeping in mind that humans always perceive things to be getting worse, irrespective of if they are or not; [I've filed a bug report](http://xkcd.com/258/). For example people believe society is getting more violent while actually [we are living in the most peaceful time in human history](http://www.sciencemeetsreligion.org/theology/violence.php)

Comment: @RichardTingle Maybe it's not getting *worse*, but good questions are definitely few and far between - certainly in the web technologies sections.

Comment: @Richard, that's not a matter of the current generation wrongly perceiving the state of the previous generation. This phenomenon is pretty recent (I think it started 6 months ago as far as I am concerned). I'm active in several tags, and it really seems the average quality of the questions has gone from tolerable to ridiculous almost overnight (and is not getting back up).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Exactly, that's the time frame I would go with as well.

Comment: Same experience with Java / Android. Personally I think it's ever since [The Summer of Love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/) where we decided we should be "nicer" ... with the last 6 months being a nightmare.

Comment: This reminds me of the "remember when 4chan was good" meme

Comment: In Python, even FAQs are not closed.  It seems that a _fresh perspective_ is needed every hour that a faq is posted.

Comment: When people do not remove their upvoted answer [despite knowing that the answer is wrong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252404/should-answers-that-do-not-answer-a-question-be-preserved), there is not much left to guess about the quality of the site.

Comment: Repwhores answer [faqs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354294/what-does-mean-qt-programming) and refuse to vote to close.  Oh my! internet dollars.  It's not because of the poor questions, but because of these repwhores that the quality of site is going down.

Comment: This is perfect response to [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

Comment: @devnull: if it is clearly indicated that it is wrong then the answer may have value as a sign post, to avoid others to go in the wrong direction e.g., [this answer is wrong (because it may block)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16425237/4279) but it is still useful so that others won't make the same mistake again

Comment: @devnull: how "faq" is different from a duplicate question?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Fantastic argument!  From now on, you should post an obviously wrong answer to any question so that others would not make the same mistake again.  Moreover, vote to undelete the useful post that has now been deleted by a mod.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian As an example, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350880/unable-to-find-file-or-directory-python-subprocess) -- I know you already have.  This is a "faq".

Comment: @devnull: I assume that the wrong answer is provided in *good faith*. People make mistakes. It is unavoidable. But we can avoid doing *the same* mistake twice.

Comment: @devnull: If you know about a duplicate question; why there is no close vote? Or do you want to close all "too simple" for your knowledge level questions? [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350880/unable-to-find-file-or-directory-python-subprocess) has a googlable title and I don't like the solution proposed in the comments so I've provided a solution that I consider to be better.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm wondering what happened to your _good faith_ that made you earn [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=4279)?  Didn't you want others to _learn_?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I didn't realize that the problem was [something that was not searchable earlier](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=unable+to+find+file+or+directory+python+subprocess).  I hope that the question is asked and answered more often.

Comment: Probably related and a suggested solution: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/7586) (and [meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228822/7586)). I'm not sure how effective it is, but closing many of these question is definitely a good idea. For the record, I am also a lot less active than I used to be, but there are various reasons for that. Not finding interesting question is one of them, but not the main one.

Comment: I have to agree with @devnull. I've recently come back to the python tag and it is blowing my mind. There are even up-votes for questions that make no sense, wrong answers up-voted and selected, and a reluctance to answer to comments by clarifying questions/answers. I with my daily vote quota was higher. There may well be a correlation between bad quality and tag popularity, reflected in the rise of popularity of SO as a whole.

Comment: @devnull: I do not understand. What is your suggestion? If you consider a question to be a duplicate; is there a reason not to vote to close it? Or do you want to close all "too simple" questions regardless of whether a duplicate exists?

Comment: @juanchopanza: do you agree with the part about 1. closing "faq" (too simple) questions even if there are no duplicates or about 2. removing technically wrong answers that clearly marked as such no matter what or both? Or am I completely missed devnull's point?

Comment: Throwing in my $0.02 here, but I think the problem is that SO is perceived as a first line of enquiry by people. I'm still fairly new to SE as my (*cough* totally meaningless) rep indicates, but in my question tags I'm consistently seeing the same type of *I don't really understand what I'm doing, fix my code* questions. The code in question is totally devoid of any kind of knowledge about the architecture in which it is going to be deployed. Am I to understand that I should just keep linking to the basic documentation for these people?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian If a question is an FAQ then there must be a duplicate. So I would vote to close, even if the question is otherwise good. The problem is that not enough people do the same. Removing technically wrong answers is complicated, especially if people start up-voting them. The same applies to bad questions. Too many people are up-voting bad stuff, not enough people are down-voting. It is turning into the blind leading the blind.

Comment: @juanchopanza: thank you. It sounds reasonable. Though if the question is a duplicate then it doesn't matter whether it is a FAQ; it should be closed as a duplicate. *"blind leading the blind."* -- it was so 5 years ago though quantitatively the proportion might be (much?) worse now (I won't speculate about the reasons).

Comment: @Tomalak, put that question to an SO advertiser and you're likely to hear a very surprising answer

Comment: @Garry What's an SO advertiser?

Comment: It's an entity that runs promotional material on the site pursuant to an agreement they made with the site and generally involves the payment of a fee.

Comment: @GarryVass Thanks for the eloquent definition. ;) I see what you mean, I didn't make the connection because there are generally no ads shown on my system. I'm still a bit unsure what very surprising answer they would possibly have for me...?

Comment: OH, [found this hilarious](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811526/exporting-pivot-table-in-ms-access-to-excel-with-c-sharp/23315654#comment35782880_23315654)... since when do we accept answers that MAY/ MAY NOT WORK? since when do we allow this? haha

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Are you sure it's not closer to 7 months ago?  That is, when the school year begins and there's a new group of people just discovering StackOverflow?

Comment: @Izkata, yes, it might be our own September That Never Ended. We still would have to determine what has changed last year, though. It's not like AOL has started to serve Stack Overflow as their default portal. *Wait...*

Comment: I shocked by the current [Hot Qutestion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23330100/352101).  Is this reflecting the level of SO users? I mean this is just basic mathematics, has mathematics been dropped from programming course?

Comment: "Maybe other topics aren't overrun" - they absolutely are. Just look at the C, C++, Objective-C tags.

Comment: Keep in mind, folks, that a lot of what's being seen or at least perceived here re people who don't/won't understand or research is just reflective of many dev staffs...people who aren't willing to learn and have this notion that software design and dev is this easy lunchtime nonsense any highschooler can do. Why are we surprised to see that attitude morph into a forum like this? A lot of "2nd chance" "career" schools attract "SW/computer" students because they think it's easy, but wash out when they discover it isn't. SO is an echo of that notion, IMO.

Comment: [The question's quality is dropping because of answerers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811526/exporting-pivot-table-in-ms-access-to-excel-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Should this be closed based on its subjective nature?

Comment: @QueueHammer The rules for Meta are not the same as the rules for SO.

Comment: Quality is dropping because this is SO. As more people see not-so-great questions, more people come here to post that quality of question. You know the saying, birds of a feather flock together?

Comment: In agreement with @RichardTingle's post (great xkcd reference, btw), I think that it's difficult to really ascertain whether question quality is changing based on peoples' individual perceptions. If this were really happening, I might expect it to be gradual. And if it were gradual, it would be difficult to accurately perceive. In Moneyball by Michael Lewis, it's noted that it would be nearly impossible to tell the difference between a .275 and .300 hitter in baseball just by watching, but stats differentiate them. So, I think what's needed is data based on metrics possibly yet to be devised.

Comment: @Andy That measurement could be the rate of involvement (answers/comments/rep per time unit, average rep per answer, how many days online, stuff like that) for seasoned users over, say, the last year. Also, I'm not sure if question quality can really drop any lower anyhow, it's pretty rock-bottom for the questions I mean. It's the sheer *amount* of garbage that worries me.

Comment: If nobody said this before I'd like to. Thank you for your answers. Please do not be discouraged. Even if the person asking the question might not be able to use your answers thanks to google some other people having similar issues might get help. I think it's faster to find an already answered question that might point you in the right direction than to form a new question and wait for answer.

Comment: I really love this recent one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428254/add-class-to-div-in-random-sequence-and-after-add-remove-class-to-div-in-random

Comment: If you haven't noticed, the quality of most things in life has been getting watered down, mostly due to the technologically instantaneous world we live in. Just look at music, TV, movies, fine dining, etc. The experts and people who would die for their craft still very much exist, it's just that more and more people of them are hidden behind the influx of "weekend warriors" so to speak trying to half-ass their way into or around new "endeavors". The same goes for questions here on SO.

Comment: @Bolu You are actually correct. Many universities have dropped mathematics as a requirement for a CS degree. It makes me sad too.

Comment: @Bolu That question having more than 100 upvotes discourages me so much that I almost want to quit the site. If I didn't use it for asking questions of my own, I probably would.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately (or fortunately?) the page you linked to has been removed.

Comment: There's always been schlock and there's always been artisanship, @FastTrack; history is just a great filter for the former. Ever hear the phrase "panem et circenses"? Even the ancient Romans had their Real Housewives of New Jersey.

Comment: @durron597 That's kind of inconsequent. Also, what so discouraging about 100+ upvotes on this question?

Comment: @Tomalak Because I have seen so many other questions in the last month that are way better than that one that are lucky to get 5 upvotes.

Comment: @durron597 Which one, for example?

Comment: @Tomalak For the sake of comparing apples to apples, this is not the best question I've read all month (far from it), but it is a very good **beginner** question that shows a lot more effort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441537/printing-arrays-reverse-array/22441641#22441641

Comment: Clearly, the OP is not really a question, or a good one by any standard.

Comment: Speaking as an occasional SO user, I'm not seeing this decline in quality, personally.

Comment: I blame WordPress.

Comment: @JoshCaswell maybe, but definitely NOT to the extent that it is today

Comment: If anyone cares, [this question just got picked up by Programming Reddit today](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/24vitp/question_quality_is_dropping_on_stack_overflow/).

Comment: Bitching on meta stackoverflow certainly gets you more attention than, say, bitching on freenode/##C++

Comment: I think the main problem is about fairness, the reward given to an answer of a poor question must obviously be less than an answer to a well constructed question. In my opinion we can deal with this problem by letting people decide the quality of a question, so I can +1 the quality of the question. By increasing the quality points I mean that the points rewarded by an accepting an answer/upvote to an answer of that question will also depend on the question's quality. So an answer to a poor quality question will be awarded less while the answer to high quality to answer may be awarded more.

Comment: Allow rep to go into the negatives so that these "new" users that have been downvoted to hell and back for poor questions immediately see the negative impact of their questions.

Comment: @RichardTingle no small irony that this post is a duplicate of so many others here on Meta.SO

Comment: I have noted that there tends to be a cycle of sorts, apparently based on the school year.  At the start of the term you get a lot more very basic questions, and the nature of the questions changes over time.  But it does seem that there are more very poor quality answers of late.  (I would observe that changing the "close" categories hasn't helped -- there are no longer the "too stupid to live" closing categories you could use for the really dumb questions.)

Comment: I think there are two effects at work. First, some of the complex and interesting questions have already been posed and answered here. Mission accomplished already. And on the other hand SO is a free resource for answering your homework. As long as anyone can pose a question and may get an answer it will always be like this. It would economically be outright stupid not to exploit SO in that way. Now everyone decides which questions to answer. Maybe we can just find ways of better ignoring low quality questions?

Comment: @Tomalak: The reason is simple, good questions are closed because are too wide/open or whatever (what book should I use, what's the right way/programming language to do... etc.), but on meta "we believe is the right way to handle it" and this is what happening. Based on rules, the only questions I can ask are usually "too specific" or just bad questions in general. I didn't ask a question myself since months considering usually when they are helpful, they get closed, prefer chat over the website.

Comment: Just wanted to write the same thing Fire-Dragon-DoL is pointing out. Sometimes it's hard to be very specific, but then SO peers are closing the question, because it's opinion based... but sometimes I NEED the opinion of experts - to which approach would be better, what they would recommend and so on. I don't think these types of questions are any worse by definition than very exact questions. And one more problem - If I ask a complicated question (that takes time to understand the problem) then I usually don't get any answer at all, but for some easy questions - there are many equal answers

Comment: Not only is it dropping, but the askers also arrogant and rude at times. :-(

Comment: @RichardTingle Prof. Pinker will have to review his Zero. Look at Russia and Ukrain...

Comment: @algiogia you see that's the point.  People don't realise that things like that would have been a daily occurance in the past whereas now they're massive international news

Comment: I would argue it's simply a numbers game coupled with users for whom English doesn't tend to be their native tongue and/or are unfamiliar with jargon.

I increasingly see questions by "userxxxx" types that joined moments ago for the sole purpose of asking this one (very poor) question.

As SO becomes more popular this is the inevitable trend; the only way I see of combating it (without going totalitarian and locking to only users with x rep etc) would be for users to be diligent about requiring more info and for SO to improve automated detection and surfacing of answers.

Comment: It's understandable that you feel frustrated when the OP doesn't understand your answer and you feel like your effort has been wasted. But remember that what you post will not only help OP but all the future visitors to the question who seek an answer for the same question.

Comment: The UI quality will soon drop too...

Comment: What a snooty question.  Thank God the number of snobby intolerant answerers is declining.  Take all their knowledge, put it in a basket, and it amounts to squat because the basic understanding of how to apply the knowledge is missing.  Really, only answer quality matters.  Anyone who says otherwise is hallucinating on their own bum juice.  Have the argument out in a rational setting, people who hit on question quality are always filled with self-righteous delusions of being self-made--none of it ever true.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 That's an opinion, too. Although the lame accusations are uncalled for.

Comment: @uhsarp That would help against the frustration, but unfortunately it does nothing against the problem.

Comment: @Tomalak They totally are called for.  I've yet to meet one 'bad-question' guy who hasn't been totally deluded.  "Opinions" *should* be based on facts and observations, not on greed, compulsion, and mob mentality.  It's an opinion that saying 'bad question' is mishandling a learner.  It's a fact that learning decreases and misbehavior increases when this form of mishandling occurs.  If 'bad-question' people expressed behavior that matched their statements of desire, they just wouldn't say 'bad question' at all.  In other words, what you put in is what you get out.  So, stop asking for bad ones

Comment: @Tomalak Let's rip this apart: 'Why did I even help this guy?' - Bad attitude sets a bad example; bad answer.  'He neither has the will nor the capacity to understand the answer.' - Takes two to tango.  Means you can't answer comprehensibly, also.  'I have just been wasting my time.' - See above.  You're asking, "Why do people do bad things," and describing your own bad behavior.  Do two wrongs suddenly make a right?  They did something wrong, now you will.  Then, they'll see you doing something wrong, and they will.  It's the cycle of hate and revenge, isn't it?  I hope you understand.

Comment: @Wolfpack I don't think you have enough evidence to accuse me of greed, mob mentality or delusions of grandeur. Please stop the ad hominems, they are not helping. If you've met guys like this on SO, I'm truly sorry that you've had a bad experience.

Comment: @Wolfpack *"They did something wrong, now you will."* You're jumping to conclusions. I did not say anything of that sort, your entire argument seems a lot like straw man bashing to me. Take a look through my answers, find me an aggressive, unhelpful, offensive one.

Comment: @Tomalak Bro, I've encountered you.  I've encountered people on SO.  I've encountered people offline.  I've encountered people on IRC.  I've encountered people on every forum on the internet.  These people all share the same cloak.  I'm judging the behavior, not the person.  The behavior, itself, is greedy, mob-mentality-driven, and delusional.  You should check it, if you care about yourself.  If you don't, it's your loss that these words inevitably apply to you in the eyes of anyone who witnesses you indulging in them. It's compulsive.  It's bullying.  You people are careless and entitled.

Comment: @Tomalak It's not straw man.  If anything, it's slippery slope on the 3rd turn, but on the second turn, there's no such fallacy.  I'm saying: 'This is a bad question; the question quality is slipping....'  That's a poor mentality to take towards any kind of question.  Taking that perspective is wrong.  It messes people up in their lives.  You shouldn't do it.  These people trust the community by putting their questions online, and it's a huge wrench in the gears when people get a condescending response: 'This question blows, let's close it.'  I have an endless stream of this-aint-right for it.

Comment: @Tomalak And just to illustrate the mob-mentality that "you don't have", here's 500 points for a slap in the face.  Here's 400 points for the #1 tool who agrees with you.  Here's -1 for anyone who wants to actually see the issue resolved. You know what people want to hear, but your mind is closed to even the most basic principals of psychology which completely disagree with the answers the community has fortified, and the answer you've selected.  "People have no drive or love," that's because the mentors are snooty brats with holier-than-thou attitudes who can't be asked and will troll you.

Comment: Making it harder to post is another thing - while we want people to contribute to the community, if they're not willing to register to possibly the best development Q&A site in the world, how likely are they to put effort into proper questions and answers? Why don't we remove anonymous posts?

Comment: @Ian: I understand where you're coming from, but I think most of our troubles are from registered users, not anonymous posts.

Comment: New user might have difficulty while asking the question and I think we need to guide them or support them in improving their questions.

Comment: It's the same for the C tag. I see no end of questions that start "m relatively new to C and I've been trying to make a simple unix shell for an assignment" then go on to ask us to debug their program. What strikes me as odd is that either every course has the same set of assignments, or these are assignments from a particular set of courses. Perhaps a dupe detector should pick these up, or people should not be able to post questions that the dupe detector spots until they have a certain rep or they are manually approved, rather like we do for first questions.

Comment: @devnull Your comment inspired me to post [Is answering bad-quality questions considered a positive or a negative contribution to StackOverflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254287/492336)

Comment: @sashoalm Anything that would increase traffic would be a positive contribution to Stack Overflow.  Quality doesn't matter.

Comment: @devnull The real traffic comes from Google anyway.

Comment: Other than NullReferenceException questions, I'm not seeing an unusually large number of crap questions on the [tag:c#] and [tag:.net] tags. What tags are all these crap questions in?

Comment: I've been a member of SO for over five years now.  A common pattern I have noticed is that answers are posted ASAP.  Question askers often select an answer that does not entirely answer their question.  Later answers (sometimes better ones) get no upvotes, while the quick one line snarky answer gets 15 upvotes in 60 seconds.  The newbie question asker with 100 reputation trusts all these up-voters and selects this answer...despite the quality.  Call it the "5 minute lifespan" of a question.  This "5 minute lifespan" perpetuates the poor quality and shoot from the hip answers.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey The "fastest gun in the west" issue was a problem from day one. It's inherent to the game mechanics of the site. However... things didn't get dire until roughly six months ago. (But that might be skewed perception on my end.)

Comment: But don't worry guys: Yahoo is offering to fix all our problems: http://i61.tinypic.com/2zhp9fn.png Saw this, laughed and immediately thought of this question.

Comment: SO currently has two very obvious problems that lead to quality loss: 1. It is way too easy to "protect" a question (as happened here...), that actually makes people feel controlled externally, by some random arrogant elite guys.. you probably know what I mean; 2. Closing logic (duplicates etc.) is well done, but still misses a single little thing: if your question was closed, you will not lose reputation! This is silly: thought its totally ok to give rep pts to the nice guys answering it, there is nothing motivating the questioneer to avoid such behaviour in the future.

Comment: @Frunsi Regarding your points: 1. the *"random arrogant elite guys control me"* feeling is caused by a disproportionate positive bias towards your own question. Random people with experience have a way more neutral view at a question. Having your question governed feels awkward or irritating, since you *of course* think you did everything right. However, asking a really good question is surprisingly difficult. 2) Duplicate asking need not be punished. Duplicate answering should not be rewarded (rep +0 after a question has been marked duplicate). Duplicate finding should give a small incentive.

Comment: @Tomalak "..x.. feeling is caused by a disproportionate positive bias towards your own question" - No, that is NOT the point, most of the time I do not have a problem with responses on and handling of my questions at all. But, even if this one here is "meta", just try to you step back for a moment, look at it from bird's-eye view, and ask yourself the question: why is this protected now? Why did some "random arrogant wanne-be elite guys" flagged this as protected? WTF?

Comment: @Frunsi I have no idea what your grievance with the "protected" state in particular is. As far as I can see way besides the point of my question above. Protection is a spam prevention measure, nothing else.

Comment: @Tomalak My grievance is just that I would like to have added an answer to this 3-month-old question (which shouldn't really be regarded "old", or should it?). However, it doesn't matter that much, ... but exactly these kinds of things deter people. And, among others, such things are causes for quality drops too, because that scares away the (oh well, lets call them..) "middle class" people. The important big group of "Vernunftbegabten" (average smart ppl with some talent for reasoning), ppl that are neither stupid nor foolish nor experts on SO social behaviour rules and stuff.

Comment: @Frunsi To write an answer on a protected question, you need a mere 10 points of reputation. Can we agree that if a user is not able to muster *a single upvote* anywhere then his potential answer on a particular high-traffic question is not so great a loss in the grand scheme of things?

Comment: @Tomalak You are right, forgive me, I did not see the button (I was used to the answer form immediately available..). My fault (it would be picky to start discussing UX issues here and now.. I understand why it is like it is, ...), just forget my comments ;-) Thought I still think "duplicate asking" should be punished... because it is avoidable, and punishing it could motivate users to do at least a little search or thinking before asking.

Comment: @Frunsi No harm done. :)

Comment: Almost 666 upvotes.

Comment: I've recently, in the last few months, noticed a massive increase of the "please code this for me" questions without any code provided, at least under the "Android" tag. Seems to me that many "newbies" are very lazy and don't do any research on their own, even though they say they are totally new to Android and often to programming. What those guys need is a tutorial and programming courses, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Feel like askers >>>>>>>>> answerers , and this contributes to a great amount of bitterness. At this point even The Fastest Gun In The West answers I am grateful for  because that's all I'll ever get ; questions feel to have a 5 minute lifespan - either you get an answer or you never will. (Or by the time you do, its been years and no longer matters).

Comment: @JohnCarpenter That's a bit like advising commuters to avoid traffic jam by all leaving home half an hour later. :)

Comment: And when we try to be precise about what we are expecting (not cutting-pasting wikipedia definitions for instance), we get threads to have the question closed, because it's not a good thing to say in the site, and that it "excludes" some users. This site is mad.

Comment: @Wildcopper "What those guys need is a tutorial and programming courses, not StackOverflow." Fully agree, unfortunately. Close to 100% of questions I have seen lately fell into that category. Maybe I was just unlucky. Problem is that you cannot really say it as a comment, it might be received as unfriendly and so the only way is to watch SO slowly going down, I guess.

Answer (score 482):

The question quality will continue to decline as long as we continue to reward the bad questions with answers.

I'm willing to repeat an [unpopular view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252072/749181) here: We need to stop rewarding answers to bad questions if we want to stop bad questions.

Many bad questions on this site get good or mediocre answers from well-meaning (and/or repwhoring) users. The people asking the questions go away happy: they have their answers, even if their questions are closed or downvoted into oblivion.

To stop the bad behavior, we have to stop encouraging the bad behavior. We need to stop answering bad questions, and we need to downvote the answers to bad questions. The downvote tooltip says "This answer is not useful." **Answers (even correct ones) are not useful if they contribute to the demise of the site.**

Comment: As you well know, I completely agree with you here. As I just commented on @devnull's A, I personally think no rep should be awarded to closed questions. By all means, leave them there ... just roll back any reputation. 5 people with significant reputation decided the question had no value and closed it. Take away the reward for bad behavior and see what happens.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Sounds like a great idea. Did you ever submit this as a feature request in meta? Possibly amend or extend it to: "roll back any reputation gained from a closed *or negatively voted* question".

Comment: @Denis And the post would immediately be flooded with downvotes.

Comment: @devnull: I certainly wouldn't get a down vote from my end. And it doesn't really matter, does it? It's meta.

Comment: @Denis I actually just came up with the idea :-D But I agree it would get downvoted into oblivion. We might hurt someone's feelings by taking away their imaginary internet points. Don't get me wrong, there's some edge cases where this really might not be perfect but *personally* I feel we're well past the point of worrying about edge cases.

Comment: @BrianRoach: or not… See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009

Comment: @denis Well, I might be wrong about the downvoting, but I'm pretty sure I'm right about the "Won't do it because we might hurt feelings" ... linked from that is the same suggestion *4 years ago* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions and that even proposes *incentivizing* finding dups which is also a good idea (possibly even better ... less stick more carrot, etc)

Comment: @BrianRoach See [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252011/2235132) that was downvoted into oblivion.  Reason: it committed the sin of suggestion no rep for answering duplicates.

Comment: There are existing suggestions along the lines of removing rep from an answer if the question is closed, @Denis. [Stop the gamers: neutralize rep earned on answers to questions closed within 24 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214426) is a good example; others are linked from there, and https://www.google.com/search?q=site:meta.stackexchange.com+no+rep+closed+question will turn up some others.

Comment: Does answering these bad questions really hurt the community though? I think slamming newbies for bad questions is what hurts SO. Bad ?s still are generating traffic and it really comes down to the user search when it comes to querying what you are looking for.

Comment: @BrianRoach so what about questions that have been voted to (re)open by 10-15 people, having 20-something upvotes, but are still closed by one moderator? Do we want to further punish users by taking away the rep as well?

Comment: I think you're right, but the way SO is currently gamified creates incentives to do the opposite.  Consider a person like me.  As you can guess, I'm quite new to SO.  I actually read it for years without participating because I found it too strange.  (I could edit comments, but not make my own?  What?)  When I did decide to start participating, I found ridiculous limitations like my inability to post a screenshot to support a question.  So what did I do?  I answered questions -- *any* questions -- in a desperate bid to gain rep just so I could use the basic features of the site.

Comment: so does it have something to do with earning reputation by answering?

Comment: In addition to getting regular amounts of rep for answering bad or duplicate questions, the [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badge creates additional incentive to reward these questions with an answer...

Comment: @yardpenalty answering bad questions with good answers only encourages more bad questions.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a few filters we could optionally apply, disabled by defauly:  1) don't show me questions from people who've been around less then n day; 2)don't show me questions with a score of < n; 3)don't show me questions from people with a reputation of < n.  That way, you can answer poorly received questions from new users with a bad score if you want to earn some points, or you can instead choose to surf/search for only quality ones you might actually learn something from.

Comment: @Poldie such filters have been requested and routinely rejects (it creates a sandbox environment where bad things happen unchecked). However, the entire point of my post was that we should not answer bad questions, so if we ever get such filters, I hope people will use them for good (closing, downvoting, etc) instead of to encouraging people to post bad question by giving them good answers.

Comment: For people that toss around words like `repwhoring` and `imaginary internet points` you guys seem strangely obsessed with not awarding rep for certain classes of questions. I agree with @yardpenalty not answering questions hurts SO, slamming newbies hurts SO, being flippant hurts SO. You improve curation you don't try to discourage people from asking questions that absolutely defeats the purpose of this site.

Comment: I agree with you, but on the other hand, I've seen some good answers to terrible questions that go something along the lines of: "I'm not writing your homework for you, but here's an article you should read that will help."

I think the best way to discourage people from asking bad questions is to teach the askers how to teach themselves. If someone takes that approach, shouldn't they be rewarded?

Comment: @CullenJ On a tutorial site or a discussion forum that behavior would be altruistic and worthy of reward. Within the context of SO, however, the behavior is the opposite of what is desired. The answer is likely to help only the OP, because we depends on good searchability to allow future visitors to find useful question/answer pairs. StackOverflow's usefulness to the larger community requires both sides of the equation : good answers _and_ good questions.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins That makes sense to me; I'm just wondering if we should look at it as an opportunity to turn a bad poster into a good (or at least slightly more informed/experienced) poster. Although I suppose whether they'll actually learn from one such experience is debatable.

Comment: @CullenJ I think your motives are good, and I applaud them. There may be cases where well-placed explanations help to turn a mediocre or poor user into a good one. However, we already have help documentation, Meta and Google; I am confident that most users with the desire or capacity to learn can find the information they need. The response I am advocating is directed toward the much larger horde of non-programmers who simply want someone else to do their hard work for them, and no amount of hand-holding is going to help them become useful members of the site.

Comment: Also see [Stack Overflow Book Reference Site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253391/stack-overflow-book-reference-site). Its a tool to close the poor quality questions *and* profit too.

Comment: In addition to rolling back gains from closed question, add a point or two to people who raised helpful flags. The helpful duplicate flag surely helps general SO quality, but at the moment those who create duplicate questions and answers are rewarded with upvotes, and those who do the work of the first group by searching for previously asked questions are left with only a dozen of flags per day and a couple of badges related to flags.

Comment: or: prevent answerers from gaining reputation by answering closed, deleted or duplicate questions. upvotes and accepted answers should not produce a reputation win for the answerer if the question has been closed. answerers will learn that when they see a message like "-25 your reputation for question: 'How do I catch a NullPointerAxception?' has been cancelled because the question has been trashed"

Comment: @nsfyn55 - you know what hurts SO? A flood of inane questions that result in people not being able to quickly find the answers they need. The purpose of this site is _not_ to have people ask an endless list of questions--it's to build a library of _useful_ questions and answers.

Comment: @Yawar Your close. The purpose of the site is to build a community that in turn yields a library of useful questions. When people's questions are dismissed out of hand or a first time asker is flamed for not asking the perfect question that endangers the community. That hurts SO.

Comment: Returning energy to the Internet and helping other programmers is in my blood, and yet I find myself often hesitating before getting involved with a poorly worded and unkempt question.  My limited experience has shown that there is an inverse correlation between messy and unclear questions and the chance they will appreciate my reply (e.g., with a "thank you" or an upvote).  Answering questions of these types may unfortunately teach the poster that "crime pays" (i.e., there's a sucker to be found on SO, so why bother being civil?).

Comment: @yardpenalty I don't think bad questions need to be slammed, but I have seen numerous occasions where bad questioners have been prodded to improve their questions. I think this scenario is a win for everyone: questioner learns how to ask better questions, readers learn better questioning and learns some good interpersonal skills. I think we concentrate on the helpful aspects of the site.

Comment: @Poldie I actually did some filtering a while ago (http://stackapps.com/questions/4159/stackfilter-alternative-homepage-for-stackoverflow-with-some-specific-filters) -- not sure how well this still works though.

Comment: Another Bandaid for a body with no wounds.

Comment: Your logic's inverted.  You're trying to go against solid theory that's all but set in stone: there are no bad questions.  Askers don't have the knowledge required to form good questions.  If you don't take whatever you're given and improve it (with revisions or high-quality answers), you're feeding into the cycle.  The asker will be stuck on the bad question and re-ask the question.  The question is generated naturally from some course of learning, and it will be re-asked as long as it isn't made easily reference or the resource that creates the question isn't modified.

Comment: Punishing answers is not an answer to improving questions.

Comment: "Check the FAQ for the newsgroup, do your homework or you'll get 'RTFM' as an answer or more likely end up in people's killfiles" — _a note in every high volume technical group on USENET_. I'd love a killfile for the user who asks 120 redundant questions, could have done a simple RFTM, never accepts an SO answer, never writes an SO answer and show no upvotes in his profile. In biology this is called "parasite load" and it is quite detrimental to the organism carrying it.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260087/1947286

Comment: I would say *answers* quality is dropping even more than questions!!!

Answer (score 316):

Some thoughts from a new user...

I tend to search for answers before asking and for years have found the answer I needed and never created an account. About a month ago I was struggling with a particularly ugly problem and happened to find the perfect detailed answer. I wanted to upvote the answer, but was informed I needed an account. So I created an account and then found out I needed 15 rep points. Tried to leave a comment - needed 50 rep points.

So I've kept it in the back of my mind to eventually go back once I have points. I looked into getting points by answering questions, but any that I know the answer to are either already answered or dross - or both.

Then I figured I'd just ask questions as they came up, but yet again, the answer is usually found as I'm writing up the question. I had one good one - but then realized it was better in the software's forum. Finally, just yesterday I had my first question - and it's more of a "given my unique setup that eliminates these obvious options, what do you suggest?" Which feels vaguely off topic. It hasn't been downvoted and I have some great suggestions now...but doesn't seem particularly useful to others.

I guess my point is that it's HARD to enter this community. I understand why, the idiotic questions are painful to read and the only appropriate response is "learn how to program". However, the current setup also precludes new members joining. I'm not a guru by any stretch, so my ability to answer good questions is limited. And given I follow the general rule of "research first", most of my questions are answered without needing to ask.

So, I'm left with a piddly reputation that allows for nothing. Understandable - but annoying none the same. Ah - but I CAN bug you with every droll question that pops into my head and also answer these stupid questions. THAT will get me rep easily and quickly.

You see the problem? It's extremely hard for a somewhat legit person to enter the site...but relatively easy for others willing to lower themselves to asking and answering stupid questions.

Not offering a solution - just an observation.

This was linked from another forums site - perhaps including it...somewhere...might help? http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Your reputation should not be a major concern. Once you contribute one or two good answers, you will be past the initial hurdles quickly enough. They are in place to prevent automated commercial spam and dumb "me too!" reactions. Comparing to more traditional programming forums these hurdles work pretty well. Neither commercial spam nor completely useless comments are very much of a problem here.

Comment: In some sense this is true, another upvote and I'll be able to do the same; another 7 and I can comment. Then again it's taken me a month to find a suitable question - that happened to get 2 upvotes. So, at a rate of one upvote every 2 weeks I'm looking at being able to upvote myself in May and being able to comment in August.   Now obviously this isn't taking into account other factors (a good answer tomorrow might put me over the top rather quickly). But it still points out a rather real temptation to answer stupid/easy questions because I *might* get the rep I need to do X.

Comment: For me personally - I won't care much about rep once I get the ability to upvote that original great answer...HOWEVER - I'm sure there are others who want the ability to do some other high rep action, or who are just competitive, who will take the easy road.

Comment: @Tomalak - disagree.  That's how it USED to be.  The ability to accrue righteous rep is inverse to the activity of the feckless mob.

Comment: There is always a topic to be answered. Technology changes rapidly and so does code and frameworks. If you know C# in .NET 2.0, for example, and now you have same C# but with .NET 4.0, answers will be different. It's not that your old answers no longer work, it's just a new approach has emerged since then. No longer it is knowledge of the language, it's that + available frameworks and how to use them, and all of it is changing frequently. Example: my highest rated answer (see profile) was published 2 months after the question was asked - which was answered already and has an accepted answer.

Comment: LadyCygnus gives a good analysis of how the dynamics have changed.  There's still opportunity to shine, but it is diluted.  @Neolisk, your point is encouraging; but like Tomalak, you are minimizing this deleterious shift -- which is very real, and which is the point of the OP.

Comment: @Smandoli It's been a *very* long time since I was a low rep user. Almost six years. Of course I don't know how it "feels" like these days. All I can state is: the intent behind the hurdles, the point that they seem to work pretty well in this regard and the point that it still takes no effort for me to make somewhere between 50 and 100 points a day *with fresh answers*, if I really try to (not bragging, just pointing out that it is possible to overcome the tiny hurdles that guard immediate site interaction from newly registered users).

Comment: @Tomalak, good perspective, thanks for the added insights.  EDIT: I just re-discovered the OP here is yours; lots of angles you are covering here, upvotes all around.

Comment: another thought...I'm not a guru. Although I'm really good at what I do, it typically doesn't involve a deep level of knowledge. As an example, although I've used Perl for 10 years 70% of what I've done has been file IO and regex. I might come up with a decent question or two, but I doubt I'll ever answer a good question. It's *hard* for a mid-level to get started. We care about keeping this site useful and our own Rep (not rep).

Comment: Wouldn't this site **want** mid-level users who are actively trying to solve problems to post *good* questions to challenge the high-level users? Yet it seems like this is the group that find it hardest to get started. I have no problem being a lurker getting the random question answered - all this is observation since the question was asked. Note - I might be missing something being new.

Comment: @LadyCygnus: I completely agree. Although I would love to contribute answers, I am not experienced enough as a developer to answer the complex questions that the experienced Stack Overflow users might consider valuable. Moreover, several of my own questions have arisen not because I have not done my research but because the resources I have found are either too simple or too complex for my current level of understanding. Even though certain questions may seem irrelevant or trivial to a guru, their presence is what makes Stack Overflow valuable to me at this point in my career.

Comment: You seem to assume that I think a mid-level or beginner question is a bad question. I don't. Question quality is not linked to the level of experience. StackOverflow is designed to attract people with a certain mindset, not with a certain minimum of experience. Unfortunately it seems to attract more and more people with a bad mindset lately, so there some correction must be made to the design.

Comment: If someone asks me "how do I make a bulleted list in HTML?" I'll happily answer (or mark as dup) because it's a reasonable, albeit basic question that contributes to the body of knowledge. The test of question reasonableness should be generalisability. This would eliminate "my code doesn't work, fix it" style questions.

Comment: I had the impression that if a question was marked as a duplicate you would loose any rep associated with answering (or asking) it.

Comment: @LadyCygnus: you don't, which can be seen as unfortunate since it means answering duplicates allows gathering reputation but cleaning them up does not. Of course, on the other hand, people who answered and got upvoted did make an effort so not rewarding them seems harsh.

Comment: This is a good answer and it kinda gets at the natural progression of the site: all the obvious, important questions for domains that have been available for years have already been asked.

Comment: One statement in defense of the stupid questions is that the search facilities here really suck.  I can search for a question I know I answered, using my ID as one of the search arguments, and not be able to find it many times.  And in general, when I'm looking for a "previous answer" that I know I've seen recently I can only find it maybe 30% of the time.  Google does better searching SO than does SO's own search "tool".

Comment: LadyCygnus, you are my Champion... I don't have to write the answer you crafted, and I fully subscribe to everything you wrote.  Maybe the site could offer another track to enter the community via some sort of sponsorship by power users for serious people like you or me?

Comment: I agree that there is an incentive for new users to ask and answer crap questions. There is also a perverse incentive for the rep junkies to answer stupid questions. We need to fix the rep system so its less of a game to see who gets the highest rep  and have people sit at a general level (up and down as they improve/dis improve).

Comment: @LadyCygnus Bravo! I'm also "relatively" new to SO, but since I don't use innovative framworks or experimental languages, most questions and answers are already there... so, if I want rep, I'll answer stupid questions for an accepted tick or an upvote. Gurus can keep getting their 200 rep per day, newbies don't stand a chance. Unless they game the system and therefore quality plummets. I am ashamaed of one of my answers as a Stundent of Computer Sciences but dare not delete because it represents half my reputation. :(

Comment: @Daren - I don't have any answers I'm *ashamed* of...yet. I do have one answer to a "give me the code" question that has given me nearly half of my points (it was helpful...but slightly snarky). I expect at some point the question will be closed and I'll loose all of those points (and at this current point will loose commenting privilege).

Comment: @HotLicks - 2nd on the search being bad. In all the years I used this site as a lurker I always came through a Google search; knowing the answers were likely to be good on this site. I've only tried using SO's search a handful of times. I immediately gave up and went back to Google.

Comment: @Daren - So, after the first few hundred points that gain you privileges, what good are additional points (other than as "trophies" for those that are inclined to covet such things)?  Why even have points?  I've got 20-odd-k points, and all they'd really be good for is to down-vote 20-odd-k answers.

Comment: Here's an idea:  Charge points for upvotes as well as downvotes.

Comment: @HotLicks Why wear a suit when jeans and t-shirt are fine, well oftimes you don't need the suit but it can come handy to have one, and in some context it might even be required. Rep in SO is like a suit, a vanity item but really handy from time to time. When you learn how it works, you don't value it so much, after all it's just a "suit", no real skill required except the money (here it = time + knowledge)... but people tend to give meaning even to useless stuff. One of the offered solutions was to post the rep of the guy asking the question so you could mostly ignore low reps from up high.

Comment: @Daren - Except that high-rep folks are more likely to post difficult questions with no good answer.

Comment: @Daren - as a low rep user I don't much like the idea of making it possible to filter out my questions (nearly the only way I *have* of gaining points to do anything). I understand where this comes from (these questions mainly come from people who made an account to just post that one question and leave). Maybe instead "length of time as  a member"?

Comment: @LadyCygnus I agree, was just making a point. The problem has no easy solution. I visited SO for almost a year as an unregistered user until I really needed to ask a question because I could not find any help anywhere. Then a few months passed. Then came a spree to try and get some rep to unlock privileges, (trying to answer questions, posting questions is rarely a good way to get rep, answers get 3 times more upvotes at twice as much rep per upvote) in which I helped people with low quality questions... It was a run for the best/fastest answer to try and get a few upvotes often for nothing.

Comment: @LadyCygnus Enjoyed hearing your perspective. Thank you. +1

Comment: @Daren and LadyCygnus - I too am a professional user who uses SO on a very regular basis (even before creating an account), but rarely do I do anything that generates rep. Most of the time when I run into a problem that I'm having difficulty with, I'll Google it and look for results in the official docs and on SO. Usually I find the answer or at least something close enough to be useful in figuring it out. All of the rep that I do have is from half of the 19 answers that I have posted. I always try to put effort into the answers that I give, but the results are not predictable based on that.

Comment: @Daren and LadyCygnus - I posted my first question about a year ago, and I earned the tumbleweed badge for it not getting any responses. I eventually just gave up waiting on it and abandoned the approach I was trying to use in favor of an alternative that I was actually able to get working. Last week I posted my second question, and all 3 of the views it has were mine. Seriously disheartening for someone who actually put forth the effort to ask a good question... :/   So I definitely agree that the site seems to be leaving those of us who are good-programmers-but-not-gurus abandoned...

Comment: @LadyCygnus Nice post, pretty similar to my experience as a new user

Comment: awesome post! `but relatively easy for others willing to lower themselves to asking and answering stupid questions.`

Comment: Just as a reminder: if you manage to earn 200 rep on any site, then you can get 100 rep bonus when you enter a new one, with all the privileges.

Comment: @Calmarius - Ha! This just happened to me. I wandered onto the site looking for an answer to an xslt question and noticed a huge jump in rep points. 300 rep points - woot! Watch out high-reps I'm coming for ya! ;-)

Comment: That's the thing, this community is really hard to join for users who are good at googling, and really easy for those don't bother to google or read instructions/[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)/similar resources. I was a lurker for years, answered one question, and gave up for a year before I finally got started. Then it got easier and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 196):

In my view, SO made the jump and became the zero-cost version of Mechanical Turk aeons ago. I stopped visiting the site twice in disgust, and more than a day passes of late where I wonder why I'm still around, so I suppose you can say my reaction is retreating from the stench.

Fwiw, I made a [modest feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178234/filter-to-only-see-questions-asked-by-users-who-provided-answers) a long while back — namely, **please show the rep of the original asker on the questions list** — in the hopes that I (and assuredly others if this thread or  a few other [recent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252443/where-are-the-non-trivial-php-questions-lately) [threads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) are anything to go by) can discriminate between sewage I've no desire to read and questions I might be interested in. (The reaction I got was discouraging, to put it mildly.)

Since then, SO opened the flood gates to more newcomers, which is their business at the end of the day. It began to [accept code questions without the slightest bit effort or research as valid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic), [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason) and [eventually dropped and refactored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow) various close reasons, and even [eliminated close altogether](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) in an effort to nurse these newcomers.

The problem is by no means new, btw, as evidenced by [this four year old thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions). The number of users who are full of it might be, however, if this graph is anything to go by:

[image: first vote]

(Image credit: [Daniel Renshaw](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252161/417194).)

I think it speaks mountains about the mood on the site. The site's owners should probably take note, but I doubt they will because traffic is king, quality and community be damned.

To be honest, **my very personal wish still is to be able to coexist with the sewage.** If I were able to know if a question is asked by a low-rep user instead of whichever random high-rep editor fixed his or her post, I'd be happy enough, not click, and move on, while leaving the sewage to whichever rep-whore is willing to deal with it.

What I'm left with instead is, basically, no reasonable vote-to-close option (I'd like the "demonstrate some minimal understanding of the problem" close reason back), and an invitation by the powers that be to simply down-vote the awful. And boy, do I down vote. It's almost the only thing I do of late — often times after barely reading the hideous wall of spaghetti before me. Whether it'll be useful in the long run is another question entirely — I for one do not think it will be enough.

Editing to add, seeing two of the comments from below… There seems to be a question ban that doesn't fire early or often enough. If that is the problem according **how about adding some kind of "This low quality content is not welcome on Stack Overflow" flag?**

Comment: Good grief, man: if you see a horrible mess of a question, vote to close as "unclear". That misguided off-topic reason was being abused by idiots who thought it meant they had to get rid of questions from years back that were holding up a huge pile of duplicates - that wasn't just bad for folks with the same problem, it was actively *counter-productive* to slowing the flood of new, crappy questions. Y'all never needed an excuse to close crap - the problem is that there's more crap than there are folks who can close it.

Comment: @Shog9: it's all I do of late. More often than not without bothering to read a question in full. But as I write in the last paragraph, I do not think it'll be enough to keep the dam from cracking.

Comment: Before someone jumps in with "It used to cost rep to downvote a Q and when that changed is when it started to go down" ... sure, that explains the *initial* drop. It does not, however, explain the continued decline nor the cliff off which we've plunged since the start of this year.

Comment: @Shog9: what's currently missing is a clear-cut, polite (or not so polite) close reason along the lines "Please learn to code, read the docs, google your problem, and *then* come back asking questions".

Comment: Because that shouldn't be a close reason, @Denis. Close reasons are intended to be directed at *questions* not *users*. We do have something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans - we just need it to kick in sooner.

Comment: @Shog9: Seems like a trivial fix to me: add a "User is a n00b and should get question-banned" flag… (or whatever polite variation thereof mods can think of). :-)

Comment: Any pervasive, systemic problem for which the solution is "have the moderators handle it" will inevitably continue to be a pervasive, systemic problem. There is no reasonable number of moderators who could conceivably handle a problem this size - anything short of leveraging the entire population of downvoters on Stack Overflow is destined to be too little, too late.

Comment: @Shog9 I disagree with you first comment in this thread.  Crappy questions cannot be gotten rid of easily because there are very few folks willing to close those.  That's the reason crap continues to flourish.  Make upvotes cost a bit of rep, even 1, and then things might improve.

Comment: If you believe folks are asking questions because they're trying to get *rep*, you're being a bit naive, @devnull.

Comment: +1 what @devnull just wrote, though I'd suggest -5 irrespective of whether it's a question or an answer to send the message that people able to give answers are *a lot* more valuable than those who stick to asking questions. That might *instantly* fix a huge number of problems right here and now.

Comment: @Shog9: but then, perhaps tweak the algorithm so that the question ban kicks in immediately at e.g. the third question if the net total upvotes is zero or less without having delivered a single upvoted answer. And I still stand by my suggestion from years ago to deny anyone from asking a question prior to them having gained 100 or more rep by showing they're able to deliver an *answer*.

Comment: @Shog9 You really think so?  What do you say about [this post a few minutes back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/when-to-undelete-a-question-that-was-deleted-by-the-op) urging to undelete a duplicate that was deleted by the OP?

Comment: What does that have to do with anything we're talking about here, @devnull?

Comment: You said: _... because they're trying to get rep_.  This is an example to illustrate that.  @Shog9

Comment: @BrianRoach: Based on the recent threads on the topic, I'd lean towards attributing the cliff from earlier in the year to the community collectively getting some kind of a "screw this crap" moment.

Comment: if you change the graph y coordinates from the baseline value of 70% to 0% , it doesn't look so bad

Comment: A surprising number of bad questions are asked by users with reasonable rep, though.

Comment: @WarrenDew: it's because a surprising number of high rep users have an answer / response ratio that is well under 1. :-|

Comment: Interesting chart, I wonder what happened in early 2011 to start the trend. Would love to see more data.

@Stilly.stack changing the baseline to 0 would effectively obscure what is a pretty clear trend. It wouldn't make anything better, it'd just *look* that way.

Comment: @macke: question down votes became free around 3 years ago, and kicked off the trend. But the quality was already very low then as I can recollect.

Comment: @macke: [Downvotes on questions were made cost-free](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90927) in May 2011. Ever since, we learned to properly use them, so the percentage of questions with downvotes is *naturally* increasing as we are finally making sure crap gets cleaned up automatically. Remember, [downvoted questions get deleted automatically if not answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048), and downvoted questions count against a [post ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997). **This graph makes me happy**.

Comment: so you want to be so elitist that you don't want to even read questions posted by people with low reputation, just assume that they're by definition bad. If everyone's like that, it means new people never get rep, never get answers, even to great questions, and will either generate multiple accounts to upvote themselves time and time again or leave.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You seem to be elated looking at the _proportion_.  The __absolute numbers__ might have actually gone up which would give a true reflection of the amount of crap that flows into the system.

Comment: @devnull: there are clear correlations in that graph with changes in how we self-moderate: downvotes on questions becoming free, and the close reasons being cleaned up. We are now finally using downvotes on questions the way we were meant to; e.g. downvote crap, not necessarily close it (plenty of on-topic stuff is crap). The graph doesn't show anything about volume. Hell, it doesn't show how the percentage is calculated either; percentage of *all* questions? Or only those posted in that period?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: if you follow the credit link beneath it, you'll find the data source.

Comment: @Denis: yes, studying it already; it looks like percentage of new posts. Good!

Comment: @devnull: the number of new questions in the past 6 months has been fairly stable, so it is the number of first downvotes that has been increasing. It correlates directly to the switch in close-vote reasons. We'd need a graph of close votes cast next to this to bring this out, I think, but I do believe the graph shows that people (correctly!) switched from close votes to downvotes.

Comment: But do the downvotes actually work? I mean, every crap question still gets an answer (or 4) even when downvoted just because there's always someone willing to help the retard that seemingly hasn't discovered google yet ... which means the questions don't get deleted automatically, right?

Comment: I've got to agree with @SvenT23 - a closed question blocks new answers and gives immediate feedback "you don't know how to ask a good question and here's why", while a downvote has absolutely no effect on the behavior of a new user who didn't have any points to lose.

Comment: Interesting graph. Personal anecdote: ever since we made the close vote queue something worth working on, I've been close-down-voting regularly. If I'm not the only one, this might just be some kind of "catching up" effect - the content has always been bad, but it was difficult for people to express this, since it was hard to find a bad post from twelve hours ago.

Comment: How many *good* questions are the first post of a user? Could it be mandated that a user first answer something and gain a single upvote before asking, at least in certain tags?

Comment: I have very much noticed lately; as a professional programmer, if you ask a question that you couldn't reasonable solve by 30 mins on google, i.e. something hard; you get no responses. So basically it's dead for anything other than "how do I do x in jQuery".

Comment: I'm actually puzzled about how "gimme tools to lock out low-rep sewage" and "disable new user registration to lock out low-rep sewage" actually differ in the context of increasing the qulity of SQ *questions*. I fail to see how "low-rep user" == "sewage user" ignorance would encourage the *reasonable* SO-newbies to get more involved and ask, ask, ask more (to improve both themselves & the overall question quality). But I'm likely missing something obvious here, since I only have some ~160 reps.

Comment: @lunakid: The problem stems from the fact that the bulk of the sewage comes from very new users. You're not noticing the problem yet, but you will at some point — I'll predict that much, because you're focused on delivering answers. After a few weeks or months, you'll no longer see answering crap as a distracting mind game (which it is, really: I'd wager every newcomer that delivers answers saw it that way at some point). On the contrary, you'll increasingly be wondering why you should be wasting time on users who cannot help themselves. It'll then dawn on you that most of them are low rep.

Comment: Nice graphic.  It's the natural cycle.  People who are of the correct opinion that question quality is really in the hands of the answerer, and those who call 'bad question' are flouting their own inexperienced, is at risk of being banned.  The community of people who are really best equipped to answer skillfully dwindels, and you're left with a concentration of smug people who will continue to cause problems with the perpetuation of their BS.

Comment: @Denis Hi Denis I agree with you. I created a filter to only look for questions who's user's have > 100 rep a while ago, but other people didn't like it: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162190/unanswered-questions-from-users-with-reputation-100

Comment: **how about adding some kind of "This low quality content is not welcome on Stack Overflow" flag?** Umm, because it would be manifestly untrue? The vocal meta-folk seem to not welcome it, but those actually in charge of the mechanisms seem to welcome it. Yeah, let's ensure that we keep filled up with noobs who won't or can't answer question and we'll be the most well endowed Question & Question site in the known universe; as for where the answers will come from then is kinda like the stale joke about internet startups: 1) get a big userbase 2) ???? 3) profit!

Comment: Upvoted just for the graph.  I love me some data!

Answer (score 174):

## Self-Filtering By Requiring a User-Name On New Accounts

One possible aid: Force each new user to create a user name rather than provide one for them.

The worst questions are asked by new users with default user-name of *userNNNNNN*. That suggests to me these folks are "drive-by" users looking for a quick answer without any willingness to put in the effort described in this Question.

Seriously, I suspect making the sign-up process require even the slightest bit more of a commitment would significantly improve the quality of new users and questions.

Comment: Why fool around with usernames?  Make them enter a 42-digit prime number in order to complete the sign-up process.  Huh?

Comment: @devnull Ironic comment, coming from a person who bothered to devise such a clever and creative username.

Comment: I actually agree with you here. A vast majority of the terrible questions I see every day come from exactly these people, who appear to have picked up the framework (Spring Framework / Hibernate) with no idea how its actually supposed to work, and then dump their highly offensive code all over the front page and expect people to fix their problems for them

Comment: "Raise the barrier of entry a tiny bit" is a very good suggestion. I had a professor in university who was in charge of the mandatory 2nd semester group programming course who made a short, written java test a requirement for attending the course. This was justified as neccessary for evaluating the knowledge level of the students, to be able to better separate them into groups. He admitted later on that the test was mostly to filter out people who had no real interest in programming, as about a third of the students who signed up for the course didn't even show up to the test...

Comment: @l4mpi Exactly. I'm not suggesting actively filtering new users but rather **self-filtering** by requiring some bit of effort on their part. Requiring them to invent and type a user-name is a good first step. The equivalent of my suggestion for that teacher would be requiring potential students to submit the bit of Java code but never bothering to look at the submissions. Merely making the submission is enough to self-filter out the utterly uncommitted persons.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. It would have made zero difference to me. I looked at SO many years ago, and mostly ignored it simply because it seemed too academic for my needs, where I had primary interest in solving business problems through automated processes. I've returned to SO in the past couple months due to finding a problem related to this thread _in other similar forums_. This time, I joined; and the "username" was completely irrelevant. After 40+ years as a programmer, I doubt I could care less; and I suspect that others with similar background would mostly feel the same.

Comment: @user2338816: I don't think that Basil suggests that this will be a perfect filter.  However a simple filter that reduces the problem significantly is a good idea I think. And the fact that it would have made zero difference to you is actually good - it's a sign that it wouldn't be a significant barrier to people who would be an asset to SO (unless you're saying you only post low quality questions).

Comment: What would stop people from creating user names like ";faiohjdlakjfadlkh"?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Nothing would stop a person from creating a user name like ";faiohjdlakjfadlkh". And how would that be any worse than "user5929393"? Even even a minority of "drive-by" users are deterred this minimal effort, then job done.

Comment: I didn't say it was worse. My point is, the amount of effort required to create a user name is the same as the amount of effort to bash on your keyboard randomly with a stick. Which is only *slightly* less than the amount of effort required to compose the crap questions you're trying to eliminate with your proposal. I don't see a user name requirement changing anything...the hurdle is just too low.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I never said my suggestion is a panacea. If it helps at all, it helps. I still wear my rain jacket even if I forgot to bring my rain hat. The point is that user-naming is one low hurdle that puts no stress/workload on a serious user while possibly keeping out some of the least serious people. Besides that, my suggestion was truly meant to stimulate similar ideas on how to raise the quality without burdening the well-intentioned and without becoming elitist.

Comment: New users are already required to register before asking a question. They are then presented with the "How to Ask" page and have to scroll to the bottom, check a box saying they read it, and click "Proceed". Considering that the "drive-by" users you mention *already* do all of this, I seriously doubt making them choose a user name would discourage them.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot You keep missing the point that there is no reason to *not* try a small step such as this suggestion. If it helps even occasionally, then we are better off with no burden on the serious user. Like the other naysayer, "devnull", I laugh at the irony of your having put in the effort to create such a distinctive user name.

Comment: I think it would be a waste of developer time because it would do essentially nothing to stem the tide of crappy questions. But that's just speculation; there's no way to know without trying it. 42 others agree with your proposal so far; perhaps you could make it a full-blown feature request. I of course agonized over my user name for several hours before settling on one ;)

Comment: I like this.  If it takes only 5 seconds to get an account and start posting, it kind of adds to the "do it for me now" mentality.  Raising the bar for a "minimal profile" sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: What about, if instead of a user name, you instead had them answer a short quiz? Especially for those with rep points below, say 100 (and thus this would still apply to myself since I think I'm *just* getting the hang of this). Could be as simple as "What type of question is appropriate for SO? a) Can you fix my code? b) Is Perl better than Lisp? c) How do you write a loop in Java? d) Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color? (the 2nd highest voted in HTML)

Comment: A filter to separate kind of user is a good idea, not to exclude them (they will leave by themselve if,only interested in their own little problem even not to say thks to answer, other don't take care of their selfy). Think to people that enter to the domain (i personnaly don't know java but could handle simple issue) and want to learn by sample/problem, they certainly have dummy question at first. The formulation and effort is, i imagine, better and they will rise their level for next question, passing the "filter" if the test could be redo. This also mean that filter is by domain (and sub).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes, difficult, "...there's no way to know without trying it", I think there's no way *with* trying, either: so little change, in so high noise of so many other factors. After all, said quality level already fails to correlate (being "steadily falling for no clear reason") with the binary value of offering a default user name or not. (Basil, will I get spanking for my stupid name, too? I actually upvoted your answer! ;) But then, to be honest, I started placing bets on the "naysayers", too...)

Comment: What @BasilBourque is saying is the sign up process is too automated at present and requires very little effort. If the sign in process required you to fill in a few mandatory fields (including username), then this would act as a deterrent to those who can't seem to be bothered to string a simple sentence together when asking questions.

Comment: this is a **GREAT IDEA**.  fantastic thinking, Basil.  of course it will be totally ignored by SO.

Comment: Perhaps a more useful filtering, like a short quiz on the SO FAQ? However, I'd expect the first question after the quiz was instantiated would be "What are the answers to the SO FAQ quiz?". (Yes I realize this is a bit of a Catch-22 (but as catches go, it's the best there is))

Answer (score 91):

Here's the two examples discussed in this post:

## https://answers.unity3d.com

## https://www.parse.com/help

---

An excellent reference point here is the Unity3D forum (at answers.unity3d.com)

(I am or was a top ten member.)

Unity is very important commercially as it is now the main game platform, and the "answers" site used to be fantastic -- and indeed, very important commercially.  Since, like many companies, Unity's stance was "oh, uh, we offer utterly no support because ....... we offer a Forum!" (Fair enough, it's a commercial decision.)

**It's now complete crap and everyone with serious questions, has, abandoned it.**

The site is now just riddled with the lowest possible quality questions.

If you're an SO user, and you're concerned about the "future of SO", I encourage you to just click on that link to, well, see the "future of SO" (as sad as that sounds).

Even if you're not a game engine programmer, or involved in software, just click on the link, and click "newest questions" to see the recent flow. Again even if you not a software engineer, you will immediately perceive the really, really notably low, remarkably low, quality of the fluffflood of questions.

For a few years there, many **mods would scream "Just delete bad and duplicate questions"**...

but **nobody did it**.

(And then ... who knows if it would make any difference if mods had done so?)

You can see literally years of discussion on it here,

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/432710/meta-unity-answers-is-degrading-.html

and many other meta discussions there: long-time top mods just giving up, etc etc.

Indeed, if you bother to read through or glance through some of that material, it is a **case study of a forum going to the dogs**.

(I have no idea if this is, or is not, happening to SO, of if the "mechanisms of failure" are the same.  I offer it as a fascinating reference point; an example of a once popular and excellent QA site which has gone to hell.)

Notice on that site ...... sundry proposals made by desperate keen users, as the site was slowly going to hell.

Notice proposals of every variety ...... technical, social, etc ..beginners sections, advanced sections, moralistic rules, actual legal remedy, etc etc.

(It's actually really - you could use the words "quite sad" - to see the decay from vibrant members desperately suggesting something, to, eventually, people saying (I quote) "fuck this" and leaving, to eventually people simply not showing up.)

Fascinating tidbit:

If I'm not mistaken, due to the insane popularity of Unity3D, that site is (I'd guess) the largest example of "A QA forum gone to hell."

Notice the overwhelmed Unity staff members (who consistently tried to do the best job possible before the Fall) - it's possible, people here on SO probing in to the whole issue, may wish to ask them questions, or whatever.

It's worth noting that the Unity site "is now dead, functionally" means: hence, if I post a serious advanced question, quite simply, nobody sees it. The flood of "ridiculously low quality" questions is overwhelming.  So the site is not usable, not functioning, you can not get "answers" there.

(It costs something like US$2000 a year to be a professional Unity user; as a curiosity, it's actually *commercially significant* that the forum is now deadfluff.)

An interesting phenomenon:  (I don't know if there's some equivalent here on SO).  For awhile at the beginning of "the fall". More serious users would sort of PM each other "there's an interesting question here" regarding worthwhile questions. However I'd say this has just been abandoned; most people have given up and the fluffflow is just totally overwhelming.

Note that Unity3D, as a topic, in inherently "dangerous territory for fluffflow." The whole idea of Unity3D (if you're not a software engineer) is that it makes the very difficult, quite easy. Amazingly, you get brand-new programmers trying to learn programming, I mean from day 1, with a 3D rendering physics game engine ("!!"), which is kind of a recipe for disaster in terms of the QA site aspect.  So, that issue tends to make the "answers.unity3d collapse" more of an extreme example; perhaps you don't suffer that so much on SO, I don't know.

{I think - I'm not an expert - the sort of moral equivalent on SO is "fuckers asking homework questions". As far as I can see on SO, those of you who "actually care", a pretty annoying issue is the FHAHQ issue. I guess a similar thing on answers.unity3d was "absolute beginner programming questions unrelated to Unity as such." Anyway, it might help with the thinking here.}

My personal takeaway from the whole affair?

## Social solutions will not work.

Sad but true.  If someone on the meta discussion realises "Hey, we mods must _ _ _ to solve the problem!"

**The simple reality is: it Will Not Happen.**

The ONLY solutions are technical solutions.  i.e., all new questions are simply plain deleted after 2 hours unless 4 of 20 top-ranking mods certifies the question is original and worthy ..... or whatever.

Social solutions do Not Work. Proof, click to the Unity site.

{But see my caveat below.  It is simply factually the case that SO, like say any Western Government, is now an I.S.M.O. ..... an Incredibly Slow Moving Organisation.  It's inconceivable that anything Radical (say - "eliminate membership," "make all pages bright pink," or whatever) will be tried. You might as well suggest a Western Democracy would try fast, aggressive solutions. So, the issue is settled. Click to the unity site to see SO's future.}

---

**And here's a contrary example, with an equally bad outcome!...**

Consider Parse.com, which is becoming wildly important in many aspects of mobile computing. They have their own QA forum. Now, the owners TIGHTLY CONTROL the forum, so there is NO crap content.

Result ... nobody likes or uses the forum.  :/

It's tough ...

---

## And for a complete scientific analysis, with diagram...

Amazingly, this question actually totally explains the dynamic, which ruined the above two sites:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/294884

Regarding SO being ruined in the same way, you can simply place bets on when it happens. There is - absolutely - no cure.

(SO could **aggressively** try different strategies, to at least try to find a cure. Nobody knows what the cure is: you can trivially write down a list of **aggressive** ideas which could be **aggressively actually tried**. For example, it might be that you simply must vote on a post if you are even an unregistered visitor, it might be that "registration and membership" has to be completely eliminated form the SO concept, it might be that only the 3 highest ranking members on the whole site can vote on posts, it might be that ALL posts are automatically eliminated after 36 hours unless a high ranking member approves them, it might be that you simply can't have a ranking unless you use an RSS tool to constantly monitor posts, it might be that you must eliminate 10 weak posts a day to have a score over 5k -- etc etc -- it's easy to think of aggressive ideas.  But - simple fact - SO is now an incredibly slow moving organisation; **nothing like this is going to be tried**. It's just that simple. [There would be a huge bizarre panic by owners and 'constituents' at any aggressive ideas, like eliminating posts, blocking users, adding an "advanced" section or whatever.]  It's simply a fantasy to believe anything aggressive will be tried -- you might as well hope for a modern Western democracy to try radical aggressive ideas on problems. So it's not going to happen. You can count the days until SO meets the same fate as the above two examples.)

Comment: answers.unity looks a lot like a Stack Exchange instance, is it actually based off of the [se] platform, or is it only a cosmetic similarity? Also, would it really be so bad for [main] if so many people ***stopped*** asking questions on it? It's ***the good questions*** that matter, not the junk ones.

Comment: hey cup - I have no idea about those technical issues, how it is implemented.  two years ago you could ask on there and get long informative answers immediately - but now everyone with a clue has deserted the site  :O  TBC on "unity" ... zillions of people are ASKING questions.  But (a) they are incredibly low quality and (b) everyone with a clue has deserted the site.  also (c) because of (b) nobody bothers asking good questions anymore.  it's no longer an "expert" site.  the last year or so I tried once or twice to ask an important question, and simply nobody notices it in the crapflood

Comment: https://twitter.com/bartkevelham/status/396590659303649282 ;)

Comment: If I remember correctly @Cupcake, they were originally using the SE 1.0 engine, but at some point they switched to a clone.

Comment: Also Bart regarding Parse - there's literally a comment on there somewhere "this site is useless, I'd ask on SO, but it's becoming just as useless" - Heh (not funny I guess)

Comment: I don't yet have as dark a view of SO given that there seems to be an actual concern (by community and mods) for quality, as expressed all over this question. That seems to be completely absent from the sites you've mentioned, or at least isn't as visible. But yeah, we need the community to step up and keep taking care.

Comment: Hi Bart - no, tragically, on the contrary. There was years of intense discussion and desperate debate on the Unity site, about how to "save" it. Eg You can see literally years of discussion on it here, http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/432710/meta-unity-answers-is-degrading-.html  SO is now at precisely the place Unity was a couple yrs ago, with many vibrant Meta discussions about how to save it.  Anyway - I leave it to you.

Comment: someone has already said this but if **the community wants** a "not enough effort" close reason **why doesn't SE implement it**?

Comment: HI meHow - the answer to your question is simple: SO has become a mature, slow-moving organisation. Just like a Western government. It's impossible to see them ever now "quickly changing" something to "have a go" and "see what happens" - it will never happen.

Comment: @JoeBlow - SO is THE BEST PLACE TO GO FOR ANSWERS!!!  It's magical!!  The company I work for just started a company account for that reason.  I know it's painful for some to deal with people who aren't as smart or as knowledgable as they are.  But, while some do no research and just ask questions, some of us really do research our problem if we can.  Sometimes, we just don't get it.  Sometimes management is sitting on our shoulders for it NOW.  I've been programming for over 20 years and I'm still a newbie.  Continued....

Comment: ... Continued from above - I've been tossed around from database development to embedded development to desktop development to client-server development to web development and now to mobile development.  You'd think that with all of this experience I'd be really knowledgeable.  The truth is it's not that easy to judge whether someone is asking a BAD question.  Some people even go so far as to say there is no such thing as a BAD or DUMB question.  I still think SO rocks!!!!

Comment: @JoeBlow - Oh yeah!!!  I almost forgot to say "YOU'RE AWESOME!!!"

Comment: There is no such thing as a dumb question if you have an awesome avatar image!

Comment: I like the idea to limit the top reputation you can get until you do often an action, I would add if you don't take care of the site back to 0 rep

Comment: Say @JoeBlow, want to give it a try? http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/245901-Official-How-Can-We-Serve-You-Better ;)

Comment: hey @Bart, thanks for the pointer to that corporate post from unity.  I left a sarcastic comment there.

Comment: Every single thing discussed here in this Question, it's Answers, and the many many Comments is old-hat. Every problem raised here has come up before in the mid-80s in relation to Usenet Newsgroups; any type of forum that gains a reputation as being useful is doomed to an eventual death-by-newbie. Unless all of the bad, duplicate, and do-my-work-for-me questions can be **ruthlessly** eliminated, there is no hope for any site, forum, or "bboard" — it will eventually die as the experts abandon it.  AFU (alt.folklore.urban) was ruthless but was still overwhelmed by clueless newbies.

Comment: Totally agree 100.0000% with everything Stephen just said.

Comment: As someone who has recently had to re-tag a lot of questions to [unity3d], I understand your concerns. Most of those questions are dreadful. You could dedicate an entire Stack Exchange site for debugging Unity code...

Comment: George - you should see the answers.unity3d site.  ouch!

Answer (score 86):

It isn't the quality of the questions that is dropping. That is just a symptom.

**It is the quality of new visitors that is dropping.**

A wise person once said on the [Usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet):

*"MSN users are going to make AOL users look like Kernel hackers!" - Wise Usenet User*

Well, they finally found Stack Overflow!

I did some quick research on [Closed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-down-voting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal). The numbers aren't pretty or promising, but they illustrate who these personalities are and a *profile* of what they are about.

Comment: Yeah, every third 15-year-old in the world pictures himself as an ace programmer, just days away from creating the next great viral app.  But those a-holes at SO won't answer his questions (at least not rapidly enough), and he resents that SO is holding him back like that.

Comment: "MSN users are going to make AOL users look like Kernel hackers!" ROFL... I find that about 1 out of 10 questions from 1 rep users actually suggest the user will at some point ask good questions or give good answers.

Comment: *hey illustrate who these personalities are and a profile of what they are about.* maybe some of those mythical big data analytics gurus that stackexchange employees that I keep hearing about should use that data to do something about the situation?

Answer (score 75):

I'm an Android developer.  There are certainly a lot of stupid Android questions on here.  I suspect it has a lot to do with the fact that the official Android Developers Google Group is moderated, and the moderators have been asleep at the keys for at least a year, meaning that no new members can post.  Worse, their group description specifically recommends people come here to ask basic questions:

> If you're just starting with Android application development and have a beginner-level question, consider asking it on Stack Overflow.

Yes, folks... companies as mighty as Google are actually crowdsourcing their tech support to Stack Overflow!

Comment: https://developer.android.com has all that is basically needed to start programming for android, at least if you know programming before. That should be enough for starters. It is not the task of a company to run a teaching site for total newbies.

Comment: Google can run their business however they like, but I would think they'd want to actively support developers on their own platform.  And if it's not Google's task to run a teaching site for Android, it's definitely not Stack Overflow's.

Comment: BTW, I agree completely with your comment on the original question about how SO is gamified. I wouldn't be able to use much functionality at all if it weren't for having written a number of  quick, decent answers to some slightly silly questions just to get some reputation.

Comment: @kap A company may not be obliged to run a teaching site for total newbies, but if they do, it's a very good thing for themselves, and shows a lot about their commitment to a platform. Microsoft runs the [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/), which IMO qualifies as "a teaching site for total newbies". It drives more people to learn their platforms, so more people start using their technologies and they gain more presence in the industry.

Comment: Google should have said "If you're just starting with Android development and have a beginner-level question, SEARCH FOR IT before asking it."

Comment: StackOverflow has always done a better job than the Google Groups at managing noise and duplication. Google should be applauded for admitting that. No company I know is a Jack of all trades and a Master of all. Even Microsoft, for all the things they do better than Google, had atrocious search on its own technical documentation that couldn't match Google's search of the same. As to the business of running a "teaching site", Google made a $$$ deal with StackOverflow before it made them an official Android site, but I doubt the term "teaching site" was ever used. There was already an ok one.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, BTW, I think that's simply the reason, no mysteries here: vastly improved Google visibility, that can explain it alone. The dynamics at which SO has started to dominate every Google search result list is very noticable, and likely correlates with that also noticable lack of similarly increasing resources to keep SO tidy. (I mean, simply: just too many people hase been coming and asking. Including myself, for example.)

Comment: The forum changed their moderating strategy, [it didn't take a year to be overwhelmed with spam](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/mo_djBs5_EY)

Answer (score 59):

### Too Localized

Really miss this one. But perhaps it was "too mean", and it applied to "too many bad questions".

Afterall, the mentality suddenly switched at that point from "close it and move on" to "answer it if you want, or move on" with the outlook that more answers leads to a better site.

Let's face it, the rigidity that left with Jeff Atwood needs to make a comeback. Some of the wording used which was considered too harsh is now clearly in need of helping us fight a wave of help vampires.

These users (the help vampires) expect that with a simple "how do I write facebook" question on Stack Overflow they will be able to create the next big thing. For many obvious reasons that does not work. However! As long as it meets certain minimums the question may be able to stand under current standards.

It is almost ironic that a majority of software needs are outsourced, and that many in-source experts end up solving outsourced problems on Stack Overflow.

In my opinion the closure tool is ineffective! Shocking, right? Who knew.. apparently nearly a quarter of a million users it turns out (hundreds of thousands of close votes in the review queue times a minimal 2 - probably higher).

Bring back the vague closure reasons, and close all the things. Increase vote to close weights. Impose limits on question asking for new users. Raise the gates! Board the windows! This is a call to action.

Comment: I'm glad you wrote this.  On several occasions I have seen where someone with 'goal eyes' was in way over their head.  They get an idea and slug EVERY few lines of code out in questions.  Sequentially.  I don't know if these apps finally reach the commercial stage or not, but if they do I suspect they are WORRYINGLY unstable.  A localized problem solved in Stack Overflow is fine, but we're talking whole apps from womb to tomb here.

Comment: +1 for the "in-source experts and up solving outsourced problems". I've always found that irony very sad. You can set your watch by SO when a certain time zone hits 8am, and when you comment "We don't do your homework for you" the reply is that ... it isn't homework.

Comment: "It is almost ironic that a majority of software needs are outsourced, and that many in-source experts end up solving outsourced problems on Stack Overflow." - bravo

Comment: Indeed, however the irony can turn to anger if you've ever had your role "outsourced".  I have wondered why I bother to help users from that certain time zone when all they are doing is taking jobs away from my fellow countrymen.  I'm an idiot, I think.

Comment: @GarryVass I've also seen far too many questions where the asker starts off with 'Continuing on from my previous questions on this piece of code...'

Comment: @sevenseacat, I think I could reverse engineer the full functional spec from this sequence of questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/users/3479588/user3479588?tab=questions&sort=newest  :)

Answer (score 42):

Just be more selective in the questions that you answer.

Ask yourself these questions prior to answering

- Has this question been asked and answered before?
- Does the questioner show that they have NOT tried to resolve this issue by themselves already? By searching SO and google , and even bing to find the answer?
- The question is very poorly written, and doesn't include enough relevant information, or includes too much useless information.
- Is the question very narrowly focused, and the answer wouldn't be helpful to anyone else that views the question/answer in the future?

**If you answer any of those questions with a yes, don't answer it. And even vote to close the question and/or downvote if necessary.**

---

If the question is good, but you feel the questioner won't understand the answer you give, doesn't mean you shouldn't answer the question. Since there will likely be many more people who view the question for years to come, and they will very much appreciate your answer, even if it goes beyond the questioner's abilities.

Comment: Cool. I've been applying this strategy for a few months now. That lead to my voting to close a lot of questions and answering a lot less. And you know what? This trend is increasing. I now pass 90% of my time on SO closing questions, and *they keep coming*. It wasn't always like this (and I'm not *that* old on the site anyway).

Comment: I've been more selective. It's called not visiting SO. That's why your solution here is a total non-solution.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Of course they do keep coming. SO is/was exponentially attracting more people that are new to the site and don't know what they do

Comment: This is happening to me too.. my activity was mostly answering questions up until a few months back and I gained a lot of rep really quickly.. now I'm close-voting >90% of the time because the quality of questions is just terrible.

Comment: That's what I've been doing for years, which is why my rep is low, I am usualy extremely picky. And people hold that low rep against me, "you have lower rep therefore you're no good" kind of attitude is common on this site (and other sites having rep systems).

Comment: This answer is an insight for personal sanity.  It has little to do with the OP.  Suppose we want BOTH personal sanity and a well-functioning SO?

Comment: If everyone would do this always then maybe it would work. But then you got those other meta discussions like "Why is SO so hard on new users". And for me, I try to do this, but it's hard. Sometimes is just easier to answer a question than to look for a duplicate. And in fact, I think over 99% (*) of the questions are asked and answered before on 'the internet' and at least 90% (*) on SO itself. I think those numbers are just too big to turn the tide by downvoting all of them. ((*) Both are guestimates)

Comment: @jwenting  Where are you encountering that attitude exactly, can you clarify or elaborate? If that attitude really exists then that sucks, but I find it hard to imagine that anyone would seriously hold low reputation against someone.

Comment: @Pekka웃 just read the questions on this very theme and you'll see that many blame it on low rep users. I've had people send me snide IMs claiming my answers or comments have no value because my rep is lower than theirs too.

Comment: @jwenting nobody here blames it on low rep users per se - there is just the fact that low quality questions also usually tend to be low rep users... if you look around on Meta, you will find every suggestion to somehow discriminate against low rep users countered by someone stating that low reputation isn't automatically an indicator of lack of technical expertise, for exactly the reason you state. To assume otherwise would be silly. Re IMs, that sounds really unusual. I'd be super interested in seiing an example.

Comment: I don't want to have to be selective, I don't want to have to trudge through this quagmire, I want to be presented with only questions that are worth my time... and yes, it's a dream.

Answer (score 42):

A necessary intro to my answer: (derived from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late))

> Basically there are 5 camps of users on Stack Overflow:
>
> 1. The "caretakers" who want to keep the site clean and with good content.
> 2. The "help vampires" who flood the site with bad/duplicate questions who only want their question answered and care nothing for the site.
> 3. The "victims" who'd answer just about anything. Whether or not this is done for reputation is not particularly relevant to my answer, and yes, I realize people who answer just to help and people who do so just because they want as much reputation as possible are probably significantly different, but the effect on the site of both are similar.
> 4. The ones who no longer care.
> 5. The "good ones" who actually ask good questions.

**In short**, #2 and #3 are controlling the content and we need to rethink Stack Overflow's (Stack Exchange's) design if we want to stop them.

Let's assume we're in:

- Camp #1 or
- Camp #4, presumably previously in #1, but will happily move back into #1 or
- Camp #3, after having given up on #1 realizing you'll never change it, but will happily go back or
- Somewhere in between.
- And maybe with a hint of #5.

By the above assumption, we don't want #2 and #3 here. But the problem is - #2 and #3 sustain each other. There's already enough of #3 on the site (with hopelessly too much rep, whom we can't exactly just ban for this) and too few #1, with a constant flow of #2 (banning them eventually is good, but that doesn't stop the questions they actually get to post, or the constant flow of new ones), such that we'll most likely never 'fix' the site.

This problem will just get worse with more #3 and #2, worse #3's, and #1 becoming #4 and both #1 and #4 leaving, or #1 becoming #3, and, with less and less left to moderate content, the site will start spiralling downwards a lot faster. Eventually #5 will leave too as they get bombarded with low quality answers or no expert left who's able to answer.

This is, IMO, a design problem. Allowing anyone to post a question to the general public and get an answer within minutes is a great idea in theory, but I think what's happening to Stack Overflow shows the problem with it.

A few specific suggestions from my side: (or "let's put all my radical ideas in one place")

We need to:

- Put questions (and possibly answers) (at least those by low-reputation users, e.g. < 1k rep, or possibly even more) into a review queue **before** getting seen by the general public.
- Err on the side of closing questions we don't think will be useful.

  With regard to not having appropriate close reasons, we should have a constant dialogue with regard to the close reasons and what should or shouldn't be added or removed, and Stack Exchange needs to err on the side of listening to the community on this one.
- Punish (recently asked) closed questions.

  If reputation is a measure of how much the community trusts you, shouldn't we remove reputation from users who don't know what's appropriate? I personally don't trust someone with the site who doesn't follow the guidelines. Downvoting isn't sufficient here, as often users don't downvote decent, but wildly off topic, questions (unless we start downvoting these more).
- Raise the standards of what's acceptable.

  For one thing, close and downvote "debug my code for me" and questions about an error without a complete, minimal example (even if the problem is in the shown code - [broken window theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) and all that, and it should be **minimal** - anyone posting their program without a sufficient attempt at removing code not applicable to question should have their question closed).

  Perhaps more arguable, questions showing no research effort need to be closed and/or heavily downvoted, even if they are otherwise useful - [broken window theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) and all that. I like the idea of keeping useful ones on the site and not allowing OP to see them, or at least making it more of a hassle for them, in some way or another, but my attempt at suggesting that was shot down fairly conclusively.
- Detect and punish bad reviewing more and better.

  It's no use we make Stack Overflow more review-centric if we have a bunch of robo-reviewers just approving everything.

  On the flip side, we could (and maybe should) also reward good reviewing. Finding and/or checking duplicates properly is a lot of work, and not many people do currently. If we put new questions into a review queue, and get rid of robo-reviewers, we may need to reward reviewing to deal with the numbers.
- Make registering take longer / more effort.

  Presumably the lazy people will be less inclined to create an account here if they have a few hoops to jump through before they can do so.

  We may even consider including a short what's-on-topic introduction, including having them review a few selected posts correctly to ensure they get it.
- Focus more on closing duplicates and making canonical posts of which we can close things as duplicate of.

  Duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad, duplication is bad.

  It's bad, okay? Sorry, but I don't think anyone will ever convince me otherwise.

  Although having different explanations of the same thing isn't necessarily duplication (although these should be on a single page). Nor is different ways to find the same information (i.e. closed duplicate questions as signposts, although I think this deserves some reviewing).

  Having dozens, hundreds or even thousands or more posts running about asking minor variations of pretty much the same thing is bad.

---

Another post in vein, I assume...

Comment: You left out the camp of people who enjoy helping others and don't care too much about rep (or is that part of #5 for you?).

Comment: @Tomalak I consider that somewhere between #1 and #4.

Comment: Hm, that does not help me much in positioning myself.

Comment: "Raise the standards of what's acceptable" - a thousand times this. Too many people interpreted "be nicer to noobs" as "a new user wrote something that's not blatantly offensive, thus he must be upvoted"; regardless of the actual quality of the post. But fear not, if all is lost for SO we can still start an area51 proposal for a `NoSuckOverflow` where `RTFM` is an actual close reason...

Comment: I like the idea of rewarding people who find duplicates. With the proper incentive, that might be one direction where "rep whoring" might actually do something useful. It's a fine line though, and a hard-to-hit one. (I've seen it myself: Digging up the proper duplicate & proposing it costs time and earns no reward, even more so as several people have to agree on the vote, i.e. the question must have enough screen time for this to happen, and in the mean time somebody writes down the obvious answer, gets accepted and the line moves on.)

Comment: Considering those "with hopelessly too much rep", it implies that 'rep' is not a very useful metric for anyone. Is it known when that became true?

Comment: @user2338816 It's useful to some extent. I'm sure any 100k+ user has a massive amount of programming knowledge. Although one can also get a fair amount of reputation by mainly answering questions many would consider basic - I did for a time. Only the disillusioned would see it as synonymous to community trust - there are a few 100k+ users whom, based on what they answer, I wouldn't even want to trust with the privilege of voting. I haven't been here for too long, but I imagine it's always been this way.

Comment: You missed the "I want a quick answer to my homework".  A lot of the newbie questions are so detailed in scope, that it looks like a copy/paste of a class assignment. At the same time the questions being asked shows a fundamental lack of understanding of the concepts

Comment: @Noah That sounds a lot like #2. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dukeling very similar to #2 --  Might be a subclass of "help vampires", but the questions are rarely bad/duplicate. I just view them as lazy.

Comment: @Noah In my experience, lazy questions are often / mostly bad/duplicate. Perhaps we have different definitions of "bad". In the broader sense, I'd view that as any question that has justifiable reason to be downvoted and/or closed (which includes it not having any / much future value).

Comment: One issue around duplicate questions is when question "foo" is asked for a specific software version X. New question "bar" is asked, and seems similar to foo, but mentions version Y. Just pointing out the potential duplicate as a curator, especially if the reward mechanism gave rep for this, would not address the needs of the person asking the question. They need to know whether the previous answers are still true for version Y. Especially when the previous most-voted "correct" answer is "you can't do foo [with version X]". Looking at SE as a whole this issue may apply to place, time etc

Comment: Good luck with punishment.. It just proves one more time, that points, reputation, karma etc is just a game. You can't ask 100 good question per week, but it's very easy to ask 1000 stupid/easy questions and as a result you will have low rep for people (who is not sitting here all the day) asking only good question, and higher rep for people with lower quality, because they just do more here (upvote, write useless answers for useless questions..).

Comment: Regarding the "review queue", unfortunately we are already lacking reviewers so I am afraid we would be overwhelmed pretty quickly :x

Comment: @MatthieuM. The close vote queue is currently the only one that's swamped, but the bad questions would essentially go into the new queue instead of getting a close vote eventually, and low quality would similarly go there before getting a flag. Perhaps we'll need to implement this together with rewarding / punishing reviewing better, in which case the added numbers should be no problem. Or, with a much firmer grip on the quality control, people should quickly realize that [so] isn't an "anything goes" site any more and the new low quality quantity should decrease.

Comment: @Dukeling: and despite being swamped, it still take 5 close votes and one user can only vote 40 times a day :x

Comment: @Dukeling I like your categorizations, but disagree with your approach to #2 and #3.  I don't think you want to thwart them, but rather change the system to use their rep-whoreness or laziness to motivate them to help and not hurt.  For example, if you got rep for being the first of 5 votes to close as a dup, then you'd get a lot more interest in closing as dups rather than copying answers from the dup'd question.

Comment: @ChrisGerken I don't think much constructive can be done with laziness (i.e. #2) (yeah, I know, something about programmers being lazy). Rewarding reviewing could work, at least until we eliminate #2, leaving #3 with not much to do, not to mention raising reviewing standards, which should leave quite a few banned from reviewing.

Answer (score 36):

Today, I tried signing up as a new user, using a different e-mail
address than I normally use, to see what comes up and try to look at
it through the eyes of a real first-time user.  How they find out
about Stack Overflow, I don't know.  Maybe they've already tried
Googling for answers to other questions, and they notice that Stack
Overflow questions come up a lot.  Maybe they hear about it from
friends.  Maybe they are students and their professors are telling
them that this is where they should go for help, instead of bugging
the professors.  (If that last is the case, it definitely seems like a
problem, but how to squelch that is a subject for another discussion.)

So they decide they want to ask a question, and they sign up.  The
first page they see is the "About - Stack Overflow" page.  Here's what
they see:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack
>   Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together
>   to build a library of detailed answers to every question about
>   programming.
>
> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum.
>   There's no chit-chat.
>
> Just questions... and answers.

Great!  They've got a question, and they'd like an answer.  So this
seems like the right place.

> Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are
>   primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion
>   rather than answers.

Still OK.  They can't get their code to work.  They need a fix, not an
opinion.

> Don't ask about...
>
> Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
>   Product or service recommendations or comparisons Requests for lists
>   of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc. Anything not directly
>   related to writing computer programs

The first item here really ought to dissuade those who just want to
copy-and-paste their homework assignments into the question box.  Other
than that, though, askers who would ask questions that a lot of us
consider "low-quality" haven't seen any reason to be dissuaded.

So then there's the second page.

> We'd love to help you, but the reality is that not every question gets
>   answered. To improve your chances, here are some tips:

This sends the message that these aren't "rules" or even "guidelines",
but rather "tips on improving one's chances".  And the information
they really need to know isn't on this page; they have to follow a
link that says "Our community is defined by a specific set of topics
in the help center".  Sounds a bit like legalese; and on a page that
is claiming just to give you "tips" to "improve your chances" of
getting a question answered, I can understand why someone might not
see the need to follow this link and read it carefully.

If there really is a problem with question quality, then I think the
site needs to make it clear, up front, what kinds of questions are
acceptable.  The "About" page needs to be less inviting, and clearer
about what SO's mission is and what kinds of questions it's for and
isn't for.  The rules for what are considered "good" questions should
be presented as such, even if they're not absolute hard-and-fast
rules, but they should not be presented as mere "tips to improve your
chances".  Things like "Questions asking us to recommend or find a
tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic" should be
presented here, and should be one of the things users need to read
first, rather than be on a separate page that they get to via a link
that the site doesn't make it clear they need to follow.  If questions
must be relevant to other people besides the poster, that needs to be
clear up front.  And if questions from people who are new to
programming and who don't fundamentally understand it yet aren't
welcome here, that should be made clear up front, too (politely).
There should be something in bold letters that says that pasting in
your homework assignment without showing any effort of your own is
unacceptable.

Starting off with a long-ish list of rules may seem less friendly, but
to my mind it's far superior to let people know right away what the
purpose of the site is and what's expected of them, than to make it
look like their participation is welcome and then slap them.  The
latter is what makes SO look negative, or, to quote someone from a
different forum, "intimidating and arrogant".  I do think that if we
start by making the rules clear, then we should try to downvote or
close only questions that clearly break the rules, and give leeway in
less-clear cases (and keep in mind that when we expect them to do some
research before asking, others may not have as good an idea as we do
how to go about that).

Comment: +1 It is a great idea to "impersonate" a new SO user like you did! However, you imporsonated one that is interested in what SO has to say before you ask your question. This is a biased assumption. A user that has a goal in mind can ignore *a whole lot* of text that they did not ask for (think the many "are you sure" dialogs that are simply clicked away before the user read the prompt properly). These intermediate steps get into their flow. They have a question in mind and want to write it down as quickly as possible. Most of them won't read more than the first few sentences of the "About".

Comment: +1 for pointing out that we need to have clear, to the point and objective rules. Look at Reddit for example. Every sane subreddit has the rules written on the right side, so visitors immediately know what is accepted, what is not.

Answer (score 34):

A lot of the reasons (that no one seems to be talking about) is that a lot of the good questions have been asked already. Remember that the great question you asked/answered a while back. Well, now it'll never be asked again (if it is, it will be closed as duplicate).

Have you ever had a good question, then googled it and seen that it was answered a few years back. This is fine, and this is what Stack Overflow was meant to do. It's just now a lot of it has been done.

Also note that on the newer Stack Exchange sites, there are great new questions (hot network questions always has something that interests me). That's because they are new, so new questions have not been asked already.

To show this, I looked at your top questions, and they are from 2008 - 2010. I find it unlikely that you have gotten worse at asking questions, so I can only assume that the good questions you've had have been asked by you in the past or other people in the past.

Comment: A) There will always be new frameworks, languages, techniques, applications to ask questions about. It's impossible to have all thinkable questions handled. B) You'll see an *enormous* skew towards answers in my account. I'm asking a question only if I'm really, *really* stuck with something, and that happens very rarely. For the smaller part because I have a bit of experience, for the larger part because I have the determination to find out myself. I'd rather read the RFC and the language spec than ask a question. I'd rather search and try for 5 days than ask a question.

Comment: @Tomalak A) true, i'm not saying that good questions will ever completely dry up, just that in general there are now fewer good questions than bad questions. 

B) how often do you find the answer (maybe on stackoverflow) and not need to ask a question, this agrees with my point.

Comment: Quite often, actually. I agree that *someone* has to ask these questions (even simple ones, because "simple" is not correlated to "bad"). What I'm missing of late is the determination to self-improve.  It seems to be epidemic in the industry, if you look at the top answer in this thread.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm sure that lack of self-improvement has always been the case, its just stackoverflow wasn't mainstream enough so only 'die hards' used the site. so now before there was die hards with good questions, now there are die hards without good questions (already been asked) and other people with worse questions. Though if those worse questions weren't asked, stackoverflow would be pretty inactive.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted or why this answer wasn't given to the why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late thread. Of course there are new technologies but the bulk of low quality questions are about the existing technologies about which most things have been answered, so naturally there are fewer good quality questions on those subjects. Yes there are SO mechanics that need refining, but the overall reason for both these threads is simply that the good users cannot ask many more good quality questions leaving lower experience users to dominate with asking poorer questions.

Comment: As another user with rep in the low hundreds, this represents my perspective as well.

Comment: This is exactly the same effect you see in Wikipedia in terms of new good articles over time.  Yes there are new technologies, but that won't be as many questions as there were when stackoverflow began.  You would see number of good questions per week decrease over time as an inverse logarithmic curve.

Comment: As I replied to another answered here, technology is changing, answers become out-of-date. Yes, it was easier to gain reputation back then, because nothing was basically asked, but it does not mean it's impossible to gain reputation now. If only we can deal with those "bad" questions.

Comment: I think people are missing puser's point: within a given language or framework, questions will **inevitably** start as broadly good, then gradually the "easy" questions will stop as they get answered, leaving only the esoteric and the poor-quality. Yes, a new language or framework will start the process over again.

Answer (score 30):

At the risk of sounding like a broken record, I want to remind everybody that SO quite recently decided to abandon "*Not enough effort shown*" reason for closing questions.  We had quite [an active discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason/216677#216677) about it.

As it stands now people can ask questions without doing any research first.  Nothing stops them and community does not want to shut down such questions. I would venture a guess (without any statistics to support it) that the problem is not that more low quality questions are posted than before, but that they have much longer life span.

Downvoting post from users without any earned reputation serves just for letting frustration out, nothing else.  Pure homework dumps are protected by the rules and, therefore, have a chance to attract someones attention and become quite legitimate.

There is an argument that sometimes bad question get good answers and that's what SO is all  about: to be the repository of good peer-reviewed answers. Future knowledge seekers will find these bits of useful information and would't care what actually prompted them.

Be as it may, bad questions still lower the plank and bring whatever standards we have down.

Comment: @PM - "Downvoting post from users without any earned reputation serves just for letting frustration out, nothing else" - this isn't true. The automatic post-ban kicks in if no-rep/low-rep users get their questions downvoted.

Comment: @BrianRoach - Interesting. Didn't know that. Where can I learn the details from?

Comment: I don't remember using google search and finding a bad question with a good answer to be a solution to my problem. In other words, such Q/As are rarely a valuable resource.

Comment: @PM77-1 This was the original from Jeff http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294 and there's one from a current dev talking about improving it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252534/302916

Comment: @BrianRoach - [Interesting indeed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers). Thank you.

Comment: @PM77-1, as a side-note, the generation that's taking up development now likely has no clue what a 'broken record' sounds like.  When was the last time anybody heard a broken record?  So your metaphor, however apt, may be wasted.

Comment: @GarryVass - So I dated myself, didn't I?  It seems to me that "broken record" expression is used even by those who saw turntables exclusively in DJ booths.

Answer (score 29):

I'm sure it's been thought of before, but what about a short period of time (say 15 minutes) where any question asked by a new or low-rep user goes into "limbo" where people with more experience than the asker can flag it as a duplicate (if needs be), block it from being posted (until the asker clarifies it, or another user edits it to be clearer) and so on. This removes the instant satisfaction of getting an answer for your problem without first checking to see if it's been solved and/or taking the time to write a clear question.

The question might be available to answers in that time, but if a user-who-should-know-better (i.e. with high rep) chooses to answer it without checking for problems (dupes especially), then they would gain no reputation for their answer.

Comment: The limbo idea is interesting.  How to automate no rep for answers "without checking for problems" seems tricky.

Comment: @AShelly Well I figure that the problems would become apparent later when the question was flagged for being a duplicate, or for low quality and so on. It wouldn't be automatic, but would happen when users declared the question to be duplicate/badly-crafted.

Comment: Or taking the limbo idea a step further. Simply start all questions as closed and don't open them for answering until enough people vote to agree that it is a good question.

Comment: @MartinSmith unfortunately, while that would indeed be effective at deterring bad questions in popular tags, it would also catch perfectly good questions about niche technologies in the crossfire. I prefer nevan's approach.

Comment: I like the limbo idea. At first it sounds like a lot of work for the reviewers (the queues are unmanageably long already) - but it might just as well reduce the number of review tasks. Take a bad quality question by a new user. It can possibly get into 3 queues "First Posts", "Close Votes" and "Low Quality Posts". But in the meanwhile, other users will edit it in an effort to improve, generating "Suggested Edits" review tasks for a question that might be closed or deleted soon. Also, they attract bad answers which go into the queues as well. Putting the Q in the "limbo" would prevent that.

Answer (score 25):

As someone who pretty much only gives answers (and comments), the only point where I'm not happy about closing a question (and thus "killing" the answers) is when it's a duplicate. The "original" might already have hundreds of points to itself, and it gets hard for even a very well written answer to beat that. Which is a shame, because quite often, those well-voted answers can be rather short and with very little explanation - answering the question (great) but not really moving the asker forward in understanding.

A clear example of a bad question is when there's 10 answers, three sentences each, in five minutes since the question has been posted.

The repwhoring is the worst when you're really only starting out. The reputation system is great in allowing relatively well working community moderation, but when you're joining the site, no matter your experience in the field, you have to prove yourself first. Which means you'll be answering any question that comes up and you can answer. You don't get any reputation for a successful close vote - and yet, it takes 3000 reputation to even do that.

Now that I've got the needed reputation to influence the site more, I'm mostly answering questions that aren't answered fast enough, or that have bad answers. It's much more satisfying (even though it yields less reputation) to answer a good, tough question. Downvoting, vote-closing, flagging - it only really gets possible once you cross a certain rep threshold, and it brings little "rewards" - and yet, answering the question in three sentences and getting even a single upvote means at least some reputation.

I like the suggestion that questions that were closed within 24 hours of asking should mean removing all the rep people gained from answering the question (and of course, reimbursing the associated downvote costs).

It might also help to give points to helpful flags, close votes etc. Or maybe even just showing the amount of helpful flags the given user has in his "signature" - that way, you could easily see that someone who gave hundreds of helpful flags is endorsing a question, perhaps leading to more consideration and recognition?

The fact that people with less and less skill will be joining the field is rather obvious. And in a way, it's a good thing - if frees the hands of the more advanced programmers to do more important things (including making more and more tools for the less advanced programmers, to improve the overall productivity of everyone). Fighting this is like fighting the industrial revolution. It really isn't any different from being a carpenter and being outraged about "those new table-making machines" that "steal your job".

That said, Stack Overflow shouldn't be the go-to site for the simple stupid questions about basics, not really solving any interesting problem. Perhaps it's the time to create yet another site, specifically for people who want to help others grow, not just help them with one specific problem they have? As is easily seen by the amount of answers to "bad" questions, there's plenty of those answerers on this site already. Let's give them a new playground - I'd join that too. Answering interesting, complicated problems on Stack Overflow, and helping beginners grow on Stack Playground. And in the end, perhaps that'd end up shaping more good questions for SO in the future. Instead of closing the bad questions outright, you'd move them to the new site, where they'd be dealt with accordingly, transferred with their answers and points - in the end, you'd see how much rep SO users got on good SO questions, rather than how fast they are at answering a question that just appeared. The reputation system there would probably have to work a bit differently, but that's for another discussion :)

Answer (score 23):

There are multiple reasons to this.  I'd say that some questions would always be of low (poor) quality.  It depends on the users what they do (or attempt to do) in order to improve the quality.  However, neither of the following helps:

- Jumping to answer questions that have been answered scores of times.
- Refusing to VTC obvious duplicates (regardless of the quality of the question).  Often you'd find several users answering a *FAQ* who have the privilege to VTC.
- Defending a poorly written, vague, and incomprehensible question.  Choosing to answer by saying: *it seems that you want such and such so ...*  Unfortunately, even extremely high rep users tend to do that.

It boils down to *internet dollars*.  *We* are responsible for the deteriorating quality and only *we* can help improve it.

The fate of [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252011/2235132) that proposed no rep for answering duplicates does demonstrate what people want.

---

Users [would shout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327633/python-access-a-variables-value-in-the-calling-stack-by-name?noredirect=1#comment35721162_23327633) that a certain question isn't a duplicate.  Subsequently, they would [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23327959/2235132) based on [one of those in the referenced duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8856111/2235132).

[Another faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336893/python-explanation-of-operator-tuple-unpacking) that has been answered scores of times would take a couple of hours to be closed as duplicate.

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326643/how-to-get-1000-digits-after-the-dot-in-python) that has been asked several times would have one single vote to close after 1K views in a day despite the comments referring to at least 3 questions that answer the same thing.

And these are not isolated examples.  These are the norm.

That itself speaks volumes about the quality of the site.

Comment: Are you suggesting getting rid of reputation whatsoever? Because I've been considering that lately.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I personally think no rep should be awarded to closed questions. By all means, leave them there ... just roll back any reputation. 5 people with significant reputation decided the question had no value and closed it. Take away the reward for bad behavior and see what happens.

Comment: @Brian, that solution is indeed tempting. I don't think it has a lot a traction in the community right now though, considering other posts.

Comment: Of course not, the bulk of the "community" appears to be more interested in imaginary internet points than the site's quality ... hence the problem :-D

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi There is absolutely no will to close questions as duplicate.  Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326643/how-to-get-1000-digits-after-the-dot-in-python), for instance.  It has my lone vote to close as duplicate despite citing 3 different questions that answer the same thing!  Rep-whores bring the quality of the site down.

Comment: @devnull, +16? Holy <expletive>.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, rep whores would not let you close a question.  There are times when SO tends to suck for this reason.

Comment: @BrianRoach I'm sure you might have seen [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions/).  One of the answers that proposed no rep for answering duplicates is the lowest score answer!

Comment: If the repwhores decide to vote to reopen just to save their points, we could find ourselves vastly outnumbered in endless close/reopen battles. Given that, perhaps [Tim's approach](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252534/749181) may make the most sense: cut them off at a level where rep doesn't play a role.

Comment: *"Choosing to answer by saying: it seems that you want such and such so ... Unfortunately, even extremely high rep users tend to do that."* - Guilty as charged, though I really try to avoid that (also in self-defense, as these kinds of questions often very quickly devolve into an interactive debugging session that takes hours to complete). Deliberately not taking the bait can be hard, occasionally.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Another [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268357/why-does-bool-and-not-bool-both-return-true-in-this-case) which was amusingly not noticed by anyone to be an obvious duplicate!  And this would be +63 Holy ________.

Comment: Wow. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326643/how-to-get-1000-digits-after-the-dot-in-python) already has a reopen vote after finally being closed.

Comment: @juanchopanza As they say, the same question often needs a _fresh perspective_.  Given that this has been answered several times, the urgency for a _fresh perspective_ is even higher.

Comment: Answer to duplicate question had upvotes......

Comment: +1 closed questions give no rep for answers. I would still answer some downvoted questions unless a specific duplicate had already been identified. It may take less of my time to answer than to find a duplicate. I may see a question that is vague to anyone outside the relevant domain but clear to me what is being asked or needed, so I answer it. I used to be a moderator on a site that has subsequently sunk for poor questions (or rather lack of good questions, and to some extent SO and cousins may be to blame for an exodus) and later, overwhelming spam, so I empathise with the problem here.

Answer (score 22):

I wonder if it isn't just a case of "preservation bias"?

As Stack Overflow (and the web at large) has amassed answers to literally millions of recurrent questions, people who are smart enough to do a Google search have been able to tap into this resource to get their problems solved without asking anyone's help. I for one have been a Stack Overflow member for three and a half years, but only ever posted four questions – at all of the other numerous times I came to it for help, someone else had already asked about my problem, and a third one had provided a solution.

In fact I'd reckon that today any reasonably smart person with an "average" problem can search and find answers by themselves. Therefore there's a world of questions that get answered without ever being registered (e.g. by being posted to Stack Overflow or other site).

With the middle ground all but covered, questions will virtually always come up from the extremes:

1. Very difficult and/or novel questions from very smart people, who did look for references, but couldn't find any;
2. Trivial problems from very stupid people, who couldn't bother to (or didn't realize they could) look it up by themselves.

The state of mankind being what it is, it's not hard to figure that type 2 questions will come up much more often than type 1.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a tombstone inscription, but I definitely go with the reasoning.

Answer (score 19):

As I started to participate in SO, I was astonished and delighted that some problems which was keeping me away from bed for a half of the night were being solved even in a matter of seconds by more experienced programmers. That's really, really great. But on the other hand, when eventually I decided to try to help somebody else, the same thing that I had perceived as something great, suddenly turned pretty ugly for me.

Here I was, a new user which wasn't even allowed to comment someone's question or answer, trying to return the favour, help somebody else and gain some rep too. Because English isn't my native language, it usually takes me a bit longer to write down what I mean than it takes the other users. I had multiple situations, when after a minute I was already late and there was even more than 5 answers pretty same as mine. The funny thing is that, that these simple questions were often answered by users with reputation of 10k-100k+.

Now, somewhere above there has been used a term "rep-whore" addressing people who are answering low quality questions. The way I see it, sometimes it's the only questions left for new users to answer.

The other thing is that, it's a little bit frustrating when you see questions asked few years ago like "how does sth work" with several hundred thousands views and hundreds of upvotes just because it's a common issue and someone simply got lucky to be the first person to ask. No wonder people make a lot of duplicates on purpose and ask questions without trying anything on their own

Answer (score 18):

hmm, bring back the homework tag, then automatically close and delete anything tagged as such 5 minutes after it's been posted. By that time the person asking the question will have gone away, planning to come back a few days later to harvest the solutions to his assignment only to find that there's no trace of his question.
He'll likely not even wonder what happened, just assume he forgot to post here in the first place.

Comment: +1. Add a close reason called "Homework", I'm sure we can come up with pretty wording for it, but in short, it's lack of effort + useless in long term (used to be "too localized").

Comment: @Neolisk "easily answered by using documentation available to you" (aka your coursenotes and instruction books). "destructive to the community" (giving kids homework solutions is bad for the profession in that it causes a mass influx of unqualified workers). I'm sure there's others.

Comment: None of this will happen. SO is now an incredibly slow moving organisation.  It's completely pointless talking about radical, "let's try it!" solutions.  It simply won't happen. You might as well discuss time travel or aliens.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm not saying it will happen (or at least happen soon), but that it's something that would help solve the problem. If nothing is done, things will only get worse. Even if it takes months of debate, if it helps solve the problem it's worth taking into consideration.

Comment: as far as my memory goes, there was such a thing in earlier days. Though I do not know why it has gone, I can make up a reason myself: First, you never really know whether it is homework or not, it is just a suspicion. It is unfair to treat a question like you describe solely based on the perception of somebody else. Second, the fact that a question is related to homework should not disqualify it at all. The primary skill that any student must learn is to find ways to solve a problem. SO is obviously one. What really disqualifies a question is if its scope or quality don't fit.

Answer (score 15):

In my opinion, users of Stack Overflow are more willing to provide small feedback to gain extra reputation points rather than send the user to read a manual.

It is no longer a place for developers who have problems but for beginners that learn how to code.

Once I had this discussion about [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) on Stack Overflow. The conclusion was, why do I have to read a manual when I can go to Stack Overflow and write a simple question to gain an answer. Not even bothering to google it.

The cause of that is that Stack Overflow has became more popular for common questions.

A solution would be creating another Stack Exchange site where simple/trivial or well-documented questions could be moved.

The simplest solution is the easiest. We can downvote the answers and close the question. This could give a clear signal to the community what is valid for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's sad but it's really true - "It is no longer a place for developers who have problems".

Comment: We aren't yet to the point where good questions get crowded out - the basic questions get answered, and so do the hard ones.  Who knows how long that will last, though...

Answer (score 14):

Over time, a drop in question quality is unavoidable for the simple reason that, at some point, all of the good questions will have been answered.  For example, the C tag currently has 139,000 questions. So how many good questions are there about a language that has about 30 keywords and maybe 150 standard library functions?  Are there really 500 good questions per library function and 2000 good questions per keyword? I don't think so.

I think that inevitably, SO will be the victim of its own success, as all the good questions are answered. Future newbies that are smart and motivated will find the answers that they need with simple searches, and won't have any reason to post questions. So that leaves you with...

Answer (score 11):

I'm currently reading the Android and Java forums, but I'm amazed at the number of questions I see along the lines of - 'my application crashed with a null pointer exception'. Usually there's some code, a stack trace that clearly identifies the line on which the NPE occurred, yet the posted code has no line numbers! So you're reduced to making a guess at the possible causes of the NPE.

But let's face it, these types of problems aren't hard to diagnose.
I suspect that people asking these questions have little idea of how to debug their code, set breakpoints, run the app in debug mode. Life must be very difficult for them without being able to do this.

So the questions are usually straightfoward to answer, but the OP will have learned nothing, and would be far better off learning how to do basic debugging.

Comment: As an Android developer on StackOverflow, my wish would be that every time such a question got asked, its author's account got flagged by the system, and each flag would result in an additional 30 minutes delay before anything posted by him would get posted publicly. To clear such a flag, the system would then require the poster to watch a tutorial on how to use logcat, post a logcat with his original question on StackOverflow, and possibly diagnose his own problem by reading logcat himself.

Answer (score 11):

### The problem I see

I see *very* few new users whose first post is a question show *any* effort. They, as [Tim states](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252534/1424875) are here for financial security and social class (even though, in my personal opinion, they in no way deserve it). We should **step back and compare this to a scaled-up version of [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) criteria.** Clearly, the target of new sites coming out of Area 51 (and a target I feel *should* apply to Stack Overflow) is:

- A decent flow of questions per day. We're above and beyond this in most tags, and this is one thing I believe we can afford to sacrifice.
- Percentage questions answered: 76% as per Stack Exchange [explore sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) page. This is not acceptable for a beta or a thriving site. Lowering the number of crap questions (or temporarily making deletion more readily available for fairly experienced users, on questions) should help drive this up, as well as my proposed solution below.
- Avid users: We have plenty, but we should strive to see more *new* ones that are truly dedicated (that is, perform cleanup regularly, not just rep whores). This can clearly be addressed by encouraging cleanup and allowing avid, dedicated users to stand out more by decreasing the amount of noise.
- Answers/question: 1.74776889452. Decent, but could use work. I suspect many questions are crap that gets a rapidfire answer.
- Visits/day: Not considered here, but it's fairly sufficient

### My proposed solution

I'm proposing this as my *personal* take on how to solve the problem. It obviously will be a tradeoff, and may sound radical to some.

I propose to place **a moratorium on the posting of questions by new users**. At first, only 5 reputation need to be gained (from editing posts *well* or giving an answer and receiving an upvote) it would be sufficient to post. This is on the basis that the site does *not* have an oracle built into the codebase that can provide answers for free. Experienced users have questions as well, and *good* answers from new users can help lighten the situation.

While there may be some users that have a genuinely good question that would appear to be shut out, they should be capable of answering an existing question *or* editing posts, if they really would be expected to put in the effort to ask a question, monitor comments, and act upon answers by accepting or commenting.

Due to the issue of robo-reviewers, it could be beneficial to check new users' suggested edits more thoroughly as the current edit queue is not overloaded, while the closevote one is, which this idea is designed to address.

Users that work by editing *well* or answering questions decently are not likely to be the kind of hit-and-run people that dump a question and abandon it. Granted, their posts may be maginally above crap, but they still come out marginally beneficial in the end.

### And what about rep-whores?

I've considered myself at one point a slight rep-whore. From what I've seen, for me, I've answered FAQs due to the awful signal-to-noise (S/N) ratio making it difficult to find a *good* question to answer in a given tag, let alone a popular one where the S/N ratio is even more immense since new users posting crap will just dump a tag with the name of a language. Therefore, addressing this problem of posting crap and the awful ratio of good posts to crap posts can help address this.

Please comment with criticism or feedback. Thanks!

Comment: requiring rep to gain from edits / answers will most likely flood the site with lame attempts to "break through" to Ask Question page by posting senseless stuff or suggesting senseless edits. Even if 99,99% (heck even if 100%) will eventually fail, this will make a tough load to handle. I can imagine thousands monkeys blindly and rapidly copying text from "known good" answers into whatever question comes them to mind. Wanna review stuff like that?

Comment: @gnat This is true.  But playing devil's advocate:  Forcing them to look for answers so they can answer questions in order to gain rep might go a long way towards getting users learning how to search first before asking.

Comment: given that this would come at price of others having to discover and cleanup plagiarism, I would say that sounds too much pain for too little gain

Answer (score 10):

I know this is *not* what Meta wants to hear, so consider it a thought experiment.

You guys know the saying about one definition of insanity being trying the same thing over and over, and expecting different results?

SO has spent the last 4+ years trying to eliminate all the bad questions, trying to discourage people from posting low-quality questions, trying to weed out "bad contributors", trying to discourage people from asking questions, basically.

Apparently it hasn't worked. If anything, the typical question quality is worse than ever.

What if the problem isn't that people are getting dumber or more helpless or more inclined to ask bad questions?

What if SO has just become hostile to people asking questions?

That would certainly discourage all the developers who actually make an effort, who don't want to be [treated as idiots](https://twitter.com/IrisClasson/status/461192831064096768). Those people, the one who write interesting, high-quality questions, would just get their answers elsewhere, or do the research to find the answer themselves without posting the question.

Meanwhile, the ones who *don't* give a damn, who put absolutely no effort into anything, who just want answers served on a silver platter? *They* aren't discouraged by being treated like idiots, by being told that their questions are *wrong*, that that they should have followed this 8-step programme before asking their question. So they keep asking questions.

What if, in this endless chase to scare away "stupid people asking stupid questions", you have inadvertently created a hostile atmosphere which discourages those who actually had something to contribute from contributing? While, of course, those who have nothing to contribute don't give a shit that they're unwanted. They're used to that.

You've got Meta questions asking why high-rep users are answering fewer questions, you've got Meta questions discussing the plummeting quality of answers.

And these days, [Google](https://www.google.dk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=KdFqU-q_G-We0QXpoIDgCQ#q=stackoverflow+sucks) supplies an endless list of posts by disenfranchised users who have given up on the site.

Maybe, just maybe, the answer to all this is not "keep pushing to make SO even more hostile to contributors". Maybe we can't ever really get rid of all the bad questions, but we could at least stop scaring away the *good* ones?

Comment: Eh, most of the "stack overflow sux0rs" posts have been around for years. They're not anything new. "_They_ aren't discouraged by being treated like idiots..." is certainly an incisive point, however. Do you have any specific recommendations for moving forward?

Comment: If only this post contained an actionable suggestion. I agree with you in principle, especially the culture of aggressively closing questions for soft reasons seems to have given birth to a class of Wikipedia style exclusionist mods who enjoy having the power to be more right than others. That's unfortunate, *even if* a well-written newbie question will not get any flak from them (to the contrary, people will be very positive), apparently it helps fostering fear among new users.

Comment: While I don't disagree with the basic premise - SO *has* become too zealous and bureaucratic -  most of the posts in that Google result are super lame. Have you checked them out and looked at what they argue, what kinds of questions they saw closed and what happened?

Answer (score 10):

## YES, TOTALLY !

### I have the increasing feeling that Stack Overflow becomes uninteresting.

**LOL "Mechanical Turk" ;)** - But it's very pointy. I think Stack Overflow now suffers from its own good reputation. People have got the impression that Stack Overflow is a strong community where "every question is answered". Therefore, it attracts now a lot of people who have no idea and just "ask", while in fact they hope that someone will do their work.

**There is now really a lack of really good questions** - I mean questions where you have the feeling that the one asking has good fundamentals, and he has an idea of what he is doing. Answering to such questions is a kind of dialogue and exchange, where both parties gain.

**Instead, there is now a flood of really poor questions** - and it seems to be of two categories:

- students who simply post their homework; who have no idea or interest at all and just say "Please solve it for me". - Some even say "Now" instead of "Please".
- People with no or very little understanding of computer science, who got some work to do, but who have no idea of what is going on at all. E.g. just randomly running an SQL command they get from somewhere and wondering why it does not work.

It's becoming frustrating. Just adding to the discussion.

Comment: *People have got the impression that Stack Overflow is a strong community where "every question is answered".* you say this like this is a surprise. **The charter specifically states it now.** It is not an *impression*, it is what the site is now. *we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.* `Quality` has not been part of the charter in about 5 years now, and has only gotten lip service since they took it out and realized that not focusing on quality gets them more people seeing more ads.

Answer (score 9):

As a relatively new programmer, I'm basically learning to code in and out of Java and C++ classes, I obtained most of my base knowledge from Visual Basic years ago..

However, I'll admit that I first came to Stack Overflow to learn some more basic skills and learn the answer to simple questions. Maybe I'm contributing to the overall problem perhaps. I don't like to think that personally - but maybe you're right.

I approached Stack Overflow in the first place because it is a site where many highly experienced programmers come to and discuss programming. Being around experienced programmers such as yourselves and reading your comments and answers inspires me to be a better programmer, ask better questions and learn from your feedback.

I don't want to take your code, I don't want to just take your answers and never return, not at all. I want to learn from my own failings and your feedback so in the future I can tackle issues with ease, and maybe help someone else down the line -- and in the case I do use your techniques I will give credit and my personal thanks.

I respect all of you that are more experienced than I am, and I respect the fact that many of you dislike the naivety of new programmers, but, some of us DO want to learn and some of us DO want to contribute eventually but are still finding our feet.

Please don't turn your backs on the perhaps 'few' new programmers that actually want to learn instead of steal; you were where we were once. Even though I agree that teaching yourself is the best way to learn, this is a good resource to grasp the basics needed to experiment and perform trial and error.

Comment: I did not learn things by asking. I learned things by coding. Thinking, solving problems and writing code. Only months and months of reading others code and writing your own (3 prototypes thrown away until the 4th does it right). SO can not do it for you. You must do it yourself. Then you will be experienced. It is easier to go and ask someone to think instead of you. But it will never help you grow so much as whey you sweat yourself. Lazy and uneducated people it is what the question is about. SO was not originally meant to be tutorial low cost site for this kind of audience

Comment: As a newer programmer, it might be worth knowing that employers look for devs that know how to figure things out on their own (that includes knowing how to do research) as opposed to being told how to do things.

Comment: @MadConan I think most employers look for devs that know how to get job done, whatever it takes, and asking questions is one of the most important tools in the toolbox

Answer (score 9):

I believe there is only one core reason for bad questions: the OP didn't do any research at all. A person hits a problem and without spending five minutes on it or trying to understand a root cause, he/she start posting it on Stack Overflow.

And generally, this breaks down to two category of questions:

- Duplicate

All of us stumble on simple problems when we learn a new technology. And all of us will have very similar questions.

- Lacking even very basic understanding of software development.

That's more troublesome. If a person doesn't have a fundamental understanding, the question is rarely good.

I believe both categories should be solved by closing these questions. And as several person pointed it out, closing questions (**specifically in these two categories**) should be incentivized.

BTW. The most important to incentivize closing questions only in these two categories. Frankly, I don't like that all closing causes bundled together. As example, I feel that closing a question as opinion-based is overused and closing as duplicate is underused.

Oh.. One more funny idea. Add a field to Stack Overflow, which will ask "How much time did you spend trying to solve this problem on your own?".

Comment: The "How much time have you spent?" could have some interesting psychological effects, but it won't do anything against help vampires and slackers. They'll just see another field that they must set to such-and-such value to get their question through. They're not here to solve problems on their own, after all, but to let others solve them.

Comment: I think, the only way to stop abusers - to make it more pricy to abuse the system. Closing their questions should achieve this goal. And this question is more to educate newbies (who don't plan to abuse SO) that some time should be spent before posting a question.

Answer (score 8):

I wasn't active on SO for a while. Sometimes I return and try to find a good question to answer, however, got to admit that you're right. Questions' quality is getting worse and worse.

One of the solutions could be to apply some kind of filter to new users (e.g. < 100 rep.), that would automatically close their question if it gots a lot of downvotes - so if they want their question to get answered they must edit & improve its quality - then it could go to reopen queue.

<sup>Although questions are getting their answers insanely quickly, I think they get their votes even faster.</sup>

Comment: It wouldn't work.  A newbie asks a FAQ with half a dozen of related questions answering the problem, and you'd see a flurry of upvotes on the question.  It might work if upvotes start costing some rep.

Comment: [Another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355068/formatting-in-python-3-0) of a _highly-quality_ question with multiple upvotes.

Comment: @devnull: If upvote cost reputation, there should be a way to get it back. Otherwise people would be shy on upvotes. Something like - if the question was closed for any reason within 2-3 days - you don't get your reputation back. Otherwise, you get it back, to encourage healthy upvotes this way. Same for answers, i.e. you upvote an answer, and it gets deleted within 2-3 days - you lost your rep forever. However, to make it profitable, it needs to give an extra rep point, if you vote was helpful. So to upvote, it takes 1 rep, but you get 2 rep back (net +1), if it was a healthy upvote.

Comment: @devnull: Which is kind of an interesting way to look at it - you are helping SO sort out content, good from bad, rewarding this activity sounds inline with other reward mechanisms already in place.

Comment: @Neolisk I'm not sure how it can be implemented.  However, currently upvotes are grossly misused in order to keep poor questions _alive_ so that one's answer could attract upvotes.  Repwhores would be shy to put even 1 rep point at stake if were to cost them for an upvote.  Moreover, ability to close a question also depends on the community.  Those active in a given tag aren't willing to close an obvious duplicate.  The close votes usually expire.  It's the quality of participants that is going down, which has an effect on everything else.

Comment: the solution you're reaching for here is that **questions should be completely eliminated from the universe, AUTOMATICALLY, after 30 minutes UNLESS, many experts approve that the question is high quality.**  That's fine and would be worth trying. BUT: as I said above: None of this will happen. SO is now an incredibly slow moving organisation. It's completely pointless talking about radical, "let's try it!" solutions. It simply won't happen. You might as well discuss time travel or aliens.

Comment: IMO problem is that SO wants as much users as possible, most users are crapy and you can't get good from crap (nor questions, nor answers). If you want quality, you ask for quality and filter everything else. But of course then you cannot say that SO have xx million of visitors every day (with generates $$), so you will stuck with high traffic and consequences of that. If you want only tesla vehicles in your city, you can't say everyone can drive here, you can say everyone is welcome, but you can drive only if you drive tesla.

Answer (score 8):

Well I've only just joined this site, but what I seem to be noticing with the webdev questions is that people come onto SO, ask their question then take the coded answer and leave, without acknowledgement of the person who submitted it. They seem to take it for granted. Or something else that infuriates me is when they ask a question, don't give enough information, then don't come back and give the information!

Honestly though, its at their own disadvantage. If they don't want to understand why the answer is the correct way to do it, then they aren't going to improve their skills or learn anything, therefore hindering their own career.

Comment: Also I see is lot of people answers that "Write a code for me" questions, just to get reputations. If people avoid answering such questions, I think people may stop asking such a questions.

Comment: Yeah I answered one of those earlier, just to realise the user hadn't even bothered to try to code it themselves, they simply looked for someone else to do it for them. However, I don't think not answering such questions will stop other users from asking them, because a lot of people remain ignorant of the other questions that are asked on this site.

Answer (score 8):

**Additional Input From New Users**

After reading [Dota 2 - Valve is Manipulating Gamers Into Good Behavior](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/133917-Dota-2-Valve-Is-Manipulating-Gamers-into-Good-Behavior) it seems like we might be able to improve quality by increasing the amount of input we receive upon a new user asking their first questions.

The article refers to how asking an indirect question about an external factor, such as the cooperation of your teammates, can actually alter the behavior of the player responding to the question.

Along those lines, a survey-type question for new users which makes the user think about the existence of potentially similar questions that have already been answered may help guide their future behavior.

There have been several suggestions of some kind of 'tutorial' for new users but a simple questionnaire requiring some kind of ACTIVE response by new users as they are asking their first questions could be enough.

What if new users presented with the list of possible duplicates had to actively choose a reason that the potential duplicates don't apply to them?

A simple 'Does this answer your question: Yes [ ] No [ ]' or a dropdown with reasons why it doesn't apply might not be immediately helpful to anyone trying to act as a moderator but there is some potential to shape the user's behavior.

Comment: I honestly don't believe in the "it's a newbie, they just don't know how to work the site" hypothesis. "Newbie" is not part of the reason. Carelessness is. A newbie who cares will read the help the site literally pushes in their face. They will know how Markdown works. They will actually look at the preview the editor produces and will improve the question if looks ugly. They will think of including an error message they ask about and steps to reproduce it because they actually took the time and think how their question might look to a third person.

Answer (score 8):

Some form of filtering might solve this problem, i.e. your search results or home page is filtered to show results in your rep peer group, that way new comers help new comers with simpler questions or assistance on how to use Google, and veteran SO users aren't disenchanted by the quality or complexity of questions.

As a self taught PHP and Java dev, SO has been crucial in helping me understand the languages, and incredibly valuable in helping me understand the concepts and facets of each language that I should focus on.

I don't think that SO should make it harder for these questions to stick, but instead find a way to get intro-level users to help each other, perhaps by requiring the new user to answer a couple of "just read the docs" questions (that more senior users can tag as such).

This way new users are answering the questions that really should've been Googled, which hopefully will prevent them from asking similar questions.

Answer (score 7):

I think, most of the users who make their firsts posts aren't aware of the basic concepts of how Stackoverflow should work. They are used to the general standard of most Internet forums, which tend to be spammy, flamy, and so on. They think, they can do the same here. On the other hand, lots of them are just coming here to exhaust and abuse the human resource of helping programmers on SO.

I keep this as a serious problem, and it should be treated the more complex way. I would set up the following strict regulations:

1. Force users to make their first post only after completing a
   tutorial, which teaches them how to ask format questions correctly.
2. Create a blackmark system and permanently ban some users.
3. We should continue pointing out, that the question is of wrong
   quality, most likely because of the lack of research.
4. Lots of previous questions should be deleted. And like every 10th to
   be kept. There is no need to analyse the same error message over and over again, if they add nothing. Useful comments regarding a specific topic should be merged.

Comment: All of these things are *already* being done.  Users must confirm that they've read the "how to ask" page to post, there's a post ban system for users who only contribute negatively, we have downvotes, closing, and comments to provide feedback on posts that aren't of high quality, and questions can be deleted, either automatically or manually, when they meet certain criteria indicating that they are not valuable.

Comment: "*Abuse*" is too strong of a word.  After all, nothing forces anyone to spend his/her somewhat limited intellectual resources on any particular question.

Comment: @Servy I'm continuously running into redundant posts, the cleanup is not done yet. @PM_77-1 "Stackoverflow is for professional programmers.." as someone mentioned and is written on the index page. I'm saying, there should not be 10K questions about positioning `<div>` elements for example.

Comment: @RápliAndrás I'm not saying the site is perfect, I'm saying that all of your proposed changes already exist, so clearly those proposed changes, while they help, are not sufficient to solve this problem.

Comment: @Servy Confirming reading "how to ask" isn't the same as a tutorial. However, maybe a trivial quiz could be given and need to be passed? Basic quiz questions: "Choose the proper question title from this list..." or "Select versions of Windows (or Linux, Android, etc.,) you've used...". Requiring active responses might give a basis for setting any new user's required rep for asking questions. If a new user can't even recognize a Windows version, maybe a little added delay is called for.

Comment: @user2338816 Then you start getting into the area of pretty significant barriers in front of users, to the point of driving away good users who are willing and capable of being good participants, but who aren't interested in spending half an hour making a new account.

Comment: @Servy That should depend on how complex the questions are and how easy to answer. Choosing, for example, quality question subjects among "1. Urgent! Need help with error!!!", "2. Getting SQL4503N in DB2 9.7 on UPDATE" and "3. Subjects are _subjective_ anyway" takes a couple seconds to read and a click of the mouse. If there are, say, three questions, it should add maybe 15 seconds to the process (for a "good participant"). Getting all three correct could confer immediate rep power to ask.

Comment: @user2338816 And how do you plan to generate all of those questions?  What keeps them out of Google?  How do you ensure all of the questions will be clear, correct, of appropriate difficulty, objective, etc.?

Comment: @Servy If found in a Google search, that already demonstrates willingness both to search ahead of time and to persevere through a "half hour" account set up. Aren't those two qualities being sought? As for generating the questions, that should take little more than a few comments in a thread like this one. Only a few questions would ever be needed. It doesn't have to be from a large question database and could potentially be a static list.

Comment: @user2338816 If it's a static list then just trying it several times whenever you mess up could easily pass the test without learning anything.  If the results are showing up in google then you can get rid of a few people, possibly, but you're still not leaving yourself with a very high standard.  Losing even a handful of good users would make it a net loss.  For this to work there needs to be a *very* tight balance of hard enough that undesirable users can't get past it, but easy enough for good users to *quickly* and painlessly get through it.  That's a *very* fine line to walk.

Comment: @Servy Theoretically, not a very fine line for participants in this very thread. The whole discussion centers on participants' ability to recognize good/appropriate questions. Either we can, which means we could come up with a half dozen questions in a few minutes, or we can't, which almost makes this thread moot.

Comment: I tend to believe that Stackoverflow is not the first resource found by most posters, and that they are more savvy to the use of the service though not the level of expertise in their midst. Hence, a vague question for professionals more liking to specific issues.

Comment: Copypaste any error message, the first result is SO. Believe or not, there are people who never read the official documentation.

Comment: option #1 sounds like a great idea

Answer (score 7):

**Solution: Fix Yahoo Answers.**

For the last few years, I've been trolling Yahoo Answers to build SEO on a site I manage. About a year ago, they did a redesign of the site, and pretty much broke it. From what I can tell, there isn't a way to ask or answer a question anymore. The date that YA broke seems to correlate well with the date of the drop off in quality on SO in Denis' answer in this thread.

YA used to get a lot of these low-quality questions, because someone *might* answer it there.

I think if the SE folks bought Answers from Yahoo, or created a competing "general knowledge" site to attract the low quality questions, the quality would improve on the other SE sites.

Comment: SE ... buys a void?

Comment: No, @Smandoli, Marissa's too expensive. They just need to buy the Answers property.

Comment: Lol a honeypot!

Answer (score 7):

When I saw this question I immediately recall this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csyL9EC0S0c#t=3408

As explained in a similar way by others on this post it is seems some people like to ask questions with an answer in mind regardless if it is correct approach or not.

It seems that we are part of a culture of google first learn after. During the search "whatever comes first will be accepted as the correct solution" and only a few will want to learn more about it later or feel tempted to challenge the answer they found.

Others may have other ideas about this:

[Should reputation be hidden until an answer is accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79621/246392)

Answer (score 7):

(*my internal representation of the question*)

```
if(user.getOpinion().equals(this.opinion)){
   display(getNonRetreatingProcess());
}else{
   display(getCynicismBlockingProcess());
}
```

Leading to the output:

`<nonretreatingprocess>`

I'm a relatively new-ish participant on SO (1.6 yrs), but have benefited from the site for a long time, so I do see, or at least perceive, a downward trend in question quality.

Most the "why" was covered in Tim Post's post, and I feel like this is just a, "me too!" response, but I thought I'd add in a little more.  I'm going to steal some quotes from Tim to expand on.

> Folks are entering this field [*are probably*] not ever going to be good programmers because they probably aren't ever going to think like one. This job requires a degree of natural talent and not everyone has it - just like painting, sports, writing. ... This is something that the whole industry is seeing...

IMO, this pretty much covers a HUGE portion of why.  But I think at least one underlying cause that allows all of these people to write code is how programming languages and tooling has evolved to allow nearly *anyone* to make something that "works."  Higher levels of abstraction in programming languages means programmers don't need to know how their code is being processed by the machine.  Compilers are smarter, even fixing bad code on the fly.  IDE's can be configured to auto-generate code -- in some cases, auto-generating **[everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_code_generation_tools)**.  You no longer need to be smart enough to analyze an algorithm for efficiency, program a sorting algorithm from scratch, or do binary to decimal conversions in your head.  Now by themselves, all of these things are good.  They allow smart people to spend time thinking of bigger problems. But they also allow not-so-smart people to do things that should be left to the smarter-than-the-not-so-smart-people people.

The previous, coupled with the following (which will solicit downvotes, I'm sure) just exacerbates the drop in quality.

Comments to Tim's answer touched on "being nice" vs. "being mean." Brian Roach says

> But IMHO there's a difference between being rude vs. hurting some special snowflake's delicate feelings by explaining (without malice or snark) that they can't just hamfist some words into the editor, dump their code, and have people fix it for them / do their work for them. It really feels like SO went a bit too far and the pendulum needs to swing back a bit.

Agreed.  I understand it's human nature to think in black and white (it makes things easy), but the nice-to-mean line is analogous to a real number line.  There's an infinite amount of variation between levels.  I think SO and society in general has become overly sensitive to criticism.  I'm not promoting being mean, but there's nothing wrong with a bit of negativity to dissuade bad behavior.  There's a huge difference between screaming, "You f*#$%g stupid moron!!!!  You should go kill yourself!!!" and sending someone a lmgtfy link.  The former is mean. The latter is a passive-aggressive hint that maybe you should try researching things yourself. I was sadly surprised to find I can't put lmgtfy links in comments.  For me, that's an acceptable form of negative reinforcement.  I'm obviously in a minority on this topic.  Just remember "rude" is a subjective term.  Some people need a bit of rudeness to get the point (eg The person pushing their way to the front of line).  And a lot of the more recent questions are at that level of vacuousness.

**TL;DR** - Tim's right.  Be a jerk FTW. (along with other solutions already posted.)

`</nonretreatingprocess>`

Comment: LMGTFY specifically has been banned pretty early on for being nasty (and ultimately unhelpful). I never could quite get to agree with that, but the community decided that way. It's a bit like not keeping score in sports and games so no child has their feelings hurt. Sometimes you got to loose and you got to be told so and you got to feel the pain, so you can find the motivation to improve. Unfortunately there's a thin line between telling someone off for their benefit and doing so for your's.

Comment: @Tomalak I understand moderating rudeness is not an easy thing -- right up there with [parsing HTML using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2919971).  But LMGTFY seems so mild to me.  I guess I grew up in a different time and culture.

Comment: "Everyone loves to quote from the FAQ’s etiquette section, particularly the first “be nice” bit. But it’s the last section that has all the action items:

    **Be honest.**
    Above all, be honest..." ([Stack Exchange is not a forum: the role of “niceness” on a Q&A site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/))

Comment: @MadConan Don't get me started on "HTML + regex" questions and the inevitable "why this has always worked for me, don't be so dogmatic" / "but the OP asked for regex solutions" answers.

Comment: @gnat I don't fully agree with that page.  I stand by my statement that there are people who *need* a rude response before they get the point. However, determining who that is based on a faceless question on an anonymous media is a problem I don't have an answer for.

Comment: @Tomalak "*there's a thin line between telling someone off for their benefit and doing so for your's*".  That's not an xor operation, is it?

Comment: well I personally feel like I am capable to handle bad stuff without being snarky. But on the other hand, seeing others rude comments in _extremely low quality_ questions somehow doesn't bother me. Such questions damage site anyway, with comments or without, and solution is simply to delete them, which would also take care of any comments that are there

Comment: @gnat Problem is, deleting one of them may (in theory, as a numbers game) improve the quality of the site, but it does not help in preventing new bad questions from being asked. In practice, a delete vote needs 5 agreeing users, which is typically more attention than any bad questions receives. So as site popularity grows, overall quality will still go down.

Comment: @Tomalak agree, that's a real issue. My understanding is, currently SE team tries to address it by auto-detecting questions for Triage and by keeping these off the site pages while under review. So far it looks like they're on the right track, but they seem to have a [problem connecting new review to auto-deletion system](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293457/839601 "discussed eg here")

Answer (score 6):

### What is the purpose of Stack Overflow?

I would argue, to create a useful and searchable database of programming knowledge in question and answer format.

### What makes a good question?

A good question is one which helps not only the user, but also future users. This is a question which is upvoted, revisited, commented upon and maintained. The level of the question doesn't matter, it could be about eigenclasses or unordered lists, provided it's general.

The test of generalisability is: "is this an issue likely to affect more than one person ever". A stack trace thrown by a popular library would be general.

A good question is

1. Reasonably Generalised
2. Asked at the correct level for the user doing the asking.

### What makes a bad question?

A bad question is of the form: "Here's my code, it doesn't work, can you fix it for me?"

1. It's specific to a very particular problem, e.g. the user has missed a semi-colon on line 14.
2. It's asked at a level well above the user's skill level, and as such makes no sense eg. How do I make Facebook, when the user manifestly doesn't understand what a variable is?

### I would suggest the following:

1. Bring back "too localised" as a reason to close - for missing semi-colon issues.
2. Add in a "question makes no sense" reason to close - when the question is asked so far above the user's level that it makes no sense.
3. Allow people with higher rep to close a question immediately.
4. Make a downvoted question be closable immediately.
5. Use voter.rep / poster.rep to determine the weight of a close vote.
6. Remove downvote disincentive. Rep lost on closed questions should be reset.
7. Remove incentive to answer poor quality questions. rep gained answering closed questions should be reset.
8. Disincentivise "rep whoring" - posters with a few high voted answers should be rewarded more than posters with a lot of low voted questions. This is fuzzy.
9. Add in "My code doesn't work please help me" as a reason to close.

Comment: 1: we have "can no longer be reproduced or simple typographical error" for missing semicolons. 2: We have "unclear what you're asking" to handle these. 3 to 5: discussed and shot down. 6 and 7: still being discussed IIRC. Not sure about 8.

Comment: I don't automatically consider a localized question a bad one. Sometimes you are stuck with a very specific problem that's not easy to generalize and need a second pair of eyes to get you moving. That's even a pretty common case, I dare to say. Some of the very specific answers I gave to localized problems in niche tags caught an up-vote and a "wow that helped me" comment after laying dormant for two years.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - 1. Fair enough, though there are classes of question which are not purely typographical, eg. when the user has mis-understood the left and right hand sides of a variable assignation. 2. Fair enough. 3 - 5. I still contend it would be better to have an easier way to shut down users without aptitude. It takes more work, and higher skilled work to shut down a question than it does to ask it. 6 - 7. Would be good. SO appears to be technically capable of this as rep is lost when a user leaves the site. 8. It would be good to distinguish between quality and quantity.

Comment: @Tomalak - agreed, it's a question of degree. A question that **only** relates to the user's **code** is localised. A question that relates to the user's **problem** is not localised. There are levels of abstraction. I would contend that questions asked at level 0 tend to be of lower quality.

Comment: I'm afraid it would be hard to agree on a definitive level for a question. Some things are super difficult for one person and super trivial for the other. But I think it's entirely possible to agree on a few basic denominators that make a good question: Has code, code is syntactically correct & minimized to the relevant parts, has explanations, states the intent & the expected outcome, outlines a thought process, is formatted properly, proves some research was done (I even claim that when these basics are present, it already can't be a blatant duplicate anymore.)

Comment: Making it easier to mark something as a duplicate (which _many_ of these questions are) will also curtail the 'rep whoring' that you mention. Folks just won't be able to answer these with crappy two-line answers any longer because they'll be closed so quickly. [We're thinking of ways to make this easier now.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253262/50049)

Comment: @TimPost - Yes. Marking as a duplicate takes a fair chunk of highly skilled work. You need to research, read and understand. It should be made as easy as possible, and incentivised.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is a huge difference between those with the knowledge to answer the questions and those that are asking.  I was really into programming as a kid.  I taught myself BASIC, programmed an adventure game on my TI 82 graphing calculator, but I stopped to get serious about a career (getting two degrees in English, which are a total waste).

When I joined SO, I was just starting an accelerated CS degree program.  I used it as an "oh crap, my assignment is due in two hours and I'm getting a segmentation fault" source for solutions.  There was a lot of negativity towards what I asked, I rarely got good help (but when I did it was really good and I learned a lot).  I'm not sure what part of this is due to my question asking skills or SO's user base.

Now, a year later, I'm going through trying to answer questions, provide input and feedback and help others.  I see the blatantly lazy and stupid questions.  I also see the self-learners that remind me of myself as a young kid (I certainly would of been one if I was born 20 years later than I was).  I also see more and more people with limited English skills or for who English is a second or third language.

About a third of the questions i see are conceptual (How is the best was to approach this, what data structures are fastest for this).  A third are code problem questions (I'm getting this error with this code).  The final third are "I'm totally lost and not sure how to proceed" questions.  I think all of these are within the scope of stack overflow, and should be answered to the best of our ability.  If there isn't enough information, we should (nicely!) ask for the information we need.  If it isn't given, then we ignore the question and let it dry up and die until the OP is willing to make it better, and add in the additional information.

I think we need to decide as a community how to respond to the low quality questions where someone is trying to pass off work onto others, with no attempts to fix it themselves.  I see SO as a learning resource, and I've been trying to link things to these people, so they can educate themselves, instead of providing a perfect answer.  That way if they are lost, I've given them a compass.  If they are lazy, they will remain lost forever.

Comment: A question that came about from having a problem under a tight deadline is highly unlikely to provide much lasting value (although it's possible) - what are the chances of someone writing the exact same program as you, in the exact same way, making the exact same mistake, not to mention actually considering that this highly improbable sequence of events may have happened and end up doing an in-depth search to find your question? And yes, we are trying to fill the site with questions with lasting value. That's the real problem - people just wanting answers without caring about the site.

Comment: @Dukeling its then a question if the purpose of the site is a reference, or the purpose of the site is a commmunity of programmers trying to help one another out.

Comment: Definitely both - ideally every single question should be asked such that answers help the asker, but it also provides lasting value. If this isn't the goal, there'd be little point to even making the questions public in the first place. IMO questions without lasting value shouldn't be on the site at all (i.e. closed, downvoted and deleted ASAP), although I'm not sure what the 'official' stance on that is.

Comment: New programmers who ask the stupid questions, maybe don't know how to find the resources they need or how to understand documentation, are part of that community.  They need to be trained how to find the answers they need on their own, not downvoted to oblivion and ridiculed

Comment: I agree that they need to be taught, but if someone asks for food, teaching him to fish isn't a valid answer, and, in many cases, the things they need to be taught goes way beyond what one can fit in an answer. If someone's code isn't working (want food), they should learn to debug (learn to fish). Telling them what they did wrong (giving them a fish) doesn't help them a particularly large amount in the long run, and it certainly doesn't help anyone else.

Comment: As a youngster I learnt 68k assembly on the amiga, self taught via a book and a disassembler program and dissecting other's code, because I had a passion to learn to code. What I'm finding annoying is the number of students who come on here expecting their school/uni programming assignments/projects to be coded up for them to completion, without *any* effort on their part. How will they actually learn from doing this, and why are they even in a programming class if they're not willing to try?

Comment: Which is why we need to train them on how to find the resources they need.  It took the good part of a semester for me to get skilled at finding answers with google and searching SO.  It took probably another few weeks for me to realize how many good references there are online (like the Java and C documentation), as well as how to use them.  Just telling them no isn't going to stop them from posting the questions, giving them the tools to find the answers themselves will make them better programmers, as well as improve the quality of their questions.

Answer (score 5):

## The Problem

In my opinion, question quality should be examined on a broad chronological timeline. In the beginning, the people using StackOverflow more than likely had similar goals and saw SO for it's possibilities. So as to avoid it becoming yet another overrun Q&A site, I think people banded together and actively worked to manage content quality. People had a stronger sense of community pride then and picked up the trash they found on the street while out for a walk. Today, people land on SO from all over and, to them, this may be *just another Q&A site*.

## User Training

Community means nothing to those not aware of it. That ignorance (in the general sense of unawareness), I believe directly correlates with the poor question quality -- people simply don't understand why they should care. The solution, in my opinion, is to provide training to new users and communicate:

- What StackOverflow is and is not. What does the community stand for? Guiding principles? What makes this a community and NOT just another Q&A site.
- How to search for an answer
- How to write a good question if you cannot find a useful answer
- How to answer good questions

Many web applications these days, upon account creation, provide an instructional *walkthrough* to engage users and provide them with enough information to capitalize on the full experience. So, how would something like that work for posting requirements?

- Create a new badge for completing the training. Allow this badge to be revoked by a moderator requiring the user to redo the training in the event they choose to ignore the principles provided.
- New questions require:

  - Either user has earned this badge, essentially saying they have reviewed and understand what SO is all about.
  - Or user has earned a reputation greater than some arbitrary threshold, which they could earn by answering questions and contributing to the community.

As a drawback, this solution may raise the level of poor quality answers, but downvotes are in place and other users who provide higher quality answers will most likely drown out the noise and enable high quality questions to receive high quality answers.

Perhaps this approach is too harsh or does not align with the goals of StackExchange, I just wanted to communicate my thoughts here on a solution as I don't want to see StackOverflow ever lose ground in the war on quality content.

### References

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_of_community
- http://techcrunch.com/2013/01/05/in-defense-of-the-humble-walkthrough/

Comment: Doesn't stackoverflow already do this? (the whole walkthrough for new users) http://stackoverflow.com/about it gets linked as the first thing when you view the site while not logged in.

Comment: And, there is a badge related to it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed

Comment: This is a true statement, although the about page is a bit of an *indirect* approach. What I am suggesting is, rather than being an optional way to earn an extra badge, it is required before posting and focuses on communicating the key areas that currently may contribute to poor question quality. Similar to how the "review" section will sometimes give a dummy review just to make sure you are paying attention, perhaps the about page is interactive and provides a mechanism to write a "practice question" or way to indicate a good vs. bad question.

Comment: The R community on SO has a user training solution with this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/134830 (It's by far the most popular/highest voted question with the R tag.) Since most R users are not programmers by trade (they are data analysts or scientists or engineers or business folk), there is less of an assumption that you need to know how to code to ask a question here.

Answer (score 5):

It's an interesting question you raise but I think the level of question being asked is starting to reflect the liklihood of them being answered.
I've asked a few questions over the last few years and it seems that only ones that can be answered with a few lines of code or a suggestion get answered.
For example I posed a question yesterday regarding how to add a responsive iframe in a wordpress page and it's received no answers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483248/getting-wordpress-to-display-iframe-responsively). I'm not surprised as I know it's a difficult question to answer unless you have a good working knowledge of wordpress. However it just means that like along with many others the level of question being posed on here will either sink through the floor or be so vague as to be impossible to answer

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of being down-voted ad-nauseam, I suggest if there is a lack of interest in a question for reasons such as

- Commonly asked
- Not enough thought
- Sloppy; unclear

why is there no interest in training the OP to be better at Q&A?  I came across SO not because I sought it out but because Google matched my search request to SO that had a question identical to mine. I imagine a similar scenario:

1. Busy coder
2. Ran into problem
3. Google search
4. Found SO; may be inexperienced or experienced programmer
5. SO Must have professionals who know answer
6. Ask quick question; may contain any of the following:

   Poor grammar, incorrect terminology, missing syntax, poorly communicated, etc.
7. Still need an answer

Rather than down-voting and closing the question, if there is an interest in improving the quality, I would think some iteration is needed in the form of feedback to the OP. That could be as a simple as cleaning up their question, point to the 'How to Ask a Question', or have the OP clarify their question.

I view the process as no different than mentoring a new associate at a company.  They are bound to write bad code, be unfamiliar with patterns and logic but through time (their own and yours) they become better and turn into a contributor rather than make room for the next new OP to repeat the process all over again.

Also, if there is no interest in addressing an OPs question or providing assistance, why bother?  Many other questions on SE to answer.

That is my 1 red nickel.

Comment: A mentoring program. Interesting idea. Can be gamed and whored -- oh, undoubtedly. But intriguing.

Comment: Perhaps you fail to understand my suggestion.  Such tools exist already in SE and, in particular SO.  From the ability to modify an OP's question, to providing feedback about the question, to the more punitive measures such as close votes, down votes, and the myriad of means and ways, there is ample opportunity to assist an OP.  Point I make is, rather then immediately go for the punitive measures, how about those that be of some actual use and do some good in turning a bad OP into a good one?

Comment: Yeh, sorry to be dense and thanks for the extra help.

Comment: I've had some very pleasant moments in SO when I felt I did improve someone.  But that natural and satisfying dynamic is defeated by the current crisis.  If we can find a solution, we can return to improving ourselves and our fellows.  Otherwise, not.  So, I can't really take your answer as valid in this context.

Comment: That's the problem. Someone who can't be bothered to think about it their question properly (everything else: minimal code samples, state of intent, explanations, expected output, corner cases, proper question format - is a direct result of bothering to think about your problem in a structured manner) ... so everyone *not* doing that will produce a low quality crap question by default. They don't care, they are in "need an answer fast" mode. I fear they will not improve their approach when you try to mentor them about how to ask a question. The others will produce good questions from day one.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, but since you can't control that and it makes no sense to just bump them out of the system only to recycle more of the same behavior, the only solution is to "teach them how to fish" and break the cycle.  Otherwise, nothing is gained and all there is remains lost.  These same folks who poorly ask questions on SO do so on other sites as well.  I think it is more a desire to get the job done than interact on a higher social order.

Comment: When I arrived here I thought "wow, a site full of answers to lots of problems, I think I'll drop google and research directly here". Until today, I almost haven't asked much, it's all at a search distance. In my book, a programmer without research skills ain't that great.

Comment: The main problem here is that its simply impossible, given the scale of this site.  There are many thousands of terrible questions asked each day.  There just aren't enough experienced users to mentor every single person who asks an awful question.  Even if every regular spent hours a day doing so, they would only make up a drop in the bucket when it comes to all of the crap.  There is only sufficient time to get the crap off of the site through downvoting, closing, and deletion.  Those interested in learning to ask proper questions have plenty of resources available to learn from.

Comment: Also note that closing a question *is* providing valuable feedback as to what is wrong with the post, and includes lots of information on how to go about addressing those problems.  Most people who can't be bothered to spend any time researching their question, or forming a quality well written question, simply don't have any intention of improving or learning how to fix their question.  If they did, they would already be able to do so.

Comment: @Servy The prime motivation, as I observe, for the use of Q&A sites, such as SO, is just to get an answer to a question.  It appears to me all other considerations are secondary including SE's desire to formulate a repository of every question with accompanying answer as determined by the community at large.  Perhaps the problem is the ease of access to SO and SE at large.  Only takes creation of an account and one is off and asking questions with no requirement to prioritize learning how to ask questions and contribute.  That may need to be addressed in the future as well.

Comment: SO seems to be only wanting to be the last point of assistance for a question - which is understandable if people don't supply enough information to have the question answered. But if they do supply enough information to solve the problem but not enough to 'prove' the hours they have spent researching then they get hassled about the formatting of the question. If there is enough information to limit the work for the person answering it to a minimal amount but technically the question wasn't exactly as people expect, is the question wrong to have been asked in the first place?

Comment: `At the risk of being down-voted ad-nauseam` It's your opinion. Up-vote means agreement and down-vote means disagreement. Here on meta your reputation doesn't change.

Comment: This takes waaaaaaay too much time

Answer (score 3):

I am going to be blunt and just suck up the downvotes.

The problem is that SO has fragmented into two camps: the ones who think that too many questions get closed too easily and the ones who don't agree with that sentiment.

I am personally in camp A along with many other collegues and other forums (HN for instance, which one would think you would like to cater to). Many of these have left SO.

Why is this? Here I can only say that the general sentiment is that SO "closes any interesting question". And now you wonder why question quality has dropped.

From my point of view "closing interesting questions" means that I cannot ask the questions which I want to ask fellow programmers at the same level of experience. I know that I can ask technical questions about compiler errors, algorithms, specific problems etc. But I can't ask for advice anymore.

I know most of you will just argue that "that is not what SO is for". But the thing is that it used to work but doesn't anymore.

From the start I thought "cool, a forum for communicating with fellow programmers" and now I think "cool, a forum for asking very specific technical questions if framed to the liking of the mods".

Come to think of it, this is generally what happens when mods take over and drive sites in some arbitrary direction, sometimes away from what some of the users would like.

Comment: [main] is not meant to be a forum. **It was very much designed to be the exact opposite, an Anti-Forum.** Jeff Atwood is currently working on an actual forum product now, [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/).

Comment: @Cupcake: Yes, I've heard this before. And I believe that the fact that this is more enforced now is is the reason why quality drops.

Comment: These questions were considered to have been out of scope within the first year of SO's existence, well before it's popularity really started to explode.  By the time the site became successful these questions had long been excluded from its scope.  Considerable effort has been spent discussing this topic, which you're more than welcome to research.  At the end of the day while these questions were *popular* and people loved to talk about them, they generated an extraordinarily small amount of quality content despite the huge amounts of subject expert's time they consumed.

Comment: "I think that if I could ask a question to a group of skilled programmers sitting around a table at lunch, and get interesting, valuable answers, then... that question should equally well be fair game for Stack Overflow..." --> [nope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167542/165773 "human interaction... doesn't blow up like a balloon")

Comment: @Servy it doesn't *matter* that "considerable effort" has been spent discussing this topic. Apparently, despite all the effort, you have not found a solution. Because this very question is about the fact that *question quality is still dropping*. Perhaps, in light of the fact that *it didn't work*, it is worth reconsidering what has been done to fix this problem previously? Just a thought....

Comment: @jalf So because there are still some question quality problem (which, for the record, we've had for forever, this is simply the flavor of the month meta topic to complain about, that doesn't mean it's a new problem) we should remove some of the practices that we've put in place that have significantly and demonstrably improved question quality?  Sorry, but no.  The fact that question quality isn't as high as we want it to be isn't a reason to make it worse.

Comment: Yeah, the obvious best solution is to create a better software.  SO sucks for the people it, perhaps inadvertantly, targets.  They have this share of the market: why don't they diversify?  Because camp B is so resistant.  Most of them probably want the job security that comes with zero competition, so they try to troll off the people who are asking the important questions that would, in any other setting, lead to informative answers.

Comment: @Cupcake: I thought about this for a while. Why is the common perception that an "how do I best do X" question is better served by a forum? Forums don't have voting, so how can I ever know which advice to follow? The great thing about SO is that all the suggestions are ranked by votes, so I can with confidence choose the best supported answer of the question. Here SO has an edge, why ignore this opportunity? It's fine to drop the questions where no answer stands out, but in most questions you see a distinctive difference in votes between top and bottom answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree with your premise, you can ask for advice providing your question has a strong foundation of research behind it and it remains on topic. The secret is, that with that done, the question no longer becomes purely about looking for advice but a question behind the validity of your problem

Answer (score 3):

I seem to be one of the ones you all hate. I spend at least an hour before posting a question on SO researching the cause of my problem. I post a question on here stating what I have, what I have tried and what I think might be why I am having a problem. I am then replied to with more people telling me my question sucks than trying to help me. Even insulting replies that don't get removed. I have professional coding experience, however I don't have a masters in anything to do with language and writing skills. I do my best to try and word questions as per what is asked by SO and to try and give the important information that I have gathered trying to resolve the issue myself but I struggle sometimes to define my problem in the exact right way that some random person with no solution says I should.

If this site is only reserved for professionals with years of experience with a language then it should be more clearly stated. You have SO getting some of the top results for simple questions after Googling an issue, so it's going to attract people that need this sort of assistance.

I think what some people are expecting needs a sign in big letters at the top of SO's sites:

"If you don't know what you are talking about, you should already. If you post something when you don't already know the answer, prepare to be ridiculed!"

Comment: What makes you think we would hate you? You do your research first and then post relevant code? You're **wonderful**!

Comment: *"I spend at least an hour before posting a question on SO researching the cause of my problem."* Hey how could we hate you. That statement alone puts you in the 5% of users I'm not even talking about. I'm sorry to hear people insult you in their answers (can you link to an example, just for reference?).

Comment: Faith restored in SO by 2 awesome people. Thanks guys for positive messages. Will get back to you with a link one of the questions.

Comment: Yeah, dude.  I totally feel you.  Sometimes I spend 2 weeks writing a question, and I totally get trolled by answerers who obviously don't know what they're talking about and are just rating whores.

Answer (score 3):

It now goes weeks between times where I find questions that are worthy of answers and if it wasn't for my older more technical questions, my reputation would never go up (not that I care <sub><sub>but that unicorn painting was pretty cool</sub></sub>).

Looking back at how I first started answering questions I was motivated by trying to unlock the next privilege and in an age of video games I imagine I am not the only one that has ever done this, but these themselves are flawed as **the privileges reward all behaviour**.

Regardless of the quality of your posts, eventually you will get these all unlocked and that is just *wrong*. These privileges should account for your actions as well as your reputation such as you can comment when your up/downvote ratio is positive along with the minimal 50 rep and increasingly harder (stricter) requirements for the more higher up utilities.

So that accounts for users  such as me..

But then this is only for those that wish to join the community, those that wish to just get a quick answer are not addressed and I would hope there would be something that can be done about that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to interject a view point that exposes more social reasons for question quality and tie that to a technical short coming and solution.

I have taught at a local university for a few years, a short time ago. My fellow instructors noted a pattern of technical ability in the students over a partial generation say 3 or 4 years. When 17 and 18 year olds, and technically even 14 and 15 year old students can modify databases, post new web content and publish full web sites or web applications from cell phones in a matter of minutes, the competition for classroom success sky rockets when some students can not. Add this to the simplicity of popular web sites to perform these actions in such a simple matter, that when an individual decides to try and develop their own application, they are clearly lost in the complexity of coding involved to perform the functions of applications that they have experience using.

I have been a user of Stack Overflow going on three years now, and I have asked some dumb questions of my own. I also truly believe that "search results quality" leads to the patterns of question quality in postings. There is no doubt that the ability for any site's algorithms to adequately provide the correct detailed answer to even non newbies is still random at best.

If you step outside the box for a moment, and examine the success rate of Watson, IBM's AI system, [Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_%28computer%29) boasted an 88% success rate in its first round on [Jeopardy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!). To examine this further, recall the results input sections of many web sites, Microsoft included. "Were these search results helpful, Yes, No, Why not?" I pray that these sites are improving their own algorithms with these results.

I feel a more accurate assessment of the question being posted would surely improve the answer quality and hopefully reduce poor question quantity. Imagine how tough it is to find targeted results on a handful of terms from a person that is not even certain about how to ask the right question in the first place. It goes back to the beginning of learning to spell a word by trying to look it up in a dictionary, how can you look it up if you can't spell it?

Too often background details are missing on question postings. Perhaps a profile or multiple sub profiles could include the users system parameters, platform, coding language in use, software revs. And I say multiple sub profiles, in case the poster develops on multiple platforms, [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [Visual Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic), [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29), C#, [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), etc.

There is plenty of room for a better Stack Overflow, not taking anything away from how awesome it is and all that it has done for the numerous developers that rely on it. But change is inevitable.

Answer (score -3):

These are the best solutions to low question quality:

### Revise the question, yourself

Get the ball rolling on a better answer by correcting grammar, spelling, etc.  If someone's asking a question, it's because they need help--maybe just some encouragement.  Try to avoid kicking them while they're somehow down, right?  If you improve the quality of the question, you may find additional information that reveals the question to be of a better quality than you had initially imagined.  This will also help to inspire the asker to do a better job on this and future questions.

### Ask *politely* for revisions

If you're polite when you ask someone to revise his or her question, and avoid jumping to 'close' or 'downvote', you're more likely to get a lasting effect from the asker.  This is common knowledge in behavioral shaping.  *Traditional punishers, especially those that precede incentive, lead to more intense misbehavior.*  For those of you who are nerds: diplomacy: lawful good; intimidation: lawful evil.

### Create better resources

Bad questions often arise from bad resources--often bad resources which cannot be improved.  Learners are taking time to investigate your culture by learning your language; so, you should give them some respect in the form of clout.  They want you to take the time to know who they are.  Ask: "what learning resources are you using, and what page are you on".  There are a lot of resources that programmers generally dislike (for example, w3schools).  But you can send edits to w3schools!  Why bash what you can change?  I really dislike the qt manual, and the oracle java manual, and they can't be edited.  I always wonder: "Why do people try to excuse the errors in these books, which can't be changed, and bash w3schools without sending in edits?"  Anyway: educators know, providing resources is essential, and sometimes that means 'teach this 12-year-old learner how to use google without killing his or her motivation'.

### Learn about education

Too many people think that knowing a skill means being able to teach a skill.  The truth is, there aren't many good teachers out there.  Do you know what humans need to learn?  Struggling through manuals and resources is actually very ineffective.  Most people who say they learned all by themselves actually had instructors, seat partners, family, friends, etc.  Most home-based learners don't have a community, so they ask chatty questions that we might consider low-quality.  It's not a good idea to slam people for getting chatty, though!  Try merging: build a better answer: try to avoid off-topic closures until some work has been done to make the learner feel more accomplished.  It's a natural part of human learning to seek connectivity and dialog: in employees, engagement is gauged to increase performance by 200% sometimes, and I estimate the number as being much higher.  A learner is a professional, sitting down, trying to fit into an office, basically.  Would you want your trainers and bosses to say: "That's a dumb question.  Close it, take some credit away from this guy, and don't answer the question?"  I challenge you to spend a few days in an office like that.  What kind of response would you want?

It's easier for askers and answerers if there's an exercise involved in each correspondence.  Instead of saying: "This is the answer."  Try: "This is the answer, and here's a follow-up question to help you cement in the knowledge."  This is known as "functional learning", and it's probably the best way to learn.  If you find yourself saying "rtfm", you may find askers becoming angry with you, professional educators laughing at you, and if you're working as an educator, you very well may lose your job.

A lot of the people who point to questions as being bad--it's common knowledge that that's wrong, by the way--, are also just terrible at answering questions and get the wind knocked out of them every time they try to help.  They don't like answering because they've been conditioned to dislike answering; so, they want to push the blame on the askers.  It's better to take a break from answering if it becomes that kind of compulsion: an addition to being sadistic towards learners.  You're practicing the skill of answering poorly: it's a habit instructors avoid because they can see the motivation die in students, but online, that can't be seen, so educators don't kick themselves when they mess up.

There are so many things answerers say that they could be saying better.  Remember, it's always your responsibility to improve your own communications, first, to improve the community.  Complaining about others (just to whine) is obviously less effective than improving your methods (with the obvious intention of effecting a specific result).

### Here's a quick palate of answer/comment upgrades to improve the community and long-term, hopefully improve question quality (wrong answer; reason; right answer):

- This is a place for help, not free work.  Sorry, help  = free work.  "Please, break your next question down into smaller bits and re-ask, if possible.  This is how I would break it down: a, b, c, ..."
- RTFM.  Sorry, that's not conducive to learning.  "Use this resource.  It covers that.  Read up to this section."
- Use google.  Probably already did.  "Here's a suggest keyword.  Make sure you use google, not hotbot."
- That question's too basic.  There are many reasons for asking basic questions; avoid using 'too'.  "Did you know that was basic info?  Here's the answer.  Now, what resource are you using, and why didn't you understand?  Read this resource up through here.  Here's a reference, make sure you have it open next time you ask."

There are many more of these, and there are much better ways to improve these answers.  These should get you started, though.  Can you build on these sublimations?  I'll also say, there are better solutions that I just don't want to put up, proving that some people (including myself) just don't want the competition that comes with posting the best possible answer.

### Methods for stopping troll answers ('bad-question' responses)

1. Require a comment and 5 minutes prior to a downvote.  This forces answerers and commenters to give askers a window of opportunity to improve the quality of the question.
2. Allow a 20 minute window after initial commenting prior to 'close votes' being allowed.  This gives askers an opportunity to rework the question and make it fit before it's closed, if it really just needs a few finishing touches (which is often the case).
3. Increase the penalty associated with down voting.  Down-vote abuse is really at the root of the issue.  It starts the dialog off on the wrong foot, so the asker is not likely to take the associated advice to heart.

Comment: I know people don't want to hear this, but it's true.  One of the most common methods for throwing off responsibility is to blame others, and that's really all this is.  It's the answerer's responsibility to manage the question, the asker, and the answer, all three.  Fundamentally, people should take as much responsibility as they possibly can unto themselves in all situations; so, there's no room to disagree.  This is the most mature path in any situation (to do your best and work with what you have).  It sets a bad example to rate questions without working to improve them; however, we can.

Answer (score -7):

As long as new technology is coming, there will be new questions. For example, in the Microsoft domain 5-7 years back most questions were related to [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline), now it is mostly .NET and [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language). After a year it will be Microsoft tiles-based applications.

So, most of the Visual Basic 6.0 questions are now obsolete, so you will get good quality questions in the latest technology.

Comment: VB6 was end-of-lifed 6 years ago. There has only been one VB6 question for over a decade: "Should I use it?" "No."

Answer (score -9):

> Tomalak states:
> "I'm seeing a rapid trend towards worse and worse question quality. It gets to the point where I'm asking myself "Why did I even help this guy? He neither has the will nor the capacity to understand the answer; I have just been wasting my time". That happens more and more often lately and is pretty frustrating.".

Unfortunately there's a recent push in this direction:

https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/principles/

> "**Content principles**
>
> Principles and tactics for writing at Stack Overflow. These will help produce clear, consistent content for users of different professions, identities, and levels of English fluency.
>
> **7th grade reading level**
>
> Write for a 7th grade reading level. Stack Overflow users are busy people with limited time and attention. They’re also located all over the world with different levels of English fluency. You can help everyone follow along by choosing simple, consistent words and phrases, and being careful about jokes and cultural references.".

That guideline starts out poorly and improves as one reads through it, its heart is in the right place but its head is not.

Writing for a 7th grade reading level is **too low**, in some cases [Stack Exchange requires users to be 18 years old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339095/282094), while the [minimum age is 13 to 16 depending upon location](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338517/282094). I can appreciate that we have users from around the world (and I help everyone regardless of location) but targeting all our answers to 13 year olds is the wrong direction to go.

I have worked for hours in some cases to help people with their question, with the help of others we have assisted the person to write a clear question using correct English; and offered an answer that they can understand - but mandating that as a writing style is wrong.

Some subjects simply require a high school or university level understanding. Dumbing it down as the default is rude and goes against Stack Exchange's statement above: "Stack Overflow users are busy people with limited time and attention.". If something is unclear to someone who is learning that's one thing, but talking down to people is quite another.

The question:

> "What's your view on the state of affairs in Stack Overflow - is your perception similar to mine? If yes, how are you dealing with it, other than retreating? If no, what do you do against creeping cynicism (because that's what really worries me here)?".

I think that overall that the question quality has increased (on our **other** sites, not so much on Stack **Overflow**), people generally understand to write better questions that are useful to others; otherwise the only attention they will receive is downvotes, negative perceived comments more recently (strongly) frowned upon, and no answer forthcoming.

Woe is the rep 1 user who asked a question that isn't particularly good. A half dozen of those and they are well on their way to the "one question every six months street"™.

Having almost exclusively answered questions and asked so few I do answer much less than I used to. But there's fresh blood to take my place, and plenty of critics to voice any complaint I could make.

That's unfortunate.

Comment: I am not sure what your point is.

Comment: "but targeting all our answers to 13 year olds is the wrong direction to go. " - no, it's targeting the reading level to that of a 13 year old By Some Metric:tm:. There's grown people with that level of english, purely because not every country in the world teaches English as a first language, and because English education is pretty bad in some cases (even in countries that otherwise have good english education)

Comment: Also, it even says what I just said in the actual description. The language barrier applies here too. Writing for a 7th grade level is NOT the same as writing for 13 year olds, but writing for a specific level in some or another definition I've never been able to properly understand why is used at all. Finally, that quote is from stackoverflow.design, which defines the site itself. It is NOT equivalent to a requirement, rule, or whatever for askers and answers. Yet anyway.

Comment: Also, while generally writing for a 7th grade level is recommended, that isn't possible in some cases. Terminology comes _hard_ into play for actual answers, which means there will be cases where it goes beyond that. That alone is probably why it's a part of SO's design guidelines, and not the post writing guidelines for questions and answers on the site itself. (Newsletters and site design is completely irrelevant in this case, because Stack writes all that anyway)

Answer (score -10):

Personally, I find that the friendliness of users on SO is much lower than on most other sites. Many times I ask intelligent questions only to have the question closed because it's been asked before. I always address the concerns and clarify about why my question is different, but to no avail. I'm not saying that all users are bad, and I still go here first whenever I have a question as the amount of helpful users is also high, but I view the site as a hostile environment.

In your question, you say that sometimes, the asker seems incapable of understanding. But that is exactly why they asked in the first place: to find a way to understand. If you answer the question, your goal should be to help them understand. If they don't, it's not their fault, if they took the time to ask on here and respond to your posts. You have no right to be mad at people for their lack of intelligence.

As for the people who only ask homework questions, they are making it worse, but the majority of the questions I see are quality questions that are often berated for their seeming stupidity.

And really, stupid questions aren't very hard to combat: just rate down and move on. But driving off potential good contributors is a wrong that is much harder to write.

Comment: A dowonvote without an explanation?! No surprise.

Comment: Friendliness is not something you should take into your mind. There are many kinds of people. And you have to calm down. Some users are here since the site is newly established. So as the quality of questions drops. They may say "Why I see this question again!?". Actually A **Really** good question is hard to find , because They are already asked before!! Stackoverflow encourage everyone in the community to search for answers , than encourage you to wait for answer to come to you. So please be patient and live in the community.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound angry, and I apologize if I came off that way. Friendliness is an important thing though. Just as important as quality questions.

Comment: It's important. But don't let it ruin your mind. I think we should focus more on how to ask page

Comment: I'm just saying that instead of trying to find a solution to a problem you have little control over, consider fixing a problem that you (I'm not saying anyone specifically, you could all be really nice) have complete control over.

Comment: What do we have complete control over? I don't. Today what can I do the best is to flag bad questions. I got at least 30 useful flags every day. It's hard to maintain both qualities of the site and feelings of new users. Please understand that. And sorry If we make you feel that we are unfriendly.

Comment: *"Many times I ask intelligent questions only to have the question closed because it's been asked before."* - I don't know if anyone has mentioned this to you before, but... if many of your questions are getting closed as duplicates, you're probably using the site wrong.  (1) You're supposed to search diligently for answers, on this site and elsewhere, before asking.  (2) Closing a question is not unfriendly; it's just part of how the system works.  If your question gets closed as a duplicate of something else, you still get an answer (on the duplicate question), so you should be grateful.

Comment: If you find the community to be unfriendly, perhaps you should [visit here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/2891664) because it's being discussed; however, this question is not about that.

Comment: I have to agree with @Denis here looking at your questions (that I can see) they don't look particularly well thought out or formatted all of which can be gained by spending a little time reading through the introductory topics in the help section. If you really want to help the community this shouldn't be a problem. That way you will learn how to better utilise the site and a lot of your frustrations will vanish.

Comment: A downvote with explanation!! This thread is talking about people that don't put any effort in searching before posting a question. The first question that you have asked on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657602/how-can-i-output-the-literal-contents-of-a-string-in-java Now come on, don't tell me you did any google search about that, plus there must be tons of questions like that already on SO. We are trying to have as less as duplicates on SO and you just adding more, you clearly haven't understand how stack exchange work yet.

Comment: I have to say that this answer, although heavily downvoted, does provide a relevant dual perspective on discussing OP. That is, is the quality of ANwSERS and comments declining? This isn

Comment: The quality of SO is the quality of both questions and answers. It does not make much sense to discuss why questions are getting worse without looking at the friendliness/unfriendliness of answers that shape the questions. As this answer suggests, if well-thought intelligent questions are encountered with harsh criticism and irrelevant answers by those who do not understand or do not care to understand the questions, why do you expect people continue to ask good questions?

Comment: The more I use this site the more it seems like a giant circle jerk.  It could fit right in as a subreddit

Comment: @D.W. I do thoroughly research my questions before I ask them. People misunderstanding my question and thinking it is a duplicate is fine, but I always point out the difference. It's only after I point out the difference that they close the question.

Comment: @ForceMagic I spent at least 10 minutes googling that question. I couldn't find it and so I asked here. People like you are the problem I have with SO.

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks, I'll check that out.

Comment: @Prime624 10 minutes worth of research effort isn't a whole lot, although I'm not saying you would've found an answer to that question - you may have had more luck looking for why a backslash doesn't print in a string. Your question is somewhat invalid though - the result you're getting is the literal contents. And people are sometimes blinded by lack of research effort regarding things that are difficult to search for. And some people might consider your question not useful, as it relates to basic syntax which you really should learn as soon as you start learning about strings.

Comment: @Dukeling What I should learn when I learn Strings is irrelevant. I didn't learn that, for whatever reason, and I am therefore asking a question. If I learned everything with the related concepts, I wouldn't be asking questions in the first place.

Comment: @Prime624 10 minutes is far too short - I wold search for 30 mins at least and then go away an thing then ask - I would expect  only to get a good answer after a day or two - i.e. let other see and vote/review the answer so just not rely on one person's view.

Answer (score -10):

Look, in short, this is place for help.  Not a place where others are going to do you work for you.  If you thought that you were going to get free work, well....  I have this bridge.....

If you're not getting the behavior that you want, you're offering the wrong incentives.  That's straight out of my business classes.

If you want better questions, incentivise asking better questions. If you want better, more polite answers, incentivise that too.

To incentivise this, allow for the down-voting of questions.  Deduct extra points for redundant questions. It should ding the asker so that eventually, they won't be able to ask anything anymore.

To incentivise polite, accurate answers, that needs to be separate from the overall "rep" score.
Add a "politeness" score and an "accuracy" score to the those who answer questions and open it to voting.  The trolls will quickly be silenced by the community.  Those who give wrong answers will quickly be voted down.  Right now, no matter how rude or wrong your answer is, if you get voted up, you get your rep points, thus there is no incentive to be either polite or accurate.

Comment: Politeness is very problematic to measure. For example, people who grew up in a British or American culture might have a very different idea of "polite" or "offensive" than I might have. My polite could be understood as borderline rude by others. Assigning a politeness value to an answer won't work very well. Besides, I don't think the site has a politeness problem in the first place. It has a Zergling rush problem.

Answer (score -11):

Well I say the answer quality is dropping on Stack Overflow!

[LOL](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/LOL#Initialism). OK, anyway...

Incentives matter. Introduce money and things will change immediately. Similar to Rugatu:
http://www.rugatu.com/

I once asked how to only look for users with more than 100 reputation points a while ago, but some people complained about that. So I created my own filter:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162190/unanswered-questions-from-users-with-reputation-100

Just remember the eventual solution might not align with Stack Exchange's business interests.

Comment: Oh man, I can already see the fraud that would result from a solution that changed the incentives from Imaginary Internet Points to actual money `:/` Not to mention an increase in hostility when people have actual money on the line.