# When to undelete a question that was deleted by the OP?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-undelete

This question [Why local classes can't have static data members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254270/why-local-classes-cant-have-static-data-members) was a duplicate. I should note that I did not find the duplicate immediately either and if I had not been so surprised that it was not asked before I may not have looked as hard as I did. It was still a good question but the OP ended up deleting the question. By the time I checked back it had gathered two undelete votes and I could vote to undelete it, but should I? I wouldn't have thought to undelete the question myself but two 10k+ users seemed to think it was worth undeleting, maybe because it only has one duplicate and may be a useful signpost. I am a little skeptical of that since the question is not really different enough but assuming good intentions on the part of the two voters (*as one commenter pointed out that may be a bad assumption*) am I missing some other good reason not to leave the post deleted? What criteria should I be using here?

Comment: Do you think is really *is* a useful signpost?  Does it use radically different terminology, does it have a lot of views, is it likely that there are a number of existing links to that post throughout the interwebs?  *Most* duplicate posts are not useful signposts.  It's rather rare for a duplicate to really add a lot of improved searchability.  It happens, yes, but generally assume that by default it won't, unless you have reason to believe otherwise, rather than assuming that by default it's a good signpost.

Comment: This irritates me no end; half way through a "nooooo! Duplicates can be useful" comment and its gone

Comment: Probably they were in the middle of writing an answer when he deleted it :)

Comment: @user000001 We wouldn't *want* people answering the duplicate.  If someone has a new answer that they feel is a lot better than any in the duplicate question, they should post it to the duplicate question.  The only reason that would be a problem is if the post *wasn't* a duplicate and someone was going to post an answer explaining how to solve this problem, and how it's different from the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @RichardTingle It irritates me to no end that so many people think that the vast majority of duplicates are useful, when in fact only a tiny percentage of them add value.

Comment: @Servy I was not convinced it was but I don't often see deleted questions get two undelete votes so quickly so I felt I might be missing something.

Comment: There's nothing useful about that post.  The original post [already has plenty of mojo](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+local+classes+can%27t+have+static+data+members).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Vote based on whether *you* think it adds value or not, rather than based on how others have voted.

Comment: At worst it does no harm by continuing to exist as a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy I get what you are saying. Usually I have a pretty strong sense of what the good decision is but in this case the two undeletes when counter to my initial instinct and there is not much in the way the covers this topic so I thought it made sense to get a check on it.

Comment: @Servy there is a lot of conflicting content out there on duplicates and clearly a wide variety of feelings so I can see why there might be some confusion about how useful duplicates can be.

Comment: @RobertHarvey seems to be the consensus, looks like it was undeleted and closed. I am guessing to prevent an undelete and answers accumulating before it could be closed?

Comment: @user000001 I can not dismiss that possibility but that would seem like abusive behavior to undelete a duplicate question just to answer it.

Comment: @Servy note "can be", and the specific time I was thinking of the OP used very different terms

Comment: @shafik I totally agree with that. It was the only motive for undeleting it that I could think at the time.