# Redefine what we mean by a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

At present we say that a question must be an exact duplicate of another question to be closed as a duplicate.

What about saying that any question that would not need to be asked if all answers to another question had been read should be closed as a duplicate?

So for example a question about way someone’s headers don’t work on their website, could be closed as a duplicate of a questions about how to debug none working headers even if the 2nd questions did not cover all the same details as the first.

Comment: We already use duplicates like that *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, some people do, but can we get more people to do so, so more of the in coming question flood can be closed.

Comment: asked and answered at MSE: [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217401/does-the-new-guidance-on-duplicate-questions-suggest-closing-a-question-as-dupli)

Comment: Be careful, a "process to follow" answer can be useful, but won't necessarily resolve a question which may actually have a more complex cause.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, the question could include details about how the process was followed to make clear it is not just another person that has done no research

Answer (score 8):

The "close as duplicate" process was always meant to consolidate *questions, not answers.*  It was never meant to serve as a proxy for "You can find your answer over here," which is essentially the moral equivalent of a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).  Nor is it a proxy for "you didn't do enough research."

If you're finding that a common question is being asked in several different, but essentially minor variations, *create a canonical/reference question,* and close the variations as dupes of that.

**Good examples of canonical questions**
[How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)
[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: There are dozens of opportunities for this within the c# tag.  But question 1, this would mean writing a question and simultaneously answering it; and question 2, what would keep fgitw smart-asses from flagging the canonical question as a duplicate?

Comment: The last time a high-profile canonical question was attempted is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618).  The author made it very clear that he was writing a canonical/reference question, and the community [begrudgingly accepted it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868), although closing `icanhazregexez` questions against it [remains controversial](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252615/102937).  It's not a great canonical question, because closing questions as dupes of it is the moral equivalent of RTFM.

Comment: The questions for most of those types of problems tend to contain the **symptoms** and not the **problem**. What you are suggesting is to group the **symptoms** (questions that all have the same/similar answers) under the **problem** (a more generic question containing information about the **problem** and how to fix it) by using the *duplicate* flag. This is one solution that utilizes the current functionality of SO efficiently and elegantly. I like it but I'm unsure of how much of our community is aware of this and how practical it will be for some questions...

Comment: In the end, when you have a problem, you google for the **symptoms** and not the **problem** otherwise you would probably already know how to solve it...

Comment: we try to do this in VBA / Excel tag where nearly 1 in 5 questions is about "finding the last row using vba" or "how to copy data from one workbook to another"... It's pretty difficult to maintain, specially that a question is usually too localized to mark it as a duplicate of another but we still, we try.