# Should there be a Stack Exchange site dedicted to "My homework to write a linked-list does not work" questions

Tags: discussion, questions, homework

I swear I see two or three nearly identical C or C++ questions about broken hand-written linked list implementations every day. The ways they are broken are all the same three or four varieties.

If it has "linked list" in the question and it doesn't use `std::list` then lets send those somewhere else. Or to a FAQ. Really. It's getting stupid.

Comment: I agree 100%. So, either find a good target as the proposed Canonical dupe, or create one: Simples!

Comment: You've got a gold badge in both c and c++. Hammer away. What's to discuss?

Comment: Just find a good dupe target like [the infamous NPE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), no need for a separate site.

Comment: We already have that site: Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: It is the time of the year, end-of-year assignments are rough on everybody.  You could put the site on pause until early June, you could help slay the dragons.  It is up to you.

Comment: I would be LOL if the situation was not so tragically bad.  The worst of it is the almost total lack of debugging attempts.  I blame Hollywood for portraying software as written by a gifted few 'smart' hackers in a few minutes and so hard work with the debugger/logger is for other people:(

Comment: Just downvote them out-of-hand.  This selfish approach of 'post anyway and let someone else put in the effort of searching' is past annoying.  Same with 'i++ + ++i' - two of those in the last hour.  A 'homework/beginners' site would be a cucumber-fest where immoral/uncaring askers give free rep to the immoral/uncaring answerers:((

Answer (score 11):

No. Although it gets proposed with some degree of regularity, creating a separate site to act as a "garbage dump" just doesn't work. We've actually even tried it before, and it was a total failure. You can imagine why: who will want to go answer questions there, when it's already been established that the questions there will be low-quality? Without experts, who will maintain the quality? Without any quality, who will want to *ask* their questions there? Yeah. Garbage and lack of moderation begets more garbage.

The questions should be kept here on Stack Overflow, as long as they are on-topic for our site. If they are not on-topic, either because they're not programming-related, because they don't contain a minimal, reproducible example, because they arise from a typo or other circumstance where the answer is unlikely to ever be helpful to others in the future, or because they are too broad to be answered in our format, then they should be closed. Please vote to close questions meeting any of those criteria, or anything else you find listed in the close reasons.

In this particular case, where you're seeing a rash of questions concerning a specific topic (like implementing a linked list by hand), it generally works best to find and enhance (or create anew) a high-quality **canonical** question, which you can use as a target to close new questions (even those that would otherwise be on-topic) as a duplicate. This canonical question should be posed rather generally; maybe something like:

> I am trying to write a linked list by hand in C++. I know that `std::list` exists and that I should use this whenever possible without reinventing the wheel, but I am trying to learn how pointers and linked lists work for educational purposes.
>
> I understand that a linked list implementation should consist of:
>
> [some pseudocode]
>
> How should I flesh this out into a complete implementation?

Then, the answer should be a high-quality answer that *explains*, in detail, the steps of writing a correct linked list implementation. Feel free to make the answer community wiki if you don't want to take on the burden of writing the whole answer yourself. Or do write the whole answer yourself, and reap the reputation rewards.

These types of canonicals add *significant value* to our community, not only as a target for closing low-quality duplicates (which, as Heretic Monkey points out, you are in an especially nice position to handle, since you have gold badges in the relevant language tags, thus giving you dupe-hammer privileges), but even just as a general reference point for others.   Since it's C++, you should add it to the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) by including that tag. I don't know about you, but I still refer to [the operator overloading FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) on a semi-regular basis, and I find it extremely useful. This could be similar.

Comment: The "SO for beginners" is discussed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252781/would-it-be-a-terrible-idea-to-split-so-up-into-a-tiered-platform to save on detailed reasoning.

Comment: I have answers of my own on "SO for beginners/homework" scattered elsewhere on Meta, too. It was easier for me to retype a summary than to go searching for a link.