# What do I do if my question happens to be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Let's imagine I ask a question and do not realize that another user has posted a similar one. Mine seems to be a duplicate (for instance somebody points to the existing similar question in the comments). What should I do? Should I delete the question? Should I flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: Flag it as a duplicate, and let the community vote to close it if they agree that it is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Read the answers, attempt to apply them, and see if it does in fact solve your problem.

Comment: @Servy OK, but what about the **duplicate** thing?

Comment: @KeillRandor First find out if it is a duplicate, since you're unsure.  You do that by reading through the answers and seeing if they solve your problem.  If it is a duplicate, you go from there, if it's not, then edit the question to distinguish it from the related question.

Comment: @vcsjones This isn't utopian world.  Very often do you find that yours is the only close vote on an [obvious duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23386011/2235132) and the answers make it evident that more duplicates exist.  Related (to the example in this comment): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252547

Comment: Don't worry about posting duplicate questions.  If it is a real FAQ, chances are that you'll get plenty of upvotes and it's unlikely that one would vote to close it.

Comment: [vote / flag to close and be happy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 "see section '1. You discover that one of the answers in duplicate solves your issue' here"). Generally, there's no need to delete it, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, no, maybe?

If you found the duplicate yourself after very little effort, then just delete your question.

If you found the duplicate after some responses to your question led you to different search methods, or after an eureka moment, close/flag your question as a dupe to increase the search profile for future visitors who might think the way you do.

Answer (score 2):

If you already found your answer on the duplicate, you can delete your question.

If answers to your question already have upvotes, vote to close your question as a duplicate of the other one.