# Is there really a problem with hoarding rep points?

Tags: discussion, reputation

It has come to my attention that StackOverflow isn't quite as good as it was a few years ago. You can debate how much it has declined, I tend to think it has declined only slightly, but it does need resolving.

Some attribute this problem to a large number of poor questions coming in, creating a disengaged group of answerers. I am sure there are other reasons that I haven't seen yet, as I'm not a very 'active' user lately.

A few years ago, while there was the potential to 'game the system', I was under the impression that most (not all) of the users, like me, would take reputation points with a grain of salt, and be willing to downvote poor content appropriately, and be polite to other users who had already answered a question, even if in the short-term it hurt their score.

1. Has this changed, is there now a measurably larger amount of people who are in it for the rep, and ignore the rest of the 'good deeds' that can be done on StackOverflow?
2. Can you point to evidence of this?
3. And finally, is this under debate or is it a general consensus among the Meta Stack Overflow users?

Comment: How do you measure whether someone is just here for the rep? Altruistic behaviour is not easy to measure - perhaps self-deletions of non-downvoted answes may be one hint, but I can't think of any other reliable metrics. Personally, I'd agree a majority of users today is the kind you describe, but then, I'm not sure whether they ever were the minority

Comment: Right, it might not be measurable. Just wondering whether it's growing or shrinking noticeably. I noticed a lower quality ratio, but assumed it due to the nature of my own questions changing over time (often people simply don't know the answer) After looking into it further, I'm thinking there's more going on. I've heard mention of rep-farming, but is that really contributing to problems more than it did 3-4 years ago?

Comment: Stack Overflow is maturing as a site.  Most of the reasonable, quickly answerable questions have already been answered.  Many of the people who remain to post questions are missing something fundamental and don't know how to post a good question or look around the site.

Comment: Most rep hoarding used to occur as a result of bikeshed questions, which we've pretty much eliminated. What remains is [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506).