# Can there be tag-specific reputation required to close questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I often get sick of seeing the flood of poorly worded, unclear questions, where the OP has not made much effort at all into doing a basic search of Google or SO. Have voted to close many questions like that.

This is NOT one of them:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415315/oracle-application-express-3-2-1-report-heading-substitutions

It doesn't even need any edit. It's a good question, clearly written, appropriately tagged. And within *10 hours* or less it has already been flagged for closing as "unclear" - by some who appear not to have any significant reputation in the technology being asked about (Oracle Apex, in this case).

Not sure how best to solve this (apart from voting to reopen, of course). Can the vote-to-close be tempered by tags at all? e.g. my vote to close a javascript question should have much less weight than my vote to close an oracle question, because of my reps in those tags.

**EDIT** - now the question is deleted! I just don't get it. If this question is so terrible, I just don't know. I've seen so many worse questions, much much worse, which survive.

Comment: How is that question actually answerable though?  There are no details, and your proposed answer as a comment seems like a wild guess made on assumptions.  I'm not sure I'd have vtc'd, but I'm sure as hell not going to vote to reopen it.  -1 to the tag restriction idea, I'd hate to be unable to vtc [crap like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23397855/168868).

Comment: What assumptions do you think I'm making? Wasn't a wild guess at all, I've faced exactly the same issue myself, and it has a simple solution.

Comment: Mind you, I'm quite happy for this suggested solution to be downvoted to oblivion, I just can't think of any better solution right now apart from education.

Comment: To your edit, it was deleted by the author, not by other users.

Comment: Ah. Well, I would not be at all surprised if they deleted it due to the apparent lack of support. I feel for newbies, sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

I've thought about this. When it comes to marking things as duplicate (and *only* that reason), it does make quite a bit of sense to give those that have earned gold tag badges in major tags more 'authority' when it comes to actually marking a duplicate. This doesn't change anything *but require less votes from experienced users in a tag in order to mark something as a duplicate*.

If you have a gold tag badge (especially in several major tags), you *know* when stuff has been asked before, and you generally know *where*. Therefore, you should be able to do something about it, as a senior maintainer of the tag. We're looking into this currently, but nothing concrete has come out of it yet. Ooops, I probably shouldn't have said anything about that yet, but oh well.

When it comes to lesser tags (which still have thousands of questions, just not tens of thousands) - you're going to end up not closing stuff that should be closed if you require rep in the tag that only a hand full of people possess. There's also the fact that people often *don't* tag properly.

tl;dr - I'm for this when it comes to duplicates, but only duplicates - because you need to have some kind of proof that the question should be closed (in the form of another nearly identical question that has been answered). "Unclear", "Too Broad", etc - entirely too subjective to open that up to one or two votes. However, I *don't* want to require rep in tags attached in order to cast close votes, I'd rather rep in the tags just *amplifies* certain kinds of votes.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat parallel I think and is something that has bothered me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748574/adding-language-support-in-offiria  this question is in no way asking for the recommendation for a tool. It's not a good question because the poster doesn't say what has been tried and what happened and it may not even be a developer question (again lack of detail) but it's certainly *not* something that should be closed because it's a request to recommend a tool because it asks no such thing.  I've seen this regularly when people who are unfamiliar with Joomla put up close votes for some kinds of questions. Maybe in another framework or in straight PHP it would be a request for a library, but in this case it's a straight question about where a file should be located.