# Does SO need an entrance?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been following ["Why is SO so negative of late?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/2940429) and ["Question quality is dropping on SO"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/2940429) a lot in the past few days and it made me curious for ways to improve the situation. Although I'm pretty new to SO I feel at home with the community already. So I'd like to share some ideas I had for possible improvements.

Concerning the many questions which a lot of us consider as **spam** I thought about a model where there would be a kind of "**entrance**" page to SO itself where people with less rep than a certain **rep threshold**, let's say somewhere between 500 and 2000 rep, would have to post their questions. Good questions (maybe 10-20 upvotes) would be automatically forwarded to the main site. This way the quality of questions on the main site would be increasing a lot.

I'm not suggesting that high rep users are restricted to the main site but maybe, to prevent some **rep farming issues** I read about in the linked topics above, they (high rep users) would not be awarded any reputation on this entrance site, unless of course it got promoted via upvote to the main site.

This is of course only a rough concept which needs a lot of thinking through, but I feel its worth considering such changes though they are somewhat drastic.

So whats your opinion? Does it sound like an improvement to you? Or is it way out of the Stack Exchange fundamentals to do such a thing? Is it even possible to implement such changes? Are they too drastic?

Comment: So, not only would we need to police the main site, we would now additionally need to police the entry site. Then, there's the issue of low quality questions still receiving loads of upvotes, thus pushing them to the main site.

Comment: There has been a lot of suggestions for separating questions by askers rep and all that I have seen are shot down quickly. It's just not reasonable for our platform

Answer (score 9):

I'm *certain* that this has been proposed before, but...ultimately, what this would do is create new problems.

- We would have another site that users would need to monitor in order to bring the questions desired into Stack Overflow.
- We would create a gulf between new users and more veteran users, giving Stack Overflow an elitist vibe.
- There would need to be tons of policing between both sites, as spam would be more likely to happen on one than the other.  Asking moderators to split their time between two (potentially) large sites isn't feasible.

So no, I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: SO already has an elitist vibe

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: You say that as if it's a bad thing. SO's goal has always been to attract the programming elite, just as other SE sites aim to attract their respective elites. SO wouldn't be what it is today if it only attracted beginners.

Comment: With SO everyone can have access to the "elite". The genius of the site is that a lot of users have moderation powers and can close bad questions in a few minutes/seconds. _that_ is the filter. It costs everyone a small amount of time, but it's part of the success of the site (check EE for instance for an example of failure)

Answer (score -9):

I'm wondering if the creation of a "Homework" or "Learning" version of SO would be beneficial.  Somewhere where the obvious homework questions could be set to (maybe a way to flag it so they get moved automatically).  This would give a "safe" place to learn while maintaining the bourgeoisie of the main SO site.

Comment: That would create a huge gulf between users (not that there isn't one already).  That, and what guarantee does one have that an expert would even look at that alternate version of SO?

Comment: What guarantee do you have that they would look at the question now?  At the moment homework questions get downvoted to oblivion, the poster ridiculed and that's about it.

Comment: And why would creating a second site change any of that?  That's not a localization problem, that's a perception problem.

Comment: I think there could be a use for such a site. Personally, I am not a beginner nor am I an expert. I can't answer many of the "interesting" questions but I can answer a lot of the questions that are ridiculed or downvoted into oblivion here and I enjoy sharing knowledge with people who actually want to learn. This applies to some homework problems where the asker isn't just saying "give me the code" but rather "I really don't understand [insert fundamental concept here]." I'd answer those questions. But admittedly this would create other moderation issues on the "learning version."

Comment: Not to mention most of those types of questions have already been answered somewhere else anyways.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a terrible idea. Some other communities (e.g. Freenode's C++ IRC channels) have a separate "entry-level" environment where those who can really stomach endless "why doesn't `j++ + ++j` work?" are free to entertain them. But I agree with the other commenters that it doesn't necessarily help with moderation, if for no other reason than we'll be constantly migrating questions between the now-two sites.

Comment: Nothing explicitly wrong with Homework questions in the first place, IMO.  As long as some effort has been put in to research them (which yes, this actually does happen...) and the question is well worded.