# "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code." should tell the user exactly how

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jsfiddle

When submitting a link to jsfiddle.net without any appropriately-formatted code blocks or code spans, the following error message is generated:

> Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

[This does not imply, in any way, that the code must be properly formatted.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TutorialFailure) Especially for a new user, [this can be downright misleading](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheComputerIsALyingBastard), since at first blush, it seems pretty obvious<sup>1</sup>:

*"I need to put my code in my question."*

But I see this all too many times: anyone who's unfamiliar with Markdown or any similar text formatting language might first try posting a code fragment without formatting it, like so (example source text):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/j5ag7/

Why this code works differently?

Here is my code.

<div>
    <p class="hilite">Example of code</p>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="hilite">More example of code</span>
</div>

.hilite {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

And find themselves still unable to submit their question, with the same error message.

*"The hell? The code is right there! Why isn't it letting my question through?! What a piece of junk."*

And they wind up doing one of the following things:

- Painstakingly figure out through some other means (help center, meta, etc) that their code needs to be formatted, and successfully post both the link and the accompanying, formatted, code. This isn't rare, and this certainly isn't an undesirable outcome, but the error message isn't helping one bit (hence this feature request).
- Not post the link, *or the code*, and get their question closed.
- Post the code (unformatted of course), but not the link, and have people whining about there not being a jsfiddle.net link even though the system doesn't require one for obvious reasons regardless.
- [Post, but mostly to whine about what a piece of junk the system is because it can't even recognize their code that is so obviously code, seriously what a piece of junk.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23448955/1)
- And who knows how many users have simply chosen to find a different site because they aren't willing to learn how to use ours, although to be fair, [they're probably the sort of users we could do without anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252534#252534).

But here's the kicker: **the system *can* recognize code, especially the unformatted kind.** If it detects unformatted code in certain circumstances, the following error message is generated:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

For whatever reason, the system never displays this message when a jsfiddle.net link is present. (Probably because the jsfiddle.net error message is taking precedence.)

There are two simple solutions here:

1. Improve the quality check to handle more cases of users posting unformatted code, especially in the context of content that *requires* formatted code, and display both error messages when appropriate.
2. Modify the jsfiddle.net error message directly. It should be enough to just copy the guidance from the other one:

   > Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Not to everyone, but that's beside the point.</sub>

Comment: Ooh, yesh. Me like. The system should also complain about tags that will disappear do to anti-XSS measures (<script></script>) and suggest that it get's turned into code.

Comment: Part of me wants to say that if you can't pass the *Markdown Litmus Test™* then perhaps we won't miss your contributions to the website.

Comment: @roippi: Yeah - I don't think referring to my example as Markdown was the best idea. Many new users don't know right off the bat that we use Markdown and I don't think it's made very obvious until you visit the editing help.

Comment: I just had my cynical pants on last night, I *do* think this is a really great possible feature - not just for jsfiddle links but for the whole site.  The percentage of neonate questioners who drop unformatted code in their first question has to be upwards of 25%; for the most part nobody makes a stink about it because it's so trivial to click edit, highlight, click the code button, submit.

Comment: To add to your list of things new users do to circumvent this message is keep both the link and their unformatted code, but intentionally break the link so the warning doesn't show up.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We've updated the error message with your suggestion, and reordered some things so that more people will get unformatted code warnings before this other error. Good suggestion!

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully it will be more helpful to users.

Comment: Whenever I attach jsfiddle link to any text, I'm getting the same error,`Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.` it looks like stackoverflow does not allow to link jsfiddle

Comment: Why cannot we just add a jsfiddle link??

Comment: cant post a simple fiddle link tsk tsk tsk