# How strict should we be when enforcing the "no external sites" or the "no code, don't paste JSfiddle link" rule?

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle, external-links

After being in SO for awhile, it occurred to me that despite pre-existing recommendations/rules, users (mostly new to the site, but there are also repeat offenders) tend to post overly-long code blocks with links to external sites, or links to JSFiddle without any actual code (they circumvent the rule by just randomly picking a word to mark as `<code>`).

With the ability to edit questions, would it be acceptable that we remove the link to external sites and leave a comment to draw OP's attention? And in the [case of questions linking to JSFiddles (or other code-hosting sites) without any actual code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253459/links-to-jsfiddle-net-must-be-accompanied-by-code-should-tell-the-user-exactl?rq=1), to remove the link to the said resource?

It just annoys me sometimes that there seems to be no common concensus on how these questions should be improved. For me, although downvoting will definitely draw the attention of OP, it might be unjustified in cases where a question is well-formatted but simply ignores the fact that external links are prone to link rot.

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Questions should be able to stand on their own without linking to external code and should be as short as possible to describe the problem. If it doesn't have the required information or if it has too much then you have appropriate closing reaons.

Comment: see also [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How much work you put into these should be roughly proportional to how useful you think the question would be *if it was asked correctly.*

- **Useless:** Down-vote.
- **Useless and misleading to folks searching:** Down-vote, vote to close ([this reason works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions)).
- **Possibly useful if it had the code:** either edit to include the code, leave a note for the asker, or vote to close as above.
- **Possibly useful even without the code:** do nothing, or make minor cleanup edits to make it easier to find.

That's assuming you do anything at all, of course. I definitely *wouldn't* bother editing out links - that just makes it harder for others to evaluate the question and burns up time you could be using on something more productive.

**Spam notes:** this isn't extremely common in my experience, but it does happen that you'll find a "question" that's nothing but a thinly-veiled vehicle for getting a link to the asker's website posted. These are usually pretty obvious, and should just be flagged as spam.

Comment: The only part of your answer I question is the "**Useless**," if it's useless I personally vote to close (which is my prerogative, of course, but I do so because I can't see the benefit of leaving a 'useless' question).

Comment: Thanks for the insightful input! I have always wanted to know if there is a general rule of thumb how to deal with bad questions or those that violate the rules. I typically only vote to close questions that are FUBAR, and don't remove links unless it links to a site flagged as spam or malware.

Comment: I don't like wasting any time on *useless* things unless they're gonna get in the way later, @David. The system cleans up an awful lot of abandoned stuff automatically, so I try to focus on what causes problems. But, as you say, your prerogative.