# Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980985/extract-an-element-from-a-template):

> So I have bought this http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.5/ template, how can I extract the banner, for modding it and inserting into my own project?
>
> I am going through all the files, but I dont want to take all the CSS, and everything, that could potentionaly mess with my current css, is there a way to safely remove just that what makes this banner work, and insert into my own project?

It can't be usefully answered without following the link, and of course,

A) The link will rot, and

B) We shouldn't have to follow off-site links to help.

While we could ask the OP to include a screenshot of the relevant banner (they can't include the HTML and CSS, presumably, as that's what they don't know how to extract), but that probably wouldn't have sufficient information, either. Quoting **all** of the HTML and CSS would probably be OTT, and probably also a violation of the license of the template.

In short: It doesn't seem like the question can be edited to fit SO's format.

Should such questions be closed? With what reason? "Unclear"? A custom off-topic?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.  How does one view an external link without an internet connection?

Comment: Yeah, pick a closing reason at random (since they took away all the good ones).

Comment: @devnull How does one view Stackoverflow without an internet connection?

Comment: @EthanHolshouser, I believe that was sarcasm. ;-)

Comment: It may have been sarcasm, but it needn’t have been. Stack Overflow content is available as an offline dump. It can be viewed easily without an Internet connection. Furthermore, external links become inaccessible over time. Content hosted here doesn’t, as we can control it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> Unclear what you are asking

would seem to be the most appropriate close reason here.

You could also leave a comment explaining that questions (like answers) should really stand on their own merits and only have external links for references etc.

If the code is too long to post in the question then that's another sign of a bad question. The OP should really be able to narrow the problem down to a few lines of code. If they're not at that stage yet then Stack Overflow isn't the place they should be posting.

Comment: Another viable standard reason: "Off topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: The only thing that would concern me about closing this is that you know what they are asking, it isn't too narrow (can help other users who search for editing this template) and it is a genuine problem. It does seem to fit the basics for being a question on here except it is a question about an external resource. In fact currently, even in its ill researched position it is still better than 90% of questions left open

Comment: @Sammaye - if they improve the question (by including the actual problem in the question itself) then it can be reopened.

Comment: Actually reading it again closer it seems like a terrible question, he is asking us to extract Html from a potentially copyrighted source for him to slap into his project and call his own

Comment: I like the copy/paste comment in the "Website is "broken", no code in question, just link to site" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments