# Why do I now have 1 reputation after posting a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I posted this question 20 minutes ago, which is now deleted and now I have 1 reputation!

> I can't seem to figure this one out, hopefully you guys can help.
>
> When I load my website, it opens up at the bottom of the page..but
>   only on mobile.
>
> Thanks in advance!
>
> The link is this [(site)](http://example.com) (is an adult site for a client, but it
>   haven't got any form of porn picture inside right now, only the
>   disclaimer image but with no nudity)

But why do I have 1 reputation now? I haven't done anything wrong, the site haven't any form of porn image inside!

Comment: If you posted the question 20 minutes ago and it was deleted, do you perhaps think that maybe your question doesn't fit our rules? Not to mention programming questions _do not belong on Meta Stack Overflow._ This question as currently written does not belong on the main site either. If you want a question to stay up and be answered, you should read the [ask] page for tips.

Comment: the question with the same text, different problem (the question where i copied the text was a problem with an autofocus) was approved and not deleted..mine first was deleted, when i copied the text was deleted because "taked me to an adult site" and now what?

Comment: As for your rep being 1 on Stack Overflow, that _is_ a valid question. (Looking at your [Reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4904377/giuseppe-de-paola?tab=reputation) it doesn't make sense here.) Perhaps a mod will see this and explain, if they see anything they can point out.

Comment: there isn't any adult content and the question is like another that wasn't been deleted..but the solution is surely different, i searche first to share my question

Comment: @Kendra:  I'm *fairly* certain that could be explained by a torrent of downvotes on a question...

Comment: yes but if the people use their eyes in the right way...it is a porn site but it isn't finished, at the moment there aren't any adult content!

Comment: For starters, your question should contain the code necessary to reproduce the problem _in the question itself._ We should not have to go to your site to see the problem, or the code involved. You instead should create an [mcve] to show us what's wrong. Also, this is a site for professionals- A lot of us use the site from work. Linking to a NSFW site, even if it's not, as you say, fully NSFW yet, could get someone who looks at it to try to help you in trouble. You don't want to get someone in trouble at work, right? (I assume not.)

Comment: No one cares about that! We do care though you aren't asking this in the right place, and it's a bad question no matter what. Also, especially if it's porn, don't use obfuscated links.

Comment: and what can you tell me about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155509/why-does-my-website-load-and-show-the-bottom-of-the-page-first?rq=1 there isn't any code!

Comment: @Makoto I figure it _is_ probably caching from the question being downvoted, yeah. It's just not _obvious_ that that's the case. If it updates shortly, then it will definitely have been caching.

Comment: Anyone that's looking at the link here - *relax*, I moved it to http://example.com.  You shouldn't run into any problems with your IT department unless they have an issue with example pages.

Comment: @Kendra:  There's definitely caching between Meta and main, that much is certain.  The fact that they're now at 1 rep instead of ~55 when we see them is indicative of that alone.

Comment: so.. i used short link beacuse i wont to index the site on stackoverflow site! Then, i don't want people have trobule but now i write that the site have adult content but with no nudity!

Comment: Leave the link alone.  People use this site at work, you know.  You don't want to take any chances.

Comment: The question you link to is older- Yes, it doesn't have any code, but it _should_ have had code. A good rule of thumb is not to look at questions that have been around for a bit- Look at questions asked in the past few days for examples of what is seen as good and what is not. The question you link to is _also_ a poor question- It should have the code needed to reproduce the issue in the question, but it too contains only a link to the site. That link breaks, the question becomes completely worthless to future readers.

Comment: what is the right way to share this question so? beacuse i imagine that i can't post the entire page code!

Comment: _"but now i write that the site have adult content but with no nudity!"_ That warning is actually enough to _prevent_ most users from looking at your site to try to help you. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help with that, by recreating the problem _without_ any even remotely questionable content. And you never know- While creating the MCVE, you may even solve your issue for yourself. Wouldn't that be handy?

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola If you feel the need to post the entire page code to express your problem, you haven't worked enough on solving the problem. You must simplify the problem. Remove parts that are irrelevant, eventually to the point that the only thing left IS the problem. At that point you wouldn't need to link to an external site to express your problem.

Comment: Additionally, linking to a site that doesn't currently contain NSFW content but will later, is just as bad as linking one that does currently contain NSFW content.

Comment: listen me guys please.. i understand that before this question there was a problem because i haven't declared the content of the site..but now what is the problem? i searche all day for an answer and i don't know where the problem will be on my page! What can i do?

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola you searched all day? so you very likely have SOME insights into your issue? You can (and should) post your question with "I saw this page... tried this solution, got this result". It's amazing you did a lot of research before coming to Stack... now please show said research? :)

Comment: This is hopeless.

Comment: i don't know why it happens beacuse in the page there arent any form of js and anything else! only html and css..i really don't know where the problem can be!

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola but you searched for a day. POST THAT. It's easy.... "you did research?" "yes!" "SHOW IT". Stop pushing back and just add that research to your question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397917/when-page-is-loaded-is-showed-by-the-bottom-side-first) that contained no code, and only contained an obfuscated link to a porn site. Members of this site flagged it as being offensive, and a moderator validated that flag. That caused a 100 point reputation penalty to be imposed on your account.

Based on your other posts, I've given you the benefit of the doubt and invalidated that flag, refunding that 100 point penalty. However, immediately going and posting that question to Meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313069/why-does-my-website-load-and-show-the-bottom-of-the-page-first) almost caused me to suspend your account when I saw that.

Simply linking to a site isn't a sufficiently good question for Stack Overflow. Your question must stand on its own if the link is missing. Additionally, I highly recommend not working around question-asking limits by posting inappropriate questions to the wrong site as you did. Also, don't hide links to your site behind an obfuscator, as that's a surefire way to raise red flags.

Comment: i will do that, thank for the support. Anyway.. i really don't know where the problem can be..so i have to post a question like this with the page code! (70 lines more or less) beacuse i don't know if the problem is on the top or on the bottom or in any other part of code! its pure css and html..

Comment: but why now i saw that someone clicked for 6 times (6 people i imagine) the down flag in a my old question? and also in another one? it is something vendicative?

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola NO, don't post the whole page. AGAIN. You did research? If you truly did it, you HAVE something. Start from 0, add the code until you see the issue happen again. Make sure EVERYTHING in the page relates to what's in it and it still reproduces the error..... and please listen to other Stack contributors (I've already told you that you need a MINIMAL example....)

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola - Questions on Stack Overflow need to be useful to more than just the asker. Work on reducing your issue to a minimum viable example, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). That by itself might identify the issue, but if it doesn't it will provide you with a code example you can post in a question. As far as the downvotes, those all came at the time you asked, not as a result of your post here. They most likely had to do with the content of your question.

Comment: okok, i will do that and also with some screenshot but without the girl of the page! Hope that anyone unvote my question only because i posted that like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310964/simulate-a-click-on-an-anchor-with-jquery this one! because it was licit!

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola - *and also with some screenshot* - What's a screenshot supposed to show people? If the problem is that it opens at the bottom of the page and you post enough code to reproduce that, we don't need a screenshot of the bottom of the page.

Comment: screenshot of what happen with different solutions, because i get different effect on the scroll because with one solution the scroll is "bouncing" and the content are all in one side of the page instead of center..i think screenshot will be userful so stop to comment only to share rhetorical question please

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola - It's not a rhetorical question. You just got a mess of trouble for posting an obfuscated link to a porn site and now you're saying you want to post screenshots. I think a lot of people will react badly to that even if there's no nudity so it's worth asking if the screenshots are even necessary. If you really want people to help you then maybe you should listen to some of the advice being given instead of coping an attitude.

Comment: so, i wont to obfuscate the link..i wont let iit indexis with stackoverflow and it is  an italian link so problably you would not understand the content also with the real link. and i said that i post screen but i will remove the background with the girl! You really don't understand? i wrote WHITOUT THE GIRL OF THE PAGE!

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola BSMP is trying to help out, basically telling you that you may be better off not having it because other users of the side may decide to flag it ANYWAY because of the site it's on. He's trying to help you out, saving you from another flagged for offensive content question. Why are you responding this way to someone who helps out? Calm down. If you need a breath of air or a glass of scotch before continuing this conversation in a civil manner, I would suggest you step out for a second...

Comment: @Giuseppe I think you're confused. Porn or no porn, the real issue is that "When I load my website, it opens up at the bottom of the page..but only on mobile. <link>" is just not a useful question. And "When I load my website, it opens up at the bottom of the page..but only on mobile. <screenshot>" is almost equally useless. At a bare minimum, include the actual code required to duplicate your issue.

Comment: its because i need an help, because i don't know where is the issue.

Comment: Not what stack is for.... we're not a help desk. You need to do your part in your question as well...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Answer (score 9):

You likely got a *lot* of downvotes.  Like, **a lot** of them on that one question. On the order of at *least* 28.

Or, more likely, [your vote was flagged as "spam" or "not welcome in our community"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history).  That would only take six people.

Some things to motivate this:

- You're not suspended, which would reset your rep to 1.
- The question doesn't show up for us mere mortals since it's now deleted
- Questions that are heavily downvoted don't generally show up in the Reputation tab for anyone besides yourself and moderators

The likely *reasons* you were downvoted:

- Your question is abysmal.  It contains no code, no real problem statement, and it comes across as you expecting us to do your debugging work for you.
- Your link contains the *potential* to take one to a porn site.  That's dangerous considering how many professionals use this site during work hours, and how IT can come down on them.

Your question can only be saved if:

- **You remove the link.**  No one should need to see the live site.
- You provide useful context into the actual problem; isolate and pinpoint what's causing the pain point and ask a question around *that*.
- Be specific about what you think it is.  Just saying "it doesn't work on mobile" isn't helpful to anyone.

Comment: okay, thanks..but can i post the entire page code? And..there is a potential..but not any form of real porn..so it is wrong..

Comment: **No.** You should first seek to isolate the code to the smallest possible piece that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola the "M" in "MCVE" means MINIMAL. Isolate it to the bare bones, showing exactly what causes your issue. If I'm helping you out for top&bottom of page, I truly do not give a flying F about what's in the middle. I need to see what's at the top, what's at the bottom, and enough code to make the loading weird.

Comment: I don't think this answers the "Why do I have 1 rep question".  Even with caching, the reputation should have been restored pretty quickly

Comment: you think the reputation will be restored?

Comment: @psubsee2003:  Let's give it another 45 minutes then.  I don't think that it takes that long for the rep to resolve, but this is something that *did* happen recently.

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola:  We'd know a bit more about the situation if you provided a link to the actual question.  It'd be better than me grasping at straws trying to determine if you had been massively downvoted or if anything else was afoot.

Comment: @Makoto fair enough.  Given the info we have here, I'm wondering if multiple users used an Offensive (or Spam) flag, which was validated when enough people flagged the same.  And that would have had a 100 rep penalty.

Comment: but why now people are clicking "down" to all my question? i have -14 of rep in 2 minutes! question that were solved and without problem F!

Comment: @psubsee2003:  I had forgotten about that...that's worth adding into the answer.

Comment: @Makoto too late - looks like Brad confirmed it

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola your other questions are being seen because of something called the "meta effect". Basically, coming here, you put your account in the spotlight. a LOT of quality-conscious cooperators then saw your question(s) and decided to act on them. It goes both ways... great questions get MORE upvotes. Bad ones get a lot more downvotes.

Comment: yes but without reason..because the older question was all licit..you can go to see..

Comment: @Patrice its true..because 6 downvote in one question (posted last week or 2 week ago idk) mean something..and now the moderator gave me the 12 of reputation that was removed for the downvote back...it mean something i think..

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola Not saying you didn't get the votes. I don't see the 6 votes on one question in your rep history, so I can't speak to it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397917/when-page-is-loaded-is-showed-by-the-bottom-side-first @Patrice

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola this is deleted. I can't see squat (10K is needed to see deleted). But the fact it got deleted would explain why you got the rep back. Now as to why it got deleted.... I cannot tell

Comment: ah okay.. problably you don't trust me but i tell the truth

Comment: @GiuseppeDePaola Where am I saying I don't trust you? I'm saying I don't have the info to give you an answer. Normally, the meta effect is CORRECT, in the sense that your question got the proper votes. Maybe it got removed because of the link to the NSFW, maybe the mod decided to remove it to help you get some rep back, maybe he misclicked .I'm saying I cannot tell you, not that you didn't get the downvotes....

Comment: @Patrice It got deleted because the question text was: "can someone help me to find out the problem with this page..the problem is only with mobile

This is the page: LINK TO THE PAGE"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot and it ONLY got 6 downvotes before that? Surprising.... See Giuseppe? This is what I was telling you: because of this meta question, more users saw your question on the main site, and voted THE PROPER WAY (downvotes here, because it isn't a good enough question for the site)