# A place to post source code?

Tags: discussion

I hope this isn't off topic, but is there a place where I can post my completed, or wip source code on here? Somewhere it can be searched for based off of tags.

Edit:
I wanted a place to host code so people could search for, and view it. Maybe snip out a relevant piece of code for questions on here, with a link back to the source code should people feel the need to look at the full project.

Comment: For what purpose? Github is a good place to post your completed or WIP code you want to share with others... ;)

Comment: (To be clear, linking to something like a Github repo doesn't work too well for questions on SO, though, since realistically nobody's gonna pore over your entire codebase in search of a bug, nor is it necessarily helpful to folks looking for a solution later either. It depends. So we're back to ... why do you want a place to upload completed code?)

Comment: I want something that people can just 'find' without me having to direct them there. And i want to be able to link the source here, if i have a question related to it(lets say.. post a snip here, and then link the full code if people wanted a better understanding off the full source) @AdamLear

Comment: Hmm. With a relevant snippet included in the question... I'd say Github (or similar) is still your best bet. We're not at the moment in the business of hosting full source code.

Comment: It sounds like you want [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/) (or equivalent).

Comment: @AdamLear mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: While @AdamLear's remarks are perfectly accurate, let's back up two steps.  Why do you feel like you need this feature to begin with?  What kind of question were you planning on asking?

Comment: @Makoto In this question >> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39323331/replacing-unknown-characters-in-a-file?noredirect=1#comment65979017_39323331) Two-Bit was confused as to _why_ i need to run the command in a specific order. That's what gave me the idea.

Comment: Fair enough.  I don't see how posting your full code would alleviate their confusion more than clearer and more precise phrasing on your part, though.

Comment: @Makoto I didn't know how to explain it and it was just making them more confused. So i wanted to know about this.

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: What is "wip source code"? And what does "based off of tags" mean?

Comment: @PeterMortensen WIP = "Work In Progress" or "Unfinished/not optimised" and by based off tags, i meant that i wanted people to be able to search, and my code come up if my defined tags are in here search.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a relevant snippet included in the question if/when needed... I'd say Github (or similar) is your best bet. We're not at the moment in the business of hosting full source code.

Having said that, linking to something like a Github repo doesn't work too well for questions on SO, though, since realistically nobody's gonna pore over your entire codebase in search of a bug, nor is it necessarily helpful to folks looking for a solution later either. There's a fine line in there somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

There shouldn't ever be a need to post this kind of content. The Stack Overflow rules and guidelines detail the creation of an [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE) for a good reason. If you have a need to post your entire code base, you in fact should be posting an MCVE. If you want to post only a partially complete code base - post relevant snippets instead.

If you can't or are not willing, then you probably are going to ask a type of question that is [not fit for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

And the answer to where to post them is the usual: inside the question, in code formatting blocks.

Comment: I wanted a place to host code for people to look at, and maybe snip out a relevant piece of code for people to view, with a link back to the code should people feel the need to look at the full project.

Comment: @austin yes and I'm trying to convince you to do the MCVE thing instead which is a pretty hard rule on SO. Questions being self-contained without a need to go to an external source are another. Keeping the content relevant to the question at hand only, so no links to personal projects or chattiness, is yet another. I'd hate to see you come back to meta to ask why your questions get downvoted or even closed because nobody tried to warn you that this site has strict [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I don't see why it should matter.. GitHub is a trusted source, and the readers will not be required to follow the link to answer the question, only if they were curious about the project at hand.