# Apparently awful question — how do I improve it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvote-reason

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615641/testing-os-exit-scenarios-in-go-with-coverage-information-coveralls-io-goverall), which has received 6 down-votes so far, and (frustratingly), nothing indicating what might be wrong with it as a question. Six downvotes is more than just one guy having a bad day: it indicates an issue with the question. I'm not whinging about it receiving downvotes (fair enough, opinions differ), but I'd really like to know how to improve my question-asking as I can only assume this is in fact a bad question. My *guess* is one of helpfulness, though to me it appears to be on a subject which is reasonably relevant to other people (sufficient that it's effectively an extension question from a presentation). What can I do to improve it?

*Note I'm not begging for answers (I did that already with the bounty which is the approved method of answer begging)—or for that matter upvotes. I just want to know how to improve the question. I believe that is compatible with the [downvote-reason](/questions/tagged/downvote-reason) tag.*

Comment: The issue in that question doesn't appear to be on SO. Rather, it's in the 2 "here" links at point `1`. Or, in other words, a relevant portion of the issue is only linked to.

Comment: @Cerbrus the code (such that it is) is all in the code block. The link is a convenience link to a github project you can just clone to avoid the fiddliness of setting up coveralls etc., because there is no easy way to 'quote' a coveralls.io 'result' without it - a screenshot would be less useful. Should I put more code in? (e.g. extracts from .travis.yml etc) and screenshots? I would have thought that would make it *harder* to read?

Comment: A screenshot is better than a link. But then, I'm not familiar with coveralls

Comment: @Cerbrus: OK I will put a screenshot in

Comment: Same for that "Slide 23" link. The question has to be answerable, even if _all_ links stop working.

Comment: It's a bit strange though that the question has 0 close votes, assuming that's the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: The question *is* answerable (well I hope so) without the links. The code in the code block contains everything that is necessary to answer it. The link just explains where the idea came from, and has (in essence) exactly the same code. The link to coveralls (the output) is for the reason above - I will put a screenshot in too.

Comment: @Cerbrus: screenshot added. Does that make it better?

Comment: related: [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: @gnat I agree that's what people seem to be thinking it's related to, though in this case the question is *not* meaningless without the links. The links are there so the response to the MCVE is not *'well, why on earth are you doing it that way?'* (at first it does seem to be a bit odd) but rather showing that this is the recommended way to accomplish the task, to illustrate the output, and to make it easier to replicate (via `git clone` as the workflow to fully replicate requires a git repository). It seems some of the problem is that I didn't make that clear enough (now fixed).

Comment: down-votes are very productive , to push people towards better things though  sometime i came across question like yours and see so many downvotes and worse thing is no comments or suggestions for improvements ,that surely doesn't look like useful , maybe sometime down-votes are like fashion , they just follow it even if they don't understand / like it

Answer (score 10):

Unsurprisingly, the original question got a pile of views after posting this question on meta. The original 4 down-votes turned into 6 down-votes, but based on the comments on the answer above, I made some changes, after which I got 9 upvotes. So, at the risk of conflating correlation and causation, I am guessing the changes I made improved the perception of the question, and here are the things I've learnt so far:

- People don't like questions which they *think* they'll need to follow links to answer, i.e. where the question itself *looks like* it does not contain an MCVE. In this case there was an MCVE there before the post to meta, but (perhaps because it was tiny) people didn't see it as an MCVE. Therefore, I called it out as an MCVE (and added a trivial function it called). Though this arguably makes the question less readable, it ensures people don't think the code is just a selective extract.
- People appear wary of links anyway. I still think I had good reason to include them (anyone wanting to test this will I suspect be grateful of a github repo they can clone as setting up `.travis.yml` etc. is boring, and it eliminated coveralls setup errors), but explaining *why* the links are included (and that they are not necessary to answer the question) appears to make people happier.
- People like to see the results - a screenshot helped, rather than just a link and an explanation.

Comment: [meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/839601) turned out favorable this time, rare case. "...people who come to complain/ask about posts on Stack Overflow on Meta are essentially inviting scrutiny and review of these posts. More often than not, it means a flurry of downvotes, close votes and delete votes on a post."

Comment: @gnat I'm presuming that the meta effect initially brought further downvotes, then I improved the question, and got upvotes. That's the assumption on which I based the rationale for this answer, anyway.