# Should links to external jsfiddle be converted to code inside the question itself?

Tags: support, external-links, on-hold

Recently my question [How does width: 100% on table-cell work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40892918/3429430) has been put on hold. The reason mentioned is:

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Although I have provided a minimal, verifiable and reproducible example. But the example is linked to external jsfiddle.

As per the current Stack Overflow, policy should I include the code of those fiddles in the question itself?

Comment: What part of " shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself" is not clear? If you disagree with that statement you may want to start "discussion" instead... but as "support" it is very unclear what kind of help you are looking for.

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). JSFiddle has been down many times. Do you know how frustrating it is when you're looking at a block of text that requires a block of code to make sense, and you can't see the code? Include everything relevant to the question in the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov _in the question itself_ was not clear to me. Sorry.

Comment: [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all JSFiddle snippets (or other external services) should also be included as code or Stack Snippets in the question itself.

If you include a JSFiddle link without any code blocks in your question, you'll get an error like this one:

> [image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Thanks. May be I overlooked the red error while posting the question.

Comment: The problem with that warning is that it does NOT appear if their is **any** code in the question. Even a reference to `<div>` negates the warning completely.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's not a perfect solution indeed, but the goal here was merely to illustrate that yes, the code must be included in the question itself.

Comment: I have added the actual code in question. Can you and others please reopen it now?