# Question asked with reference to question asked already

Tags: discussion, support

I was doing some regular edits, when I encountered [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128436/get-data-in-select-box-dropdown-when-editing-form-laravel-5-3).

The person is asking answer for another person's question with a link. I flagged this for moderator attention.

When I first encountered it, I was a bit confused, as it seems a duplicate but not completely. **Are these kind of questions allowed on Stack Overflow?** Because if yes, it will start more questions with reference to already asked questions, which could be searched directly in Google and which also makes Stack Overflow flooded with fewer interesting questions.

This question does not resemble [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266909/should-a-question-that-is-meaningless-without-viewing-an-external-link-be-closed).

Because that question includes topics around CSS and HTML, while this question is a **Meta** question, and that question has been answered as **"Undefined Question".**

Comment: i'd say yes. a question can refer to an existing question saying they are having the same problem but they should explain why the answer(s) there don't work or what is different about their situation. the linked question however doesn't do that so it's a very poor quality duplicate

Comment: Yes, seems correct this way, but without defining the details of repeating the question again. Is just a reference enough?

Comment: They made it easy for you to mark it as a duplicate because they link to the dupe in the question itself. Without anything in the post to explain why their problem is different and/or explanation why the existing answers don't work, it's just a duplicate of the question they linked to. (This actually happens more that you might think.)

Comment: So flagging it duplicate is a right action, i suppose..!

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZulqarnain Yes I also think it's the right action.

Comment: No it is not. The question that is being duplicated to another question is coding related (CSS),

Comment: The difference isn't that that other question is CSS related. The difference is that that question is about _external_ resources. This question is about the situation that answers _on an existing Stack Overflow question_ don't solve one's problem. (Either because one has a subtly different situation, or because the right answer hasn't been posted.)