# Is sharing credentials and providing access to the system allowed/is a good practise?

Tags: discussion

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50022813/681929). In the extended discussion, the OP shared his/her TeamViewer credentials with the other guys so that they can resolve his/her issue.

Screenshot of the chat:

[image: chat]

My question is: **Is it valid to have this practice on Stack Overflow?**

### EDIT 1 :

Most of the comments and few answers below are strictly focusing on use of credentials and all, but My question also involves the point made by 'rene' in comments below the question.

By having access of someone's system, the OP's problem may get resolved, but **will anyone have the reference for the future visitors that what was the actual problem, and how it got resolved.** The 'solver' may post an answer below the asked question at some point of time(may get his answer accepted too), but what about the one who asked the question, will he update the question with the exact problem he faced, or details he added while giving access to his system to the 'solver'.

and I believe the answer to the above is

### 'No'.

So,having all the discussion on platform(for ex: logs, screenshots, inputs) posted along with question will help the future visitors.

Comment: It's impossible to forbid people to do stuff like that. But I wouldn't advise anyone on doing it. And SO aims at being more than tech-support site.

Comment: The main concern is if they write an answer once the issue is resolved. If all the parties involved agree (without being pressured into it)  to share screenshots, a hangout, phonecall, teamviewer or pay a house visit  really shouldn't matter as long as the gained knowledge is fed back in to the Q/A on this site for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: Thanks for obscuring that info. Just to note I've removed it from the room now just in case...

Comment: It's not encouraged at all for a number of reasons, but ultimately it's none of our business what two consenting adults do in their spare time, especially when the data is exchanged in chat and not on the main site.

Comment: @Pekka웃However 'I' as a third person was able to breach that privacy. So I can agree with **'It's not encouraged at all'** only

Comment: @rene In that case probably they should solve the problem in chat and only post the Q&A on main when they have an actual Q&A.

Comment: @user202729 sure. The example shown by the OP rooted from a question so I commented within that context.

Comment: @JonClements note that is pretty easy to unobscure the information https://security.stackexchange.com/q/184099/27973

Comment: @Braiam I was trying to be appreciative of the effort (even though it turns out I correctly guessed what it was from the image anyway) - and pointing out the plain text version was removed so that those that are so inclinced to go and really try to work it out would have to work at it.

Comment: This may not be as big a deal as it appears.  It looks like the credentials supplied were for the Team Viewer running on the questioner's computer.  Those credentials will only work once.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Yeah... the "Partner ID" stays the same, the pin rotates and you have to have the program running and confirm connections anyway... so far from a massive risk

Comment: note that we can still read the numbers by zooming... freehand circles aren't very good at hiding info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266909/should-a-question-that-is-meaningless-without-viewing-an-external-link-be-closed)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it valid to have this practice on Stack overflow?

As far as I can see, this practice is not against the rules including:

- The [StackExchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)
- The StackOverflow Help Centre rules.

In that sense, it is valid.

However, this kind of thing is *actively discouraged*, especially in questions and answers, because of the obvious security and privacy concerns of sharing contact details, etcetera in a public searchable "space" where anyone can see them.

Whether it is our *responsibility* to do anything about it is ... debatable.  After all, people who use this site are (mostly) adults, and adults are supposed to take responsibility for their own actions.  But there is certainly nothing wrong (IMO) with:

- pointing out to newbies that it is a bad idea,
- editing contact details, credentials, etc out of Q's and A's, and
- flagging other examples for the moderators to take care of.

Note that some related things that are forbidden.  For instance, sharing *someone elses* contact details is generally forbidden by the [Content Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy).

Answer (score 1):

The user didn't give out his credential, he gave NEW (and temporary) credentials.  This should be totally fine, and under the circumstances should be preferred to the alternative.

Typicaly the team viewer credentials would be distributed either by phone or email, publishing that information to a chat just to avoid posting credentials that become useless as soon as he disconnects, would be the reverse of security/privacy.

This problem is unavoidable (and fairly trivial, as it last for the duration of the meeting), since SO doesn't have a private chat.