# Are external files in already MCVE questions valid?

Tags: discussion, questions, external-links

Are questions that already MCVE, but have external files related to the question valid?

[how run javascript with php variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392029/how-run-javascript-with-php-variables)

I think it is one of the example, which OP already posted the code to reproduce the problem, but the OP also post the run result externally (I guess it is for lazy people who refuses to run the code themselves).

My question is, if the question is already MCVE, is the external file related to the question (e.g.:post run results/what I tried) valid?

Note: I'm not asking about [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266909/should-a-question-that-is-meaningless-without-viewing-an-external-link-be-closed) because it is about questions is not MCVE without external files, but I'm asking about a question that has external files BUT STILL MCVE even if removing external files

Comment: Not sure what you mean by asking whether it's valid, do you mean whether such external links should be edited out because a MCVE already exists? If so, I don't think so, because in most cases, those external links can make the question easier to understand, even if the supplemental material isn't *required*. Imagine someone posting a JSFiddle link *as well as their code* in a question. Although a live snippet would be nicer, a JSFiddle link allows a potential answerer to immediately dive in and start debugging (rather than having to copy/paste/run in their own editor) Similar situation IMO

Comment: "I guess it is for lazy people who refuses to run the code themselves", See no evil. Don't claim people are lazy they can be on their phone. Or have a good policy of not running internet code on their computer.

Comment: On this particular question IMO, Link are picture and should use SO feature for picture so they can be displayed in the question. And won't become obsolete. Op could have spend 3 sec to use Windows capture feature and crop the picture. Delete those link only if you want to polish the question