# Why is asking "What happens if you do that and that, on that and that OS?" bad?

Tags: discussion

Here is an example of such a question:

[Does WINE implement "_printf" and similar functions in MSVCRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707953/does-wine-implement-printf-and-similar-functions-in-msvcrt)

So, I'd like to know if WINE implements "_printf" and similar functions in MSVCRT. And I offered a program written in (mostly) Assembly that can be used to test that, however, I haven't managed to install WINE to actually test that. But that apparently isn't the right strategy. So, what do you think, how can I increase the chances of getting an answer?

Comment: You don't have an on-site MCVE for one.

Comment: related: [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: I think the question you should be asking is about getting WINE set up on your Oracle Linux. On the appropriate site (not Meta), show us what you tried to do, what happened, what you were expecting instead, how you tried to solve that problem, what happened when you tried *that* l, etc, and where and why you’re stuck.

Comment: *"however, I haven't managed to install WINE to actually test that"* - I guess that changed since you posted this meta post, since your question seems to suggest you did manage to test on WINE.

Comment: @Gimby, I am not sure if I misconfigured WINE or not. I assume I somehow misconfigured it, because that appears to be the simplest explanation for the error message I am receiving. However, let's list some other possible explanations: a) WINE doesn't implement all of MSVCRT, and somehow identifies programs that try to access the unimplemented parts of MSVCRT as "corrupt". b) WINE can't run programs that FlatAssembler formats as "PE console" for some reason (even though it apparently can run console programs produced by C compilers). c)...

Comment: @FlatAssembler seems easy enough to verify, run something else. I'm sure Notepad++ is documented to work, so if you can't get that to run then your WINE installation may indeed be borked.

Comment: @Gimby Notepad++ doesn't work on my installation of WINE, however, it's also documented that you need to do some weird hacks to get Notapad++ to work on WINE. Regardless, WINE Minesweeper runs without problems.

Answer (score 20):

While we spend time on this site for free that doesn't mean we work for you for free.

This means that you invest time and effort in including everything we need in your question here on this site. And the onus is on you to provide a code example that is small enough for us to grasp and maybe run in our own environment.

You can't and shouldn't expect that you can post work orders here that are subsequently executed by volunteers and then share their debugging effort for your benefit (and hopefully others in the future).

We can assist with an actual problem you have experienced, not with stuff you only dreamed about, specially if your dream is kept off-site. That is likely not to stay there forever and so future visitors are likely to find a dead-link.

You do the effort to setup Wine, compile it and if it links, run it. If those compile, link or run steps fails come back to us with an [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: OK, well, I've edited my question. Do you think there is still something wrong with it?

Comment: @FlatAssembler it improved a bit but that bad format error does seem to happen more often, for example here: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=26368 and based on that your MRE still doesn't confirm by experiment if _printf is part of the public API of msvcrt.dll.

Comment: I'll look into that, what you linked seems like it can help me. And what do you think is a good way to determine if WINE supports, for example, _printf?

Comment: @FlatAssembler I have no idea. I know hardly anything about that topic. I just have a lucky hand when I google for error messages ....