# General question relating to what's acceptable on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

This is just a question in relation to what's acceptable to post on Stack Exchange.

For instance, is it OK to post the GitHub link for people to look at if I was experiencing slow loads for example or are code snippets better?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Code snippets are always preferred, but you can include links as well. Code snippets wont get broken like links overtime.

Comment: Links to code are generally **not ok**, unless they are only supplemental to the post, and not necessary.

Comment: And here's a source for what Yivi was saying: [How strict should we be when enforcing the “no external sites” or the “no code, don't paste JSfiddle link” rule?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260565/7795130). The same idea applies to Fiddles as it does to github or any other medium to post code.