# Improvement of searching for specific topics

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Example: I previously saw an answer covering the Command design pattern with neat sample-code, and want to find that answer again: I start my search with this string "c++ command pattern", and the list SO returns starts with C#-related questions, and perl, and ..., none of which has relevance. This shows why there are so many duplicate and low-quality questions, and I can fully understand why there is a negative attitude resulting.

These two questions: [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/15161) and [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/15161) both reflect that it is difficult to find those questions/answers that cover your question-to-be-asked.

The current keyword-searching is not sufficient, and I suggest that a more dedicated and expanded search-page that include searching within answers for keywords as well would lead to a return of quality questions, answers and attitudes.

Comment: If you use the tag notation it works: `[c++] command pattern` but I agree this should be clearer / more discoverable / easier

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour of the search engine is indeed not helping discoverability of questions.

Stack Overflow's search should recognize if one of the keywords is a popular tag, and either automatically limit the search to that tag, or offer something like

> [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2b%2b%5D%20command%20pattern) to limit your search to questions tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

Comment: Yes, but the problem is it requires knowledge of specialized search-terms that the newcomer cannot know & therefor fail to find information; a dedicated expanded search-facility will be far more useful. As it is currently a plain-vanilla Google-search is better at finding info within SO

Comment: I don't think "tagged" is a term that requires specialized knowledge.

Comment: I was referring to the square brackets and other special-to-SO formatting. (for better or worse google-searching is what people know)

Comment: @slashmais but my suggestion is to *remove* the need for the formatting by making it part of the UI, no?

Comment: Yes, see that now, I was focusing on the search suggestion using current notation in your answer. So, we agree after-all :) in part, I would go further and have a dedicated search facility where you can zoom in to the info you want by giving more and more specific terms: e.g.: "c++" gives all q' AND answers containing the term, "Command" will from within these results give only those that contain the term, "pattern" will narrow it down further, and so on, till you end up with a handful you can easily read.