# Notify users of edits in downvoted answers/questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answer-quality

Lately there have been quite a few discussions (see i.e. [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/771663) and link therein) regarding the dropping quality of new questions on SO, some of these arguing [when it is right to downvote questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/771663).

While I completely agree with the *"Please stop to be a care bear"* argument and I am prone to downvote low quality questions and answers, I feel that it is quite difficult to keep track of changes in the posts I downvoted. This may be a disincentive in those cases where the OP revises the post to improve it and I miss to retract my downvote or even turn it to an upvote.

So basically what I would like to ask is: 
**Would it be a good idea to automatically notify users of edits in questions/answers they downvoted?** **Do you think this feature will add to much clutter or it will indirectly help improving question quality?**

Comment: I like this idea, as long as I get to opt-into it, and I get to control how frequently I receive notifications (instantly, hourly, daily, etc.). If someone ends up improving their post, I would definitely consider removing my downvote. As the current situation stands, I'm unlikely to revisit questions that I have previously downvoted, unless the original poster notifies me by replying to me in a comment.

Comment: @Cupcake I definitely agree with your point: a daily notification would serve the purpose well enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, that would clutter our inboxes. We don't really care enough for that… it's bumped to the home page anyway.

Downvotes are not that big of a deal - they can quickly be canceled by upvotes. Downvotes are only a loss of 2 reputation, where as an upvote is 5 or 10.

Also, if you want notified about voting, you should start with the more extreme types of moderation first - offensive/spam, VLQ, closevotes - none of these do you have to worry about after you've submitted them. They are buried deep in your user page since nobody really cares enough to look again.

…all in addition to the fact that it would be a considerable performance hit.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I would like to have a notification for each question I downvoted that has new edits since the last time I saw it. I don't get what is your point about *offensive/spam, VLQ, closevotes*...

Comment: I was noting how the other types of votes/flags don't have to be worried about. There are forgotten about, no related notifications generated.

Answer (score -3):

*This won't be good idea* and also it burden to track down-voters.

Basically the problem is with new users or users with <2000rep.  Here are my suggestions,

1. Wait for atleast 5 minutes before you downvote a question.
2. If OP is a new users, add some comments asking to *improve the question.*

**FYI:** Don't worry that you have down-voted a question before it is revised. *Community will take care of the revised posts.*

Finally if you're interested, you can participate in [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review) to help new users.

Comment: `Community will take care of the revised posts`: I am not sure of that. Votes are rates for the answer/question: a negative vote is a downer on reading a post.

Comment: ...so if you disagree, you'd be more likely to counter-upvote.