# Is the reputation points system biased/flawed and thus provoking bad feelings lately?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

Recently on Meta a few questions have come up with huge support from the community that seem to indicate a problem with Stack Overflow becoming mainstream:

- [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)
- [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

The user [Mysticial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/1761749) has an interesting model to explain what is happening, but basically he is saying that people desperate for reputation points are fueling low-quality questions by giving them answers and moderators are being overwhelmed. This in turn in souring the heart of the community.

Reputation was great for the start of Stack Overflow, but now except for new technologies, most questions have been asked and answered. Therefore new questions are failures to find old questions or research a bit, while there is very little chance for a new user to gain reputation points. That in accordance with Stack Overflow growing all the time and finally becoming mainstream (not that surprising with USA's campaign that everybody should learn to code?).

Maybe on younger Stack Exchange sites the old reputation points system still rocks, but perhaps it is the time for Stack Overflow to acknowledge that times have changed. Praise the huge Q&A site that has been built but change the rules.

I have my own suggestions as to what these changes could look like (mostly attacking the reputation points system so "repwhoeres" have less to gain, and reputation points are less valuable, and making harder to post a question so those looking for a quick answer have to do some research first), but since I'm not an expert or even very active in the community I am most interested in how to fix the current system.

Keep in mind that failing to act now could very well destroy Stack Overflow from within. So please take this very seriously. I owe the Stack Overflow community a lot, even if my interactions have been scant, but that is because most questions were already answered or close enough.

The answers will be very interesting.

Comment: Do you have a concrete suggestion (attacking rep or otherwise) that you think would improve the situation?

Comment: Not really, when I think I got a solution I come up with faults, but I thought maybe someone smarter than me did have a good idea when thinking of the problem. I'm playing with a few ideas but don't like them enough... yet.

Comment: SO hands out programmer candy laced with crack-cocaine.  Users will do anything to get their fix, complaining about a perceived wrong to get your way is a standard addiction symptom.  It won't stop, no matter how drastic the rule changes.

Comment: @Hans, is it just me or have you become more bitter lately? If old-timers like yourself are starting to crack, what should the rest of us do? ;)

Comment: @HansPassant Of course, that doesn't mean you can't do anything at all.  It just makes it a really hard problem to work on.  A utopian Q/A site may never exist, but that doesn't mean we should give up on trying to improve.  After all, so much of what SO has done has improved quality way more than I would have thought possible after years of answering questions on older forums.  As bad as it can be at times, one only needs to spend a bit of time on some other forums to realize just how much one can actually stem the tide of crap.

Comment: @HansPassant Not on meta, hit me with down-votes I don't care, on meta they mean another thing altogether. I'm worried about the " candy laced with crack-cocaine" part though. aren't you? can't we take the crack out of the candy? or directly change the candy to apples, less demand and less addiction.

Comment: If I cared more for my personal rep, I might care more that I think it is broken. A lot of the high-rep users here commonly talk about rep-whores. That suggests a lot of high-rep users think the system is broken, otherwise why use such offensive language. What I am glad about is that I do still get good info here, and sometimes I am able to offer good advice - I think of it as giving back a bit, along with a touch of micro-blogging. 2c from a long term, low rep user.

Comment: Agree SO is getting more low quality questions. And people desperate for points answer these low quality questions.  But you have the tools: don't answer the question, vote it down, and vote to close it. You lose no rep for voting down a question. If you look at TSQL most of low quality questions do get shut down and not answered.  The problem I think SO needs to address is re-posting the  same question after they delete a closed question.

Comment: I disagree with your statement _"most questions have been asked and answered"_. It has been said in history many times that all important questions are resolved and it was never true. This is also the case for SO and programming. There will always be new problems, just think of all the new rising technologies (How old is node, AngularJS, WebRTC, Dart, ...?) and associated problems.

Comment: Just a general observation about reputation points not the actual problems: I don't really care about reputation. I'm here to learn and to teach, not to play a game. Therefore it won't really affect me but maybe there are others out there who can be steered by reputation. The only good thing about reputation in my eyes is that you can see how active someone was.

Comment: @dirkk regarding "most questions have been asked and answered";  It's true;  there are are always more good questions to answer.  The problem of late, of course, is that "most [of the low-quality] questions [that are arriving today] have [already] been asked and answered."  There's only so many times that "What's wrong with my `for` loop that looks like this: `for ( ... ) ; {}`?" needs to be asked.

Comment: I think this sort of questions came too often just recently. It's all basically the same. Even in questions that you linked this is answered. So why? Reps again? Oh please.

Comment: @aIKid I thought meta had no rep system. And have you read anything or just skimmed through... I haven't found any asnwer... yet. I don't lose hope, and I keep working on a proposal. But fixing rep is no easy task.

Comment: @Trilarion we all agree how rep should be used or what it can do for the community... the problem is not what theoretically it does, or how you or some others react to rep, but how a community of users has approached reputation and how this growing community is causing the best users to quit in disgust.

Comment: @Daren You're right that the practical solution is all that matters. And maybe the frustrated group of top users should just input some practical proposals into the discussion. I would like to see that? I think that improved filters to better ignore low quality questions might be a viable quick fix. Or we have to think about the really big question if SO really wants to play helpdesk and where to draw the red line.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm worried about. My idea is to [take away rep gains for answers of closed questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255782/shouldnt-we-revert-reputation-gains-for-answers-to-closed-questions).

Comment: Of *course* the rep system is flawed! And no matter how it's changed it will still be flawed! Just ask whoever it is that doesn't like some aspect of it. Flawed. Always. Forever. Get over it.

Comment: My previous contribution:   http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265165/rewarding-overzealous-users-for-answering-duplicate-questions-is-undermining-the

Comment: there are obviously clans voting themselves up. I mean, e.g. a question that does not meat the title, does not break down to a closed statement gets somehow some 26000 up votes. Seriously?

Comment: @SamGinrich that's not a thing. one person, nor can a group of people, create 26k different accounts and upvote a single post over 12 years undetected

Comment: @Kevin B Then there is something else, we don't know.

Answer (score 41):

A couple of observations:

1. Reputation is the way we vet questions and answers.  If not reputation, then what?  Do we just give up on the idea of vetting?  If not, then what do we replace reputation with?  Wouldn't we just be trading one problem for another?
2. There's plenty of room for improvement to the existing material on Stack Overflow.  There are lots of questions with only marginal or partial answers; I see this all the time when I'm Googling for a solution to a problem.  This is an opportunity for new users *with some actual expertise* to earn some reputation: by improving existing posts.
3. There are many unanswered questions that remain open.  Answer some of those.

The key here is *expertise.*  If someone genuinely has valuable knowledge to offer, and can offer it in a way that is instructive and useful to others, it's been my experience that such knowledge is always rewarded with reputation gain (unless your answering really obscure questions that nobody cares about).

Comment: Darn, I'm really poor at communication. I'm talking about the supposed problem where lazy people get answers from "repwhores" thus fueling the practice of poor question quality.

Comment: My answers: to 1) no, upvotes and downvotes are how we vet questions, rep is only for users. Our sociaty is higly egocentered. Rep fuels this. We can take out rep without hurting vetting of Q&A's. 2 and 3) "Repwhores" fueling bad questions are not hearing this... obviously.

Comment: @Daren maybe we need a ``repwhore'' badge

Comment: @Daren: We can take out "rep whoring" by closing and deleting the poor quality questions, which removes the reputation gained by the who answered. No more bad question, no gain for the rep whore. Downvoting the poor quality question as well will help; it gets the user's attention, it may get them suspended/banned from asking questions before it ends up being deleted, and helps move the question into the auto-deletion queue.

Comment: I used to have 15K rep. You'd never know it because I had my account voluntarily deleted for my own reasons and started anew later on. I am now a 1.9k user. I used to have access to 10K+ mod tools, I know how to review. Yea, it's my own fault that I can't access those tools anymore. I used to review tons of questions and answers daily. At any rate, it seems that the reputation is overrated. I have seen bad things done by 9k rep users as well as 15k rep users. Point is just because you are a good answerer and question asker, doesn't mean you get more privileges.

Comment: What to replace rep? Participation. Not just rep, but actual participation. Flagging, voting, time served, etc.

Comment: @staticx see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/replace-accept-rate-with-citizenship-level

Comment: @gnat: Citizenship Level was a proposed replacement for Accept Rate, not reputation points.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, and to me it makes sense as a complement to rep system, not as a replacement

Answer (score 16):

> The user Mysticial has an interesting model to explain what is happening, but basically he is saying that people desperate for rep are fueling low quality questions by giving them answers and moderators are being overwhelmed. This in turn in souring the heart of the community.

This isn't particularly new, and is fairly widely accepted among regulars here.  People answer low quality questions even though they're low quality, and this encourages people to continue to ask more low quality questions.  This is not a recent phenomena, it's just getting a lot of attention on meta in the past few days, particularly from users not traditionally meta regulars.

> Reputation was great for the start of SO, but now except for new technologies, most questions have been asked and answered. Therefore new questions are failures to find old questions or research a bit, while there is very little chance for a new user to gain rep.

This just isn't true.  There are still plenty of high quality and original questions asked on even very old technologies.  People come up with new and interesting ideas, or problems that haven't come up before, quite often.  If they *never* did then this site simply wouldn't have almost any experts, because most of them are here, and deal with all of the crap, because when they *do* run into these questions it's worth it.

Yes, there are a lot of crappy question.  Yes, a huge portion of those are related to people asking duplicate questions, or simply not doing a minimal amount of research before asking.  But that's still a very far cry from saying that *everything* has already been answered, because that's just not the case.

Comment: That's is not what I'm saying AT ALL. but the proportion of original or interesting questions is decreasing (supposedly a lot), and that is what seems the cause of trouble. I love SO and maybe twice per year I do come up with a question I cannot find an answer. And I'm working with old technologies.

Comment: @Daren The flood of crappy questions, and the problem of trying to get rid of them, is not new.  It's gotten some extra attention recently, but it has been an epic battle throughout the site's history.  We're always looking for ways of improving our ability to get rid of crap, or prevent it from being posted to begin with, and while the problem does tend to get worse as the scale of the site goes up, the problem isn't really fundamentally any different now that it was a year ago, or a year before that.  This is the [recency illusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion) at work.

Comment: Specifically, you don't see crappy questions from a year ago, but that's not because none were posted, they've just been cleaned up.

Comment: @Servy, I've been served that argument several times, and believe it or not I still think a sudden, apparently irrevocable, perfectly measurable decrease in quality in a six-months time frame trumps recency illusion any day.

Comment: @Servy Ok, maybe it was all just part of a big scare... I'm glad to know about it but you know how ideas spread... the meme got a hold in my head and I thought it was a real problem, that recently was getting worse (that graphic is scary: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252547/1761749 )

Comment: @Daren Of course low quality questions are a real problem.  Of course it's serious.  Of course we should do something about it.  It's just not new.  Crime has been a problem for a long time, so has poverty, hunger, and racism.  They aren't new problems, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't still work to solve them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've observed *plenty* of really bad content for quite a long time.  I haven't seen any really seriously dramatic changes in the past six months.  I also spent a lot of my time on the site focusing on reviewing content, locating and addressing problematic content, etc. for quite a long time.  It's something I've been focusing on.  Perhaps you've simply started looking for these problems more over the past six months, and have had your eyes opened to a lot of the problems that have actually been around for years.

Comment: @Servy: With regard to your first paragraph, I couldn't agree more. I can think of at least one example in the past week where a very high-rep user (top 100 on SO) posted an answer to a totally non-question (complete with a meaningless, non-compiling, nonsense code fragment). The question was closed fairly quickly, but the fact that the user who should have known better took a SWAG at the intent and posted an answer instead of just downvoting/voting to close is quite irritating.

Answer (score 9):

The question here is whether the rep system as defined is serving the needs of stackoverflow.com, and whether there's an alternative that would serve those needs better.

Right now, it seems as if the top priority of the site is *janitors*. But janitorial service is rewarded only with badges. The only exception is edits, and the edit reward system turns into another machine for rewarding turd polishing, since there's no quality control except the audits.

Here are some ideas that have been floated to use the rep system to reward janitorial service or improve the effectiveness of the existing robo-janitors:

- rep punishment for answering crap questions.
- rep reward for closing and deleting.
- rep floor for question upvotes.

Another line of attack, of course, is even more aggressive use of NLP robo-janitorial services to prevent the crap questions from entering the picture in the first place. Since only the team knows how much NLP they've deployed so far, none of the rest of us can make intelligent suggestions.

Comment: +1... I posted something that is pretty similar to your answer here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254593/give-low-rep-users-a-little-rep-for-being-correct-about-close-votes

Comment: This is the best and most precise answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the reputation system is flawed. Maybe it could actually be exploited in this case.

I work as researcher in Brazil (I got here on SO because I'm interested in Python), so let me give you an example from my field. Researchers have to manage students with different experiences and capabilities - from postdocs, to PhD students, to undergrads. A researcher can't teach the same techniques over and over to every single undergrad that appears (even because most of them will be finished and gone in less than a year). Even a postdoc might be frustrated in having to take care of undegrads, because their level of expertise is very different. What happens instead is that postdocs help PhD/master students, and PhD/master students help undergrads, so that every class of "tutor" student still remembers how it felt like being a "clueless" student. The problems faced by the less experienced student are often still not trivial to its student tutor, which benefits from helping.
I believe that the situation is similar here on SO. I actually do benefit from putting myself on another rookie's shoes and trying to help on a problem. Solving real-world scenarios is intrinsically rewarding. So rookies can benefit from questions even when they're trivial to experienced users - of course excluding those clearly asked out of laziness.

So, to cut the story short - I would suggest to actually exploit the reputation system by adding a "fiter-by-asker-reputation" feature to the site. Us "newbies" would keep questions unfiltered and help each other out on the simple errors we make.  Experienced users could use the filter to only see questions posted by other experienced users.

Do you people think this would help?

Comment: I like this approach. It puts less emphasis on fighting the wave and more emphasis on better filters to ignore what you don't like. The problem is though to find the filters that actually make sense. There can come good questions from absolute unknowns too.

Answer (score 4):

As a new (registered) user to SO/SE, I find that my original motivation to contribute was to get over the initial reputation requirements, and I spent a bit of time camping the PHP/MySQL tags and rushing to answer a simple question in hopes of getting an upvote or two, and maybe getting a checkmark. As soon as I hit about 150, I stopped because it's not very personally rewarding for me.

Certainly, I could keep racing to get answers in to crappy questions just to boost rep, but I feel like that undermines the whole purpose of the site (and I definitely contributed to that in order to break a few privilege barriers).

Unfortunately, the rep system is currently set up to provide instant gratification, and there's more immediate incentive to ask (and answer) a low-quality question than anything else. If I respond to a question noting that they should looking into why `mysql_*` PHP functions shouldn't be used, or the fundamentals behind Object-Oriented design, someone else is going to jump right in and provide an answer (which may reinforce the use of deprecated functions or practices), and that answer will be rewarded.

Comment: You stopped doing this after just a few questions.  Other people still haven't stopped doing this after *thousands* of questions.  That's a problem.

Comment: I too have recently joined SO and have noticed a bit of rep-whoring in my own actions (also just to get some minimum level of rep to allow me to use the site's features). It seems a lot of the low quality is due to first-time questioners looking for simple help on class assignments. Perhaps I'm missing something, but why aren't the First Posts Access Review Queues filtering out nearly all of these low-quality questions so they never see the light of day?

Comment: @JimMSDN, I spent some time in the first post review queue and there is no close flag for "homework dump". The best you can do is leave a comment telling the poster we won't do his homework for him, and downvote.

Comment: And the rep system works strangely, answers to simple questions get upvoted several times but an answer to a non-trivial question that requires research often gets at best an accept plus the OPs upvote. So there are bad incentives. I'm thinking about spending my time looking at questions with bonuses, because waiting around for someone to ask again about the differences in division between python3 and python2 feels rather silly.

Comment: @user3114046 Maybe, then, that's a solution - at least in some of the groups I frequent, a "homework dump" (and I like the term!) close flag would quash quite a few low-value posts.  Thanks for the info on how those queues work (or don't), as I don't...have enough rep to see them myself...

Answer (score 4):

> Reputation was great for the start of Stack Overflow, but now except for new
>   technologies, most questions have been asked and answered.

Do not assume that because a question has been answered, that is it. Even
questions with accepted answer I go after. Many times I have found I did not
like any of the answers, so I went out and found my own way. Here is an example

https://superuser.com/q/129269

Question was asked 4 years ago, already had 3 answers and one was accepted. Well
I didnt like them so I put my own and the OP saw it and accepted my new 0 vote
answer when top answer had 10 votes. If you want the points go get them, it is
only your own self stopping you.

Comment: Which is an example of the system working well, but [meanwhile on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=4) #3 this year from repeatedly answering 0 score pattern matching questions.

Comment: @OGHaza who cares? He is happy, the question askers are happy. If you dont like it then downvote/close as has been said many times.

Comment: But that's what we're talking about here. I don't care what he's doing, but I know if I want fast rep and moderator privileges, the fast path is to go answer exactly the sort of question we (I?) don't want on SO.

Comment: @OGHaza if you rep whore, that is your business. The point is no matter if you do or not, checks are in place to get bad questions closed/deleted.

Comment: You have just edited my post. I feel like there should be a link explaining this kind of edit. Mind to provide one?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea.  What if in addition to the up/down voting, there was a *secondary* quality scale with each question and answer?

It would be on a fixed scale, perhaps 0 - 10, or visualized as a color gradient from red to yellow to green.  Each user can vote on the quality, anywhere along the scale.  In other words, instead of voting +1 or -1, I'd still do that, but I'd also give a quality of 8.

The question or answer's overall quality is thus the *average* of the quality scores, not the total.

Now here's the fun part:  Let the quality rating be used to pad the regular rep over time.  the more time that goes by, the more points are added or subtracted from the rep earned by the vote.  The level of quality can control the rate at which this happens.  For example, a question with a 7 might add 2 rep points per week.  A question with a 10 might add 5 rep points per week.  A question with a 3 would *subtract* 2 rep points per week, etc.

This would mean that the longer a high quality question is still accurate and relevant, the more rep it will generate for the person that contributed it - all on its own.  That should encourage people to edit and prune their questions and answers to get a higher quality score.

Conversely, the longer a bad question or answer sits around, the more it would work against the author until it was closed or deleted.  This would hopefully encourage people to edit or delete bad posts.  Even posts with high quality scores initially might eventually go sour, as technology changes over time.  This would help authors hone in on the posts that need updating or pruning.

It might be interesting to play with the scale for this.  Perhaps all items start at the middle of the scale and individual quality votes would just nudge it forward or backward, or just help weight it in that direction.  In other words, a single vote for quality 10 shouldn't get the author to start earning rep points - but perhaps two or three votes for 10 would move a pointer closer towards the 10 mark.  I'm not exactly sure what algorithm would be best here - I'm sure smarter folks than I can figure out a good weighted average formula.

Comment: Hey! I actually like it! Possible improvement: instead of giving points over time, the quality influences the points given by the votes: quality 1 with 10 upvotes, = only 10 points, quality 10 with 10 upvotes, means 200 points for the user. Wait, this does not help poor quality questions get deleted... :( Still adding a quality filter would help gurus focus on high quality questions in need of answers.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce low-quality questions that are duplicate and being answered by users only for gaining quick points, I would like to suggest minor changes to current system in the following ways:

1. **Award points to the comment that shares the link to a valid existing answer/question.** It serves the purpose to address the question and satisfy the purpose of giving credits to the SO user who pays attention to maintain the quality instead of trying to gain some quick easy points.
2. **Identify the user with history of asking questions that were all duplicates of old questions with good answers.** Give warning or block the user from asking for a period of time because it is the sign of manipulating the system for others to work hard finding answers for an already solved issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see two reasons why users might want to answer crappy questions:

They desperately want reputation or they are just too nice?

In the first case I propose to change the reputation so that nobody thinks he must answer crappy questions. Making reputation less important might be one way to go, having other sources of getting reputation early (for example improving old answers) or simply underweighting reputation from crappy questions.

In the second case what do you want to do? Forbid the answering of crappy questions? Having a crappy question police? Then the question would be what SO wants to be: assorted top quality questions or just everyday questions that only show a minimum of research? The later will always be about ordinary programming problems that most of the skilled programmers probably not have. And about duplicates which are probably an increasing problem.

For the very crappy questions the current tools seem to be sufficient. Flagging as not enough research can alienate newbies quickly enough if necessary.

---

edit: I add a concrete proposal. As an experiment have a simple three way categorization of each question (scholar, advanced, expert) that is determined by voting and tells if the question has a learning (scholar), everyday use (advanced) or esoteric expert (expert) background. That way the frustrated top users can avoid the helpdesk questions simply by filtering away while the rep-whores can do their whoring. Everyone would be served better by this if only the filtering does the right job. Not sure about that. Please note that this proposal is not new, it has already been discussed probably several times. But I think it is also related to the actual discussion.

Answer (score -1):

I think one solution is to remove (or at least reduce) the 50-reputation requirement for commenting on others' answers. There have been a few times in which I had some information I felt would add to the discussion but was more appropriate as a comment. On sites where I did not have the required 50 reputation, I had to post my would-be comment as an "answer" even though it was less relevant to main question. I'm sure other people have done the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

**Chuck raw scores, beef up badges, use a log scale**

This is a proposal for moving Stack Overflow to a slightly different scoring system that is less linear and encourages broad knowledge diversity.  Instead of raw sums of reputation, we categorize it by tag and count it as badges.  Badges are counted on a log scale (count the powers of two).  Your reputation score is the sum of each badge's count.

**Case study:  Slashdot**

Slashdot has an Achievements system (here's an [example](http://slashdot.org/~Hemos/achievements) since the docs aren't so good) that could work here, with some modification.  First, I'll describe how Slashdot's system works.

Slashdot achievements are basically badges.  Some of them are one-offs while others are counted by powers of two (there are others, too: "years read" is summed while "Member of the x digit UID club" has its own logic (6-digits) to bolster older users).  Total achievement score is the sum of the count of badges plus the sum of their powers of two (this extra counting allows immediate feedback for your first hit, which would be 2⁰).  If you've visited the site ten days in a row, you get 4 points (8 is 2³, 3+1=4) and need six more days for the 5th point.  If you've visited 64 days in a row, that isn't really different from 127 days (both are a lot!), so achievements aren't handed out as readily; find another way to bump up your score.

There are flaws in the Slashdot system; achievements were implemented as a persistent April Fools' Day prank and aren't actually worked into the site in any way.  The Karma system, which is merely a linear count of your +1s vs your -1s, caps at 30, and merely wins you a base +1 to your comments at some threshold that I have forgotten.  The count itself has been hidden for ten or so years.  Another flaw is that nobody has more than fifty or so achievements (well, not counting the [site founder](http://slashdot.org/~CmdrTaco/achievements), who awarded himself "the cheater").

**Proposal for Stack Overflow**

What if Stack Overflow (or all Stack Exchange sites?) had a similar system?  Badges aren't really geared to be obtained at a frequency to be counted exponentially, which is fine.  Count the existing ones (well, those that aren't adapted for the log scale) linearly.  Add more badges (take examples from Slashdot).  Take users' existing reputation and break it up by tag (just the prevailing tag for the question, and tag synonyms will be essential here) and you have something to count by powers of two.  Then add up your badges as normal.

While this will result in far lower overall scores, users with the same diversity of answers should still have the same distance (though on a different scale).  The permissions system would have to be reworked to handle this change.  After it is reworked, it will actually feel more intuitive (it's already ~exponential, so most steps in reputation growth would coincide with new permissions).

Bounties would be their own badges, divided by tag and by color, at the cost of a badge of the same color, in the form of a "negative badge."  I also see value in also rewarding positive badges for high volumes of bounties given (since it helps the community).  This is fine as long as the pool of available badges for posting bounties doesn't count these particular positive badges or else you get a feedback loop (if it's scaled correctly, it's not a problem.  It'd be akin to a "buy ten, get one free" program).

I'd also like to see a "green" badge for bounties that would allow people to post bounties with real money (and/or previously awarded green badges) rather than reputation (to prevent abuse, a payment source (think ~credit card rather than bounty poster) would be able to reward a green badge bounty only once per user), but that's an aside.

Badge colors (bronze, silver, gold) indicate their rarity.  The final score should merely sum them all.  No weights would be necessary.  With each badge color, you have a separate bucket which holds its own value; you'll have lots of bronze badges and they'll increment slower, so you'll seek out the silver badges.  Gold badges, being the rarest, will always have a bigger impact on your total score merely thanks to their scarcity.

This encourages users to help in less common categories.  If you have 12 javascript badges (2¹¹+1) from 2k answers and zero java answers, you need another 2k javascript answers to get to 13 but only one java answer will increase your overall reputation by the same amount, so you are incentivized to diversify.  This will help boost questions on obscure topics.

Comment: you lost me at "allow people to post bounties with real money"

Answer (score -1):

As a pretty experienced programmer who reads much and asks little, I *hate* the reputation system here. I spent about an hour once trying to cruise crappy PHP questions to get some points, then gave up. I experience every little AJAX box telling me I can't upvote a good answer, and the lack of comment upvoting, as an insult.

I don't use StackOverflow a ton for *posting* so it's not yet been worth my time to try to spearfish a good question with a good answer, and I shouldn't really have to do so IMNSHO. I can absolutely see why people would pound reload on the questions and answer the first one they see, just to be able to use the g*ddamn buttons in the UI.

I'm quite capable of giving good answers, but StackOverflow's reputation system has, frankly, kept most of my (often voluminous) posting to mailing lists, forums (blech), blog posts and Twitter when talking about programming. Once I get an answer I try to cruise topics I know to "pay it forward" but both the rep system and the crappy questions make it frustrating.

**Idea:** Maybe have a community-edited "basic skills test" that a user to any SO can take to get enough rep to be able to use the buttons in the UI. I also like the idea above from @Roberto about experience-level filters, though it might be pretty problematic to implement.

Answer (score -1):

The way I see it, the rep system is used simultaneously for different purposes (maybe not intended) and this causes problems.

**Internet points**

This has been discussed enough already so I'm not going to talk more about rep in this form.

**Rights to do certain things in the UI**

This one kind of vexed me when I started using Stackoverflow. It took me several hours of answering questions to get enough rep to comment. Upvoting is easy enough to get.

**Upvotes to indicate a good answer**

This one is pretty straightforward as well. In just this aspect, there is no problem with simple questions/answers getting more upvotes as they all stay relative to the question.

**Rep as an indicator of expertise or community involvement**

I had this notion wrongly when I first browsed stackoverflow, before knowing the system. I don't feel it matters too much except maybe minor impact on credibility and maybe intimidating new users. Given that stackoverflow questions are rather technical, credibility is not as important as just giving a good answer.

**Rep as a currency**

Given that you can give out a bounty for having a question answered, rep has an actual value that isn't related to your (self-)image. A value that you can use to get help getting your hard questions answered. Here is where the high-rep simple questions cause trouble. People with low rep cannot put out bounties. Getting rep is not a straightforward exercise of putting in the effort and being rewarded for your effort and expertise. It's more a function of popularity of the question and being first. So in the long run, it might be a more effective technique to try to answer a lot of simple questions quickly in hopes of getting lucky as opposed to answering difficult questions. In general, both types of questions give similar amounts of rep (an accept and maybe a couple of upvotes), but the simpler ones require less work and the payoff can be significantly higher. In this view of rep, why would anyone waste their time answering harder questions unless they have a bounty on them? This in turn raises the average bounty you need to put to get an answer to your difficult question.

**Solutions**

- Give a set rep per answered question and the rep gets divided in function of accept and upvotes (similar to now). For example each question gets 100, for a question that has 2 answers with the question upvotes twice, answer1 accepted and upvoted once and answer2 upvoted 5 times: question asker gets 100*10/(10+25+50), answer1 gets 100*25/(10+25+50), answer2 gets 100*50/(10+25+50).
- Not necessarily show the rep of a user. This would be mainly for the Rep as an indicator of expertise. I don't really care too much about it to be honest, but I like to be complete.
- Maybe some other way to get the basic UI rights (comments). Either grant comment rights together with upvoting rights or give comment rights under review (so they could be temporarily blocked in case of abuse).

Answer (score -6):

Yes, it does provoke bad feelings. I can't tell you how many times I've wanted to make an honest-to-god helpful comment on a post only to be told i can't because my reputation isn't high enough. "How am I supposed to grind rep if I can't participate in the conversation ?!?" I would yell. The answer, of course is to ask questions and provide answers, etc.. But this is not a good way to determine reputation. Three points to consider:

1. The current reputation mechanism is subject to manipulation on a high degree. While the reputation system seems designed to prevent spam and cruft from getting in the system (at least in part), by tying question asking, voting, and answering to reputation, it seems that the system actually **encourages** users to spam -- that is to ask meaningless or disingenuous questions.
2. the current reputation system is likely a biased signal of quality.Readers will systematically misidentify good answers from **new** users as being of poor quality. This is the case because a new user posting a good answer has the same rep as a user who has been around for a long time and has been consistently down voted (i.e. a genuine bad-apple). Meanwhile, readers will systematically over identify bad answers from users with **old** users with good rep as being high-quality answers.
3. The use of reputation as a barrier to entry prevents the spread of genuine knowledge. This is why submissions in a true peer-review process are anonymized.
   Tying access to site functionality like comments (especially comments) prevents new users from making thoughtful contributions that don't really warrant posting as an answer (this very post being a good example) and prevents them from distinguishing themselves from the 'genuine bad-apple'.

Over time, the reputation system (as it stands) seems to promote a scenario wherein high-rep users become an increasingly exclusive and impenetrable club. This is anathema to the democratic/marketplace-of-ideas approach that SE seems to want.

To correct, I propose the following that would help make reputation more useful and still limit reader exposure to cruft/spam:

1. provide greater access to site functionality to users of all rep levels (especially comments as comments are meaningful avenues for dialog and knowledge contribution). Retain a more limited set of access privileges as tied to reputation to still encourage people to care about their rep (and therefore avoid posting total garbage).

   - In truth, for many of the SE subsites, i'm not sure how much needs to actually be done to encourage users to actually care about their rep. In most of the SE subsites that I've frequent (cross validated, math, R, latex), people seem to genuinely care about proivding good information and cultivating knowledge.
   - Just tying cachet to rep may be enough. In other words, less draconian things like name-tag flair may be enough to encourage readers to care about and guard their rep.
2. place visibility thresholds on bad/spammy answers. If an answer/comment does not receive at least (x) upvotes within a certain period of time, or if it recieves (y) downvotes, then it is hidden from view, deleted, shaded in grey or posted lower on the page.

   - This removes garbage posts (or at least hides them) while (if the prior change is implemented) still encouraging contributions. This strikes me as a far more reasonable solution and one that lowers the barriers for new users (who are probably quite knowledgeable to make contributions.
   - I can see how this might be a problem in some SE sites where comments and things are likely to get opinionated (devolving into flame wars etc). But most SE sites that I'm familiar with are knowledge based forums where people rarely express strong opinions and instead try to help one another with technical problems. There are myriad other sites that fulfill this role and do not have the draconian rep system used here. Yet most of those sites also seem to provide thoughtful advice and stay on topic.

Comment: I disagree with point 2.  There is a strong correlation between very low rep (like 1- 11) and poorly formatted/incomplete posts.  This is because of the familiarity of site rules and culture that higher rep users have that very low rep users don't.  And some people even try to be more lenient for posts they see in first-post queue and upvote more of the borderline stuff just to help new users get above the 50 rep mark.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I agree that there is a correlation between low rep and poorly formatted posts, but new users enter with very low rep. This makes low rep a noisy signal for quality. If it's not a source of bias it's at least highly error prone.

Comment: The point @ryanyu tries to make is that you are mistaking correlation (low rep and bad posts are correlated) with causation (low rep means bad reception). He even says that some users actually have the opposite bias. Yes, having to tie priviliges to reputation as the only available measure of involvement and trust isn' optimal, but there is no way to assay someones contributions merit without him having done some and having had them judged. Extending trust for most actions before that miniscule hurdle is passed just allows too much abuse and spam into the system to combat manually.

Comment: SE my comment before I was done writing. I assure you, i am not mistaking correlation for causation. The point I am making is one about measurement bias and the subsequent consequences of interpreting a biased measurement.  In fact, the PRECISE argument I am making is that the reputation you have is polycausal -- that low reputation can be caused by multiple factors (newness to the site or bad posts) but that most people will heuristically identify low reputation with bad posts (and fail to consider newness).

Comment: As for assessing the merrit of answers, discussion itself can bear that out. As can voting, commentary, citation of sources, and (in the case of programming questions -- seemingly the vast majority of questions on this site) example code.