# Only enable positive reputation to be awarded on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, reputation, downvotes

I question how useful negative reputation is for meeting the needs of people using Stack Overflow and also for Stack Overflow meeting its objectives.

I understand that negative reputation can be a useful way to communicate to a user that they have fallen short of a standard that would be good for them and for Stack Overflow to reach. However, I think it is possible that awarding positive reputation alone, or of course *not* awarding it, might be as effective at achieving this.

I think it is worth considering the possible downsides of negative reputation for individuals and for Stack Overflow. It is likely that negative reputation drives many unhelpful interactions between users which do not contribute to the quality of the site.

I personally feel I have been motivated to try and meet the standards Stack Overflow tries to encourage more by the positive reputation I have received when I have got things right (for example formatting a question properly) than by the negative reputation I have received when I got it wrong. Negativity, especially when not accompanied by an explanation, is undermining for many people.

I would have thought that data could be brought to bear on this question by people with an interest in psychology although I am unaware of any. I also feel that in a world where good mental health is not guaranteed it might be sensible to try and promote a kinder model.

I would be interested in your perspectives and of course your up and down votes.

I thought the following question was quite interesting in relation to this: [Ideas for proposals to help Stack Overflow create a more positive community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298693/ideas-for-proposals-to-help-stack-overflow-create-a-more-positive-community)

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to loads of users just spamming questions/answers hoping for the occasional upvote, since they would never get punished by downvotes.

Comment: Related [Is the reputation points system biased/flawed and thus provoking bad feelings lately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254202/1595451)

Comment: "Negativity, especially when not accompanied by an explanation, is undermining for many people." Assuming that by "negativity", you mean "downvotes", it's worth noting that when downvotes *are* accompanied by an explanation, they are often met with denial at best, and at worst, flat-out abuse. Many users avoid explaining their downvotes not to be negative themselves, but to avoid the negativity that they themselves receive in turn.

Comment: this is going to sound harsh, but we honestly couldn't care less about discouraging users from posting questions. We are a *library*, not a help forum. We get more than 5000 questions a day, most of which are, frankly, complete garbage. We don't need more of that.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253227/how-can-we-discourage-over-downvoting-on-questions/253230?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C14.9906#253230

Comment: See the highly related (while probably not a duplicate) [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/6045800)

Comment: Related (Might be a duplicate if you mean to remove downvotes and not just removing the decrease in reputation): [Why are proposed changes to voting, which limit or remove the use of downvotes, met with strong disagreement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405699/why-are-proposed-changes-to-voting-which-limit-or-remove-the-use-of-downvotes)

Comment: @F1Krazy Your comment does illustrate how upsetting people people find bein downvoted and how quickly it leads to a lack of communication. I think if we removed the downvote and kept the constructive criticism it might lead to better dialogue.

Comment: I guess you assume that every user (or at least most) have the best interest of the site in their mind, but this isn't the case. Due to the size it attracts more users who couldn't care less about the site or its rules. They want their questions answered, nothing else. That's why many are upset by getting their questions closed and downvoted, it hinders them to get more homework done by other people. There are a lot of those users already and way to few cleaning up the mess they left behind. There are other sites those "messy" people can go to, doesn't need to be Stack Overflow.

Comment: Look up "Yahoo Answers" to see what would happen if we got rid of negative voting. It's the ability to curate content that has made this site succeed where other sites have failed.

Comment: “I question how useful negative reputation is for meeting the needs of people using Stack Overflow and also for Stack Overflow meeting its objectives.” - **Well I question how upvotes are useful, I think we should flip the paradigm, and only allow downvotes.** Anything that isn’t unhelpful must be helpful after all.

Comment: “I think if we removed the downvote and kept the constructive criticism it might lead to better dialogue.” - Spoken from someone who hasn’t had every single question they have asked in their main community, downvoted, because of feedback on someone’s question in another community. It’s the reason my main community is hidden from the toxicity from Stack Overflow, not talking about those kind souls that downvote absolutely horrible questions, talking about the toxic author’s of those horrible questions.

Answer (score 24):

Both positive and negative reinforcement is needed. Positive reputation gain helps attract more users to participate on the site. They post questions and answer them in hopes of getting fake internet points. Negative reputation gain is needed to deter people from posting unhelpful questions and answers. It's actually not a huge reputation loss for a single downvote and is easily outweighed by a single upvote.

If at least 1 in 5 posts gets an upvote then a user is still receiving a net-positive reputation. The reputation loss is very tiny and it could be larger. However, as you noted, human psychology makes it so that any loss can be undermining. Even if it's only 2 points that mean almost nothing, people feel they lost something that they should regain. If the loss from a downvote would be -10 points then we would lose many participants because regaining that lost reputation would become much more difficult. With only -2 it nudges people towards posting something else that is more useful in hopes of regaining that lost reputation.

Reputation loss is also a penalty. A user that is consistently posting bad content should see some punishment. Wrong answers are not against the rules of Stack Overflow, so the only way we have to punish them is by designing a system so that they lose their reputation points from posting unhelpful or even wrong posts.

IMHO we should keep negative reputation gain because it serves as a form of encouragement to post better content and as a deterrent from posting bad content.

Comment: I agree that negative reputation does inhibit me from asking what I think will be perceived to be a bad question. On the other hand an answer to that question might be very helpful for me and possibly other people. I think there may be a conflict between the aim of trying to create a repository of good questions without duplication and the aim of just trying to help people who are stuck and do not have many other avenues for help than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user3425506 "negative reputation does inhibit me from asking what I think will be perceived to be a bad question. On the other hand" There is no other hand. This isn't a help desk. "the aim of just trying to help people who are stuck" Not an aim, you have not informed yourself re the site goals. "do not have many other avenues for help" Because other sites don't have the quality standards. You want to have your cake & eat it too.