# Is answering bad-quality questions considered a positive or a negative contribution to StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

When a bad-quality question (for example the typical fix-my-code question) gets answered instead of being closed/downvoted, or in addition to being closed/downvoted, is it considered that the site is better-off for it, or worse-off for it?

Is there any consensus on this? Also, is it known what the site's owners' position is on that?

This question came to me after reading [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: An approach I'm moving towards is to mark those poor quality questions as a duplicate of a question that covers the underlying problem. My opinion is that answering them directly is bad for the site.

Comment: Does "Flag for close/off-topic/can not be reproduced or typo" reason applies when "fix-my-code" question contains some trivial problems covered in basis tutorials? The reason explanation even contains the following text "this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers", which, I think, covers 99.9% of "fix-my-code" questions.

Answer (score 16):

### What's the disadvantage of answering them?

Provides positive reinforcement (for both the question asker and others) that they can ask these questions here (despite comment and down- and close votes). Either they may not realize that their question is not appropriate because of the answer(s), or not care, because they still get an answer.

With constant positive reinforcement for those asking these questions, we'll never be able to stop them, even with eventual banning.

Even commenting to give the answer, giving a hint, or pointing out a duplicate or tutorial ironically probably does a similar amount of harm.

### What's the advantage of answering them?

A good answer is a good answer, even to a bad question, and makes the internet a better place.

Being helpful is good, even for questions that should be closed and deleted.

---

Side note - for questions showing no research effort, official policy is that's not a reason to close them.

Listing those advantages without a sarcastic undertone was really difficult...

My belief on what official policy is:

- Close questions that should be closed.
- Downvoting is your prerogative, but it's expected that you'll be reasonable in how you downvote, and not target users.
- It's totally up to you what you want to answer or not.

Comment: Remember that you can get the [Reversal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) gold badge for posting a +20 answer on a -5 question as well.

Comment: Dupe marking is necessary. I do not think that it's doing any harm. The thing is two people might have similar problem with different symptoms. I believe it is a nice and important feature of the system, to indicate that the underlying problem is common for them, and keep the answers in one place. Keeping two questions helps with the searching for similar problems. It also helps not to answer the question. There are some easy questions that looking for a dupe and providing a link would take longer than answering.

Comment: @luk32 Duplicate marking on decent questions is great, but on bad questions - it's positive reinforcement all the same. If we really want to shut down the low quality, we need to close, downvote and/or perhaps explicitly point out problems in their post, but **nothing else**.

Comment: @Dukeling Well I wanted to write, that plain bad dupes should probably removed, not to clutter the question-base, but I ran out of space. I decided that its do-not-answer value is a better point, it was helpful to me on a few occasions.

Comment: I answered a bad question that showed no research and got downvoted. My answer was to a very basic question from someone new to Stackoverflow. I answered their question with a direction to go in and I also gave them a short lesson on the consequences of writing bad questions and showed them what would happen if they actually had done their research. Should I delete my answer? Here is the question (could not figure out how to hyperlink): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736699/secure-input-during-runtime-afterwards/29737317#29737317

Comment: @JohnnyCoder Commenting on or discussing the quality of the question doesn't really fit in an answer (even as a side note) (that's what comments and Meta are for). Beyond that it's up to you to decide whether or not you want to delete one of your posts (and the community will share their opinion through votes and comments). If you think a question should clearly be closed and/or deleted, I'm not sure what the official policy is on answering it (but I think it's okay), although you may find yourself with some downvotes. Although the question is deleted now, so yeah...