# People are in quest of revenge...down-voting in many cases resembles execution and punishment

Tags: discussion

I have answered a question.

Three down-votes came to me.

My answer was all correct and OK, but:

one of the down-votters commented why do you answer a question which already could be read "EASILY" in the manual.

This makes me but laugh. Is it really problematic to read answer a question which stands out bold in the manual of that certain software\technology, but when some points are not simply imaginable in the mind of the questioner, how could he/she understands searching his/her way through the manual?

The questioner does not know how he/she should ask about his/her specific question, but he/she can describe his/her question all well. In my specific case, the questioner asked about how to make all my fields in SQL set to be PRIMARY KEY, I, gave the answer by telling him/her that UNIQUE key is the point and etc... but I received down-votes..

Downvoting is only acceptable, or let me say, from my point of view is acceptable, as far as it makes the environment of SO better and more efficient, but it seems these scoring system has evoked some sense of POLICISM in this site. Too bad.

Comment: OK. So, what did you want to discuss? This post doesn't invite much discussion, does it, now?

Comment: "resembles execution" ?? Bit strong don't you think?

Comment: Just look at my question, see how people reacted...isn't it similar to suppression and lack of tolerance?

Comment: There's no link to the question you're referring to. But don't take down votes personally, they're not personal digs at you.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi maybe if you change the tone of your "rant" and concentrate on putting a proper question together can improve the way the community receives you.

Comment: You don't give the link to your answer, but from your rant, it appears that perhaps it was an answer to a bad question. In this case, you should know that many people feel it is fair to downvote answers to questions that should never have been asked on StackOverflow, because (in short) the existence of these answers make the site worse. This has been discussed in e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252531#252531

Comment: dont worry dude I get like 7 upvotes and an occasional downvote on my answers and I don't cry about it... you just can't make **everyone** happy...

Comment: Look on the bright side, you got the `peer pressure` badge.

Answer (score 27):

I down voted your meta question because I feel you haven't researched or spent any time understanding why your SO answer was down voted - instead you instantly blame it on revenge.

Let's be really straight about it: nobody has to give a reason why they down voted. This policy is not going to change any time soon.

## But wait, there's more....

You ***can*** do something about it. A few down votes might be a blow to your ego but they're not the end of the world. You can go back and edit your answer into shape. Just because it was correct doesn't mean it was a **good** answer.

The person who commented that you shouldn't answer easy questions is wrong. But if you are going to answer these then you still need to provide a **quality answer** that will be useful. You can even suggest an edit to improve the quality of the question - this makes things better for the OP, you, and the site in general.

Comment: You are complicating things...did I say it is a personal blow to my ego? People are used to easily down-vote...even if I get down-votted, and exiled from questioning again, I can make a new account. Even my reputation is not too poor, it is 1k, but, wait, down-votting has become a habit. How can I make it into the mind of my answer's down-votter that the questioner cannot have a CLUE of his/her question, then how should we blame him/her for asking a question which could not be easily found in the manual by his/her understanding...

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that my question was quality because it provided the materials for the questioner step by step. Another trend in SO is that , a first down-vote always trigger still many more down-votes...

Comment: @MostafaTalebi: You claimed that downvoting resembles "execution and punishment". That sounds like a blow to your ego to me. And if you start creating multiple accounts, you may well get IP-banned - you don't want to do that.

Comment: I don't want to argue how it is possible to turn the SO around, because it is not my concern now. I talk about the trend in SO which is a very good site technically, but it has caused some strict reactions around...

Comment: The notion of punishment and suppression is the same as down-votting, with quite a lesser degree. It is the same, though.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi When people come to Meta complaining about revenge voting it's normally because their feelings have been hurt. You really need to link to the answer because without that it's hard to answer things specifically. In any case down votes are worth less than up votes, so you can still end up with positive rep gain.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi: Only if you take the votes personally. Downvotes are a *signal*, how you respond to that signal is entirely up to you.

Comment: Here is the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626616/how-to-prevent-duplicate-entry-in-mysql/24626710#24626616

Comment: I have opened a discussion but there are 4 requests for close. How do you justify that then? In here we are discussing this issue and then you might persuade me or I may in return, but there are 4 requests for close which means there are now people wanting this democratic expression to be shut-down since it does not meet their criteria of acceptance...

Comment: @MostafaTalebi You have to understand that there are probably 20 or 30 questions a week that are incredibly similar to yours, so it is a topic that has been well discussed in the past here on Meta. Additionally people are voting to close your question as *unclear what you are asking* because, well, you haven't really asked a *question*, you simply made a bunch of statements.

Comment: Looking at your answer, it is pretty poor. It's vague, assumes a particular piece of software and doesn't really mention what he needs to ultimately achieve, just points steps towards a goal in a particular database editor. You said you "still don't know", when you never asked in the first place, and PHPMyAdmin is one of many dba tools. You should have instead (like the comments on the question have done) provided an answer which explains what he needs to achieve, how he achieves that and in what tool is the OP's prerogative.

Comment: OK, my answer is poor? First I do not accept that, second, ok, for now I'm talking about the comment on my question which does not mention what you say, my concern, too, is something else, you have gone toward a wrong direction.

Comment: I didn't think you would.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi So, according to you, your answer "was all correct and OK". But looking at your answer, it says: "I still do not know if you use phpMyAdmin", and then go to explain how to do it with phpMyAdmin. How do you figure that's ok?