# How to handle answers to duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I have come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624493/how-to-import-package-in-eclipse-import-package-can-not-be-resolved/24624558), which is a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487585/import-from-another-java-project-in-eclipse). I flagged it as such and a comment got generated out of it.

Some seconds afterwards the question got **three answers**, being exact duplicated of the answer to the duplicate question.

I downvoted these answers, as I feel like they do not provide anything useful, as the OP got his answer by checking the original question.

My question is, how should we handle such cases? Flag the answers along with the question? Is there a way to prevent such answers to duplicated questions in the first place?

[possibly related.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262944/people-are-in-quest-of-revenge-down-voting-in-many-cases-resembles-execution-a)

Comment: Another way is to close and delete the question. That will eliminate the answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent such answers to duplicated questions in the first place?

Close it as a duplicate faster.  That's about all that can be done.  The ability for users with a gold badge to cast binding duplicate votes does aid in this though.

Comment: How can I directly close as duplicate? As far as i have seen I do only have the possibility to flag.

Comment: @Theolodis You need 3k reputation to vote to close.

Comment: Ok, thanks... I need to get some rep then to be able to fulfil my duty ;)

Comment: Except if the high-rep user answers the question himself and denies to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, closing the question first is all that *can* be done; that doesn't mean it always *is* done.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the answer.

A good answer should still be upvoted. A bad answer should still be downvoted / flagged.

However, if the answer is literally copied from the other question ([without attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)), downvote / flag it. That's plagiarism. ([Case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24624792/1835379))

As a guideline you could say:

**Ignore the fact the question's a duplicate, when voting on it's answers.** (With the exception of copied answers.)

Always flag as duplicate, though.

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks for the edit, that link helps clarify it :-)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that's asked (he's not asking how he should vote on answers to duplicate questions, but rather how to prevent answers posted to duplicate questions).  Having said that, the Theolodis is entirely correct in that these answers are not useful.  They are not adding value, so upvoting them is not appropriate.  It would be just the same as if these answers were posted to the canonical question.  Adding a copy of the same answer to a question (even if it's not plagiarized) is not adding value.  It's adding noise, and the votes should reflect that.

Comment: You cant plagiarize code. That would be like saying the person that plays notes on the piano is violating the piano manufacturer's copyright on the sounds produced...

Comment: @MrJack No, it's like copying someone else's song and claiming that the song is your own.  While an individual note cannot be copyrighted, a song can.

Comment: Then all answers are plagiarized from the APIs and filestructures the programs involved use. Let's just adopt your point of view and shut the whole site down since it is 95% user-generated plagiarism.