# (Semi-)automatic handling of common programming mistakes

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24674381/1313143.) about someone's jQuery code not working. If I say he tries to do something with the DOM, I bet that most of the people will already know what's wrong with it before reading the question itself.

There are probably more than 100 questions on jQuery where the problem is the same as in this question. Technically, these are all duplicates but it's very hard to indicate because the essence of the problem is "My jQuery doesn't work". That can have many other reasons.

SO intends to build a library of knowledge for programming problems and marking things as duplicate helps to query this library (e.g. via Google) so that no one needs to take time to write a custom answer to a custom question to solve something that has been solved many times before, i.e. the SO library already contains an answer.

Now, I'm not someone who knows a lot about a lot of different technologies, but I'm fairly confident that there are many similar "common problems" in various technologies and the situation I describe here probably occurs a lot more on SO.

I would like to know if there could be some sort of way to handle these situations more easily and quickly, i.e. a way to detect these kind of "duplicates" and give advice to anyone who intends to ask a question before it gets asked.

I don't yet have an idea myself but I wonder if we could approach this in a way that makes sense. If so, it would at least partially help to [increase overall question quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/1313143), since questions about these kind of obvious and general problems would occur less.

Comment: It is extremely hard to auto-detect when something is a duplicate. Take [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675444/what-is-wrong-with-how-i-am-using-in-here), which can at first glance be seen as a dupe of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125). Yet it is not, as the OP then goes on to explain they already figured that out. (The question has other problems, but serves as illustration here).

Comment: We now have the dupe hammer for such common issues. Each tag community is maintaining a list of commonly asked problems and has gold-tag-badge holders hammering such repeats into shape pretty quickly now. I don't think an automated process could improve on that without a lot of false positives.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well even I didn't know about these FAQs-per-tag. Maybe we should kind of push new users or first-time askers in a specific tag towards the tag faq before allowing them to post?

Comment: It's called *searching*, and unfortunately many posters don't. There are *numerous* points where a user is presented with possibly related posts and opportunities to search. The ones that ignore all that are also going to ignore more such lists or pointers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters While what you just said is likely true, I find the FAQ on the tag wiki **really** obscure. You just won't find it if you don't go beyond the pure Q/A part of the site. I never read tag wikis, and I'm sure that especially new users will not either. Yet, the FAQs therein are really valuable information and they need to be promoted in other parts of the site. I would say, for example, above the box that suggests similar questions when you type a question title.

Comment: A good first step would be to automatically detect and vote to close questions as duplicates. If someone gets that to work, it might be evaluated to see if it could be added as a feature. (It would be fine if it didn't catch *all* duplicates. We don't even do that now. It *would* need to have an extremely low false-positive rate, though.)