# Make the tag FAQs more obvious and prominent

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, tag-wiki

I recently asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265217/1313143) on meta for some sort of automatic handling of "common programmer mistakes".

I now realise that the sort of questions I was on about, are actually FAQ and only recently I discovered that some tags have a FAQ in their wiki.

Now, there is also the excellent suggestion: [Thwart publishing duplicate and low quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253305/1313143). The answer that provides some wizard for asking new questions that slows the process down a bit and brings possible existing answers to newcomers' attention is a very good suggestion, however I see one flaw: when it comes to searching the existing knowledge base, it only takes into account existing questions and answers, never a FAQ. The current "Ask question" page doesn't do so either.

What I really don't understand is why is the tag FAQ so damn obscure and hidden in a place where nobody ever looks, I mean I have 3k rep and have only found them last week or so. I see it as an excellent piece of information to stop users from posting new questions for problems that newbies (to a language or framework) are bound to bump into.

I suggest three improvements here, ordered by ascending "radicality":

### Give the FAQ its own tab on the tag page

> [image: Seperate tab for FAQ on a tag]

### Point newcomers in a certain tag to the FAQ

> [image: Point to the FAQ for new users]

This is actually too unobstrusive. It should be even more pushy but it would be a start. This should appear based on reputation in the tag itself, and perhaps on total rep as well. I think we can assume 2k+ rep users, for example, not to ask silly questions.

### Query it when asking a new question

> [image: FAQ when asking a new question]

**Yes this is a sloppy mockup** but it's just to show that the attention must be focused on the fact that a FAQ hit was found. Also, it would probably not be possible to query the FAQ untill a tag has been added to the question, so the message can appear at the bottom.

In any case the above screenshot just **proves** that the system does not look at the FAQ as it doesn't even suggest the question with exactly the same title.

I think with these edits in place, the flow of new questions for common problems would be reduced a little. It also makes the system actually more helpful in discovering existing information.

Comment: Tags *already* have a FAQ tab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=frequent&pageSize=50

Comment: @Servy The questions there are not the same as those on the tag wiki FAQ...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot OK fair enough then about my suggestion #1 but how about the other two?