# How many 404s are generated due to someone following a link to a deleted question?

Tags: support, statistics

Exactly how many 404s on deleted questions do users (in the using the Internet and a browser sense) find when they click a link to Stack Overflow? Since Stack Exchange logs *everything*, I presume this data can be queried?

Basically, what I want is: in the last 90 days (or whatever is more appropriate), how many users have hit a 404 (let's exclude 10kers) due to the question being deleted which:

- were deleted in the 30 days prior to the 404 (other brackets too? 90? 180?)
- were deleted in the last 30 days (90? 180?)
- were deleted by roomba, moderators or votes (maybe a break down if they were closed or not)
- I'm not sure if this is possible, but a breakdown of the referrers would be nice too.

This would give a more accurate picture about exactly how our deletion process is doing.

Comment: While they may be interesting numbers to look at, I would not use the words "breaking the Internet" - on the contrary, deleting crappy content, even if users continue to hit it and experience 404 errors, is *not* breaking the Internet, but improving or even fixing it.

Comment: You only care about users? What about the vast, vast majority of people hitting the site who don't have accounts?

Comment: @Shog9 do you have a way to remove search engines from the results? I'm only playing safe with my request, if you have a way to discriminate humans from, um, non-humans-within-a-margin-error that would be great.

Comment: I do, @Braiam. Not saying it's perfect, but should eliminate the bulk of them. Given something like 90% of page views do not have associated accounts, I suspect the skew that would result from focusing only on accounts trumps all else.

Comment: @Briam It's all transparent for me ;)

Comment: I think a more important question to ask is where those users are coming from. Deleting pages that are linked on blogs or social media is different than deleting pages users are arriving at from Google searches.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I explicitly left that out of my request (I was about to ask about referrers). I supposed the staff would be more reluctant to give the data otherwise.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The only time you'll see Google directing someone to a deleted question is when that question has been deleted in the past few minutes and Google's index hasn't quite been updated yet.

Comment: Yahoo, on the other hand, keeps deleted questions in results for *ages*.

Comment: It's very easy to find loads of posts that link to deleted content. I have a query for that...

Comment: @Laurel oh, I'm sure there are queries for that, but that query won't tell you how many people clicks through, or how many of these links are outside SO/SE.]

Comment: @Shog9 - do you really want [people that rely on Yahoo as users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252635/177800)?

Comment: @Jarrod - Sadly Yahoo is [Firefox's current default](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-your-default-search-settings-firefox) search engine.  That's as many as 7% of searchers who may not be savvy enough (yet) to use a better search engine.

Comment: @jwd630 - or a better browser?

Comment: @jwd630 interesting, I installed Firefox on a new system (almost immediately booting up) and it came with google as default...

Comment: @Shog9 now, talking with my pillow, it suggested the idea of having both, users with associated accounts and those that don't have.

Comment: @jwd630 What? The page you link to doesn't say that Yahoo is the current default search engine, only that it is *one of the possible choices that are built-in*, exactly like Google, bing, DuckDuckGo and others. On my pc the default is Google and I believe I've always seen Google as actual default.

Comment: @Bakuriu [This announcement](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2014/11/19/promoting-choice-and-innovation-on-the-web/) and [this](http://searchengineland.com/yahoo-becomes-default-search-engine-firefox-browser-209267) or googling for Firefox default search engine says otherwise - US only however. On my Mac I have several times had to [re-choose Google](http://searchengineland.com/google-is-practically-begging-firefox-users-to-switch-their-default-search-engine-216770) over the lame Yahoo. YMMV.

Comment: I think it's a safe bet that neither Braiam nor Bakuriu are in the US, @jwd630. That said, Yahoo Search hits are a tiny minority of traffic here... Less a minority of 404s. I'll post some stats as I'm able.

Comment: What is this "roomba" you speak of?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's a daily run automatic script, which keeps the site clean(er), it deletes abandoned posts, reverts serial votings etc.

Comment: @Shog9 are you busy now?