# Understanding unexplained upvotes in posts

Tags: discussion, voting

This might come off as rant, and I will understand if the community feels like it is so. However, I'm truly intrigued about why I'm seeing every time more unexplained upvotes in cr*p posts.
It could be coincidence, but I really didn't see this happening before the welcoming stuff started - but don't take me wrong, I did have a pretty hard beginning.

Let's take this very recent example with 2 upvotes regardless of the 5 downvotes:

> I have a simple class with a just two methods:
>
> ```
> some code
> ```
>
> When I am trying to Build I am getting an error: 'SomeType.DoWork()': not all code paths return a value'.
>
> I understand method DoWork should return string type, but I'm calling
>   the method Working which returns string, so why it happeining?

Regardless of the grammar mistakes which could be easily fixed, this is truly a beginner question by someone who hasn't taken the time to learn the basics of the language. So, I left this comment, trying to be as helpful as possible, and VTC'ed as Too Broad:

> This is really too broad for Stack Overflow as we cannot teach you the basics of programming. Please do take the time to follow the *official getting started guide for c#* (link). There are also very good books that you can find in the tag's documentation here in Stack Overflow

I guess my question is, should we accept and answer those beginner questions?

Comment: Mandatory: beginner questions aren't the problem. Poorly researched questions are. Just so happens that poorly researched questions ask about basics.  But IMHO no, these shouldn't be upvoted... As to why they are? Sympathy from other newer users who don't get the quality system of Stack I'd guess

Comment: Beginner questions usually have a duplicate, although sometimes a comment expanding on how the duplicate applies is helpful.

Comment: @DavyM You are right, I've removed that part. I've seen comments that suggested that before from that user, though

Comment: That question currently sits at -4, not exactly upvoted too much.  The OP is not a newbie, has had his account for over 3 years.  Somebody posted a comment that suggested it was too hard to answer because it required teaching programming basics.  Somebody else posted a short answer that quickly solved the OP's problem.  It didn't seem hard at all.  Maybe the commenter is getting bored with the grind, lots of SO contributors peter out past 10K rep.

Comment: @HansPassant My question is not specifically about that post, but rather the behavior towards such posts. I could have answered that in seconds, that's not the point

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: "*I guess my question is, should we accept and answer those beginner questions?*" What does that have to do with "unexplained upvotes"? Which question do you want answered?

Comment: @NicolBolas I tend to upvote questions I answer. I normally don't take the time to answer questions I don't find useful. I guess that's just me though

Comment: This has been talked about before in the form of: [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Please enjoy my unexplained upvote.

Comment: *Too broad* is a ludicrous close reason for [the question being discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52617218/1709587). It's comprehensively answered in 3 sentences in the accepted answer, and could be more or less adequately answered by just saying *"You missed out `return` before the `Working()` call."* Whatever its flaws, a question that can be answered in 8 words is not "too broad" by any sane definition.

Comment: It was absolutely happening before the blog post.

Comment: @MarkAmery So we are teaching programming fundamentals now...? That's exactly my question

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto We have always taught fundamentals. A lot of questions were closed as 'lacks minimal understanding' in the past, but there are a ton of popular questions from 08 and 09 (even well into the teens) about quite rudimentary things across almost all programming languages. Eventually the 'lacks minimal understanding' close reason was removed because it was not a very smart reason to close questions. People come here to help with programming, so we should help them with programming, provided their question is specific, objectively answerable, reproducible, not a duplicate, etc.

Comment: I think probably the real problem here is that the early misconceptions of a programmer are rather unpredictable, e.g., when I first started in programming I thought more or less that a multiprocessor system ran every line in parallel unless a function "declared" itself as an uh... locking function? Personally I find these misconceptions kind of interesting. I'd agree that it might be unlikely to help future users (and there's no way to reword it, probably no "real" duplicate either), but on the other hand I don't really see anything terribly wrong or unanswerable about it either.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A score of 1 is the new 0.

When I encounter a question that does not appear to be researched at all (*"This is my code, this is my error, help"*), I downvote.

The Google query `"not all code paths return a value" site:stackoverflow.com` returns about 2000 hits. Given the duplicate indexing problem still is not solved (pages linking to answers are still lacking a canonical URI to the question page, causing duplicate content in Google), there are at least a thousand potential duplicates.

But no. People read a question that's not entirely unintelligible, that contains some code and some non-code text, and they upvote. That's fine and all, everyone can vote as they please, so just keep downvoting when you see a question that you think deserves a downvote.

And don't bother to explain your downvote, lest you become the target of revenge flagging or voting.

Comment: I agree. No one should ever comment on anything ever.

Comment: @TinyGiant How dare you comment? /s

Comment: Though I understand it, this sort of cynicism isn't a sign of a healthy community, and as someone who still remains a true believer in the Stack Overflow model, it saddens me to see it. I just want to note, publicly, that I have commented on many hundreds of my downvotes and rarely received revenge downvotes for it. I encourage others to do the same. If some thin-skinned loser decides to revenge downvote over it from time to time, screw 'em.

Comment: @usr2564301 I have a strong suspicion that a lot of the crap questions that get answers are up-voted by the people answering them. This is probably in an attempt to attract more eyeballs willing to up-vote the answer.

Comment: @Comintern We also can't ever rule out the pervasive habit of getting a coworker or office group to upvote stuff you ask on SO. This is voting fraud and against the rules, but it's impossible to catch every instance of it, especially in cases where someone might ask questions infrequently.

Answer (score 18):

I can imagine many, many reasons.

Off the top of my head (from best to worst):

- Someone actually thinks it's a useful and clear question
- Missclick/lost keys/keyboard malfunction with hotkeys enabled
- Gotta get that [electorate badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate), don't care on what I vote (there are [users that got that badge within 2 weeks](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/906451/fastest-electorate-badge-in-the-west)!)
- Pity upvote/beginners deserve encouragement/question has too many downvotes
- Masking voting ring activity by voting a lot

Since, like downvotes, upvotes don't require justification, we can only speculate.

Comment: Electorate badge should only count 1 vote per day. =)

Answer (score -11):

Yes, we should accept and answer those questions, because this is a Q&A forum.  Rather than telling people that their questions are garbage, we could allow newer helpful people who want to earn reputation the opportunity to answer these questions.  Then, rather than flagging bad posts, the awesome helpful moderators can spend their time flagging awesome posts to be included in the bible or canon and to persist into potential permanence.  And the low-quality questions with their low-quality answers can be automatically deleted over time as they are shown to be not useful (i.e. low page hits).

Comment: Try as you may, you'll never stop my legions of noobs.

Answer (score -12):

How about a new feature like a flag popup radio button form? An optional anonymous `I upvoted/downvoted this answer as ...` radio button form or something like that.

There is no need to explain votes, of course. But let's be honest; We all been there. A little guidance encourages questioners to google more or to refine their question as instructed.

Comment: This has been [suggested and shot down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) a lot already.

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh, thank you.

Comment: @Cerbrus To be fair, the question you linked wanted feedback to be mandatory not optional, and did not mention anything about said comments being anonymous.  Most of the answer's points are not relevant when you change those two conditions.  I know that optional, anonymous comments when downvoting have been brought up as an idea before as well, but I don't recall any particularly convincing arguments against them - or at the very least, not any that were convincing to me.

Answer (score -16):

Just because it's Googleable and involves basics, doesn't mean it's not a good, answerable, question.

The most likely result is "there's already a duplicate", but if there is not, go ahead and answer it. StackOverflow is supposed to have all the answers, after all.

Perhaps the upvotes happen as a reaction to the downvotes, since there's no good reason to downvote past -1. That's the kind of thing that *actually* gets perceived as "not nice", not all the nonsense we're supposed to look out for.

Comment: There's no good reason to downvote past -1? How is that different than "there's no good reason to upvote past 1"? If piling on downvotes is a problem, a better solution would be to "mercy close" them as "poorly received" when they hit a vote total of -5 or something like that.