# +10k users are supposed to guide the community

Tags: discussion, help-center

With this post in mind:

- [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252531#252531)

---

Here we try to build a really great QA, where the [10k privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says

> As one of our most experienced users, we're counting on you to guide the community and lead by example.

Then we have a +10k user answering this type of question:

- [Center-align divs so that middle one is centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285675/center-align-divs-so-that-middle-one-is-centered)

And answering me commenting it with *"don't worry, I'm ok with it. you're right with the first comment, but this was too much intriguing to me, sorry :)"*

This user is not the first, though now I decided to ask the community.

Given that *"users posting questions are supposed to make a proper research and an effort of their own"*, is this really how we want it to be?

Comment: I think the "I'm ok with it" part refers to the downvote.

Comment: @StoryTeller -- Well, given I didn't downvote, how could it?

Comment: That the answerer is okay with getting downvotes in general, so even if it had been you, don't worry about it. And I did read the comment thread fully, how else would I know about the downvote related comment.

Comment: @StoryTeller I am not worried ... and if you read the comment fully, you'll see it is not about downvoting, it is about answering a poorly formatted question, _"don't worry, I'm ok with it. you're right with the first comment, but this was too much intriguing to me, sorry"_. where my first comment is about answering such question

Comment: Again, I read things fully. I think the lack of understanding of the other person's comments does not lie with me. Is it at all possible you color their response based on your own pre-conception of them as a "low quality answerer"?

Comment: Also, you posted two comments in quick succession. The other person *could* have been responding to both at once.

Comment: Why don't you just ping the person and make them aware of this meta post so they can tell you what they meant instead of having two different people speculate over what a specific phrase was meant to refer to?

Comment: @StoryTeller -- Again, answerer writes _"you're right with the first comment, but this was too much intriguing to me, sorry"_ ... how is that not about answering low quality question?

Comment: Well, *that bit* is. The "don't worry about it" part, I suspect isn't.

Comment: @ivarni -- I was about to...and did

Comment: @StoryTeller And as _that bit is_ and as I here ask about that part, your comments make it to look like I missed that.

Comment: What specifically do you think is wrong with the question?

Comment: I didn't understand what is the problem here

Comment: @HåkenLid That _""users posting questions are supposed to make a proper research and an effort of their own""_ ..which they clearly didn't

Comment: Wasn't there a policy against calling people out publicly? You also have +10K

Comment: No, your own question makes it look like it's about the "don't worry, I'm ok with it." part, because that's what it says explicitly.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I'm the guy who answered: I confirm that part where I'm ok is the part about downvoting, because justification from you was not needed nor I've requested it.

And just to clarify: if that question was so low quality why not even LGSon voted to close it? what's the point to patronize me instead of voting to close the question and just flag my answer?

Comment: @Kaiido Ahh, sorry, wasn't aware there were. So how to then, when +10k users, IMHO, go beyond what I think is wrong?

Comment: @fcalderan -- I was looking for the dupe ... which I now found. Still, how does that justify to answer low quality questions. I think it doesn't. And for what reason do we have policies, if not to follow?

Comment: So before posting this question on meta you searched for a duplicate about answering low quality questions, right?

Comment: @fcalderan -- No, first I posted at meta, then looked for a question dupe on the one you answered....it has been answered many times, not always easy to find though, and then I got caught here for a while, answering comments – LGSon 5 mins ago

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to get into an infinite discussion: 1) you say it's a low quality question but you didn't vote to close it; 2) you say then there's a dupe but someone told you it's not a good example 3) you posted on meta a question that - with good probability - must have several dupes. In all this you patronized me telling to "reread what SO is all about". Now, I'm a kind person and if my first comment made you angry for a misunderstood I'm sorry, as I already explained above. I'm here to help and if I see a question _objectively_ low quality I vote to close it (or I help the OP)

Comment: @fcalderan -- first off, I am not angry, will never be for anything here at SO .... 1) i did voted to close, posted here at meta first though 2) there is a dupe, cover all needed, using grid too, and all works just fine, and the one saying it is not, obviously missed that the answerer is the highest ranked user on flex/grid  3) if I would have found a meta dupe I wouldn't posted mine ... so me having an opinion is "patronizing"...

Comment: @LGSon I understand what you are trying to say, I didn't complain about your message. My remark was about your way of telling it. You could and should have made your point without calling out anybody. We don't need that post to understand your point. "I often face high-rep users answering low quality questions. How should we handle it if at all?". Point is made, we all see such behavior, sometimes even behave like this in others' eyes because we've all got different thresholds.

Answer (score 10):

**It's all subjective.**

The question certainly isn't stellar, but it is at least clear, answerable, well-defined and presents a problem that is potentially *useful* to others. There are far worse questions out there - it's not just a non-formatted "homework dump".

Some would say that *any* question should be answered if it can be, regardless of the effort put into it or its complexity, and we should lead by example in answering those questions and welcoming novices instead of just dismissing them.

Others would say that *no* question should be answered unless a SSCCE is provided (or whatever we're meant to be calling it these days, I get bored of these acronym battles) and the problem is complex enough that it could reasonably be encountered by a professional developer, so we should lead by example in *not* answering those questions.

Others think that leading by example simply means ensuring the quality of one's posts are of a high standard, and has no bearing on answering good / bad questions whatsoever.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am not talking about the quality _level_, or whether it is _answerable_, as that for sure is subjective, I am talking about _posters showing an effort of their own_, and that is not subjective, either one did, or one didn't.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not about to **not** answer such questions, it is about having the poster following a few simple rules ([ask]), and when not, ask them to, and if such posts still gets answered, they never will as they got what they came for. Also, in this case the used code is needed, as based on its limitations, or requirements, decide which solutions are available. And again, unknown in this case.

Comment: @LGSon Eh? "Posters showing an effort of their own" is just as subjective as posters asking a quality question, if not more so. Whether a poster has followed those simple rules, is again, subjective (tag relevancy is subjective, good titles are subjective, etc.)

Comment: Either you try to see what I am trying to say, or your don't. And if it is about code, code is needed, or no?

Comment: And we now can see the effect at the question...when the answers fail after a question edit (which is wrong in itself) + several clarification comments, but proves my point when it comes to provide a reasonable quality.

Comment: Are you then saying to not work towards this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252531#252531