# Have you noticed a shocking decline in question quality the last year or two?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if I am just growing exhausted, but it seems to me like the quality of questions has dramatically decreased in the last year or so.

I assume this is because as Stack Overflow's backlog of answered questions grows larger and larger, it becomes more likely that people that understand Stack Overflow will have found the answer they were searching for, and those that don't will ask poorly formatted and unwelcome questions.

What do you think? What can we do about it?

Comment: It's a known "phenomenon". For example [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506) It's also not unique to [main] (and I don't mean other sites in the "umbrella", I mean other completely unaffiliated sites).

Comment: I have noticed poor question quality over the past 13 years and I have had an account only for 9 years.

Comment: Could be Eternal September, could be the moderator exodus due to the 2019 events, could be survivorship bias, could be the fact that documentation got better over the years and every recent question could be downvoted due to lack of research. Other than that, question quality was never really great (on average, at least).

Comment: What happened in 2019? @SebastianSimon

Comment: I think survivorship bias is huge on this one. People often talk about question quality only looking at the newest questions, but the amount of rubbish we have deleted over the years is astonishing.

Comment: @Laif [Summing up the main issues (The Story So Far)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/334399/289905)

Comment: Survivorship bias definitely has an impact when observing from the outside, I was moreso speaking from my personal experience moderating ans answering questions as they come in, I feel like the sheer quantity of garbage is so much greater than it used to be

Comment: Let's adjust this a little :) the amount of *everything* keeps growing, subsequently the number of litter keeps growing too. It is not really *that* different from before - just on a larger scale. And, depending on the tags you frequent, you might get an impression that SO is a heaven on Earth, or a literal hellscape.

Comment: To expand on what @OlegValter already said - not only are there more posts, you might also just be seeing more of them because nowadays you spend more time on SO doing curation. If you go from seeing 50 posts a day to 100 posts a day it might seem like there are more bad ones. Even if *proportionally* they are the same as before. The sheer *amount* you experience first-hand will increase.

Comment: No, it's been low for far longer than that, nothing shocking about it really. It also depends on when you look, when a new school year has just started there is a direct influx of "I'm a student and schools don't work with books anymore" questions.

Comment: Sturgeon's Revelation: 90% of everything is crud. Most of the content we see here will be useless, and while the percentage of good vs bad content probably hasn't changed much, there's a lot more content.