# How should I flag an answer ... [follow up]

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

Lately I read lots of posts on Meta regarding falling quality of posts and review process and yesterday I found interesting one, that was bugging me for some time [How should I flag an answer that CLEARLY doesn't even remotely relate to the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254558/how-should-i-flag-an-answer-that-clearly-doesnt-even-remotely-relate-to-the-que/254559#comment19823_254559) where general consensus is to flag it as "very low quality" which then, if I understand well, goes into low quality queue to be voted by community.

Followed the advice and flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554649/listbox-display-manipulation-highlight-first-3-itemsnot-selected-row/22554900#22554900) answer which in my eyes is poor quality because firstly question is *How to highlight first 3 items in ListBox* and answer is *highlight the three top elements in some way* and second, question is tagged WPF and provided link is for Winforms. This answer somehow got one up-vote. There is also [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554649/listbox-display-manipulation-highlight-first-3-itemsnot-selected-row/22555013#22555013) answer against same question this time for ASP.NET, by user who provided 3 answers to this question, which also somehow got up-voted.

First answer "very low quality" flag has been disputed by community, even though there is a comment with 3 up-votes explaining what's the problem.

So finally my questions are:

1. Am I getting it completely wrong and it's a valid answer?
2. If not then is "very low quality" flag still a way to go for such answers as the only flag that allows to give some short description is "Other" flag?
3. Can something still be done with such answer? For example flag same answer with "Other" flag

Comment: Downvote, leave a comment (for others to read) and move on.

Comment: So don't flag it at all or flag it, down-vote, leave a comment and move on? Was flagging it justified or I get it wrong?

Comment: I won't usually flag it unless there is a good reason.  I'd flag something that (1) doesn't _attempt_ to answer the problem, (2) when the OP acknowledges that the _answer_ doesn't answer the problem, (3) it is spam or inappropriate otherwise.

Comment: Somewhat related to the second point in the comment above: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252404/should-answers-that-do-not-answer-a-question-be-preserved

Comment: Isn't it good enough reason to flag it as low quality if the answer basically says _don't know about WPF but in ASP.NET/WinForm I would do ..._. Both answers have comments explaining what's wrong, acknowledged by users, yet they did not decide to remove the answer

Comment: Bluefeet's comment sums it up.  It's the community that causes such answers to hang around.  People refrain from removing incorrect answers that have somehow accumulated upvotes.  That said, I'm not sure how much moderators would approve of flagging a technically incorrect answer.  The only way out is to have such answers downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: Perhaps the attitude of the answerer had something to do. He geniously seems interested in the community, and maybe having his answer removed may put him off.

Comment: @Davidmh, definitely he's interested and tried to guide him, and other user, to write good WPF answer. It's an answer and maybe even valid ASP.NET answer just not answer to this particular question but now I kind of understand why flag has been disputed since I did fair share of Low Quality Reviews myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your [first example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22554900/109702), it's definitely an answer. It's not a *quality* answer, but it's still an answer. What should you do with it? That's largely up to you - personally I wouldn't flag it as VLQ unless it was blatantly so and needed some attention from the community to get rid of it. Mostly I would down vote it, or edit it if it could be done easily enough.

Your [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22555013/109702) is also not of high quality but is still an answer. Same thing goes.

> ...the only flag that allows to give some short description is "Other" flag?

Don't use this - it is for ♦ moderator attention, and moderators are not adjudicators of technical accuracy, and quality of this nature is a community problem.

Just remember that flagging as VLQ or leaving a comment are kind of like a fishing trip - there's no guarantee you will get the response you want. Voting will tend to provoke a response when someone notices their rep decreasing (if they know how to edit), and editing the answer into shape (if applicable) will get you the most instant result.

Comment: How does it go in line with all the posts about keeping the site clean and answer provided by moderator to the question that I quoted _"Flag using a Custom "Other" flag - explain what seems suspicious about the answer including that is isn't an answer and it has unusual upvotes for such a low-quality answer."_? Agree that it is an answer of sort but none of these 2 answers solve the problem and they've been up-voted. Both of these answers might as well be about something else as they do not relate to the question

Comment: @dkozl There are no suspicious votes on these answers - moderator flags are for exceptional things, not stuff that should be handled by the community (BTW I am a mod on another site). Even if they did have one or two up votes I wouldn't consider it *suspicious* - incorrect stuff often gets an up vote or two, some people don't know the difference.

Comment: Yes _incorrect stuff often gets an up vote or two, some people don't know the difference_ but is it good enough reason to leave the answer that does not bring anything to the question? I did not say it's suspicious and it's nothing against user, one of them got accepted on another answer, but the answers they've provided which might as well be gibberish. In what way answer _"in ASP.NET I would ..."_  or _highlight the three top elements in some way_ is different then the one provided in question that I quoted.

Comment: So should I flag it as "very low quality" (and hope it will be voted helpful) or not? If not what quality does either answer bring to the question? I am penalized for number of disputed flags as it influences number of flags that I can use so, from my point of view, it's better not to get involved in the review process and don't flag anything.

Comment: @dkozl Answer quality should be handled by the community unless it is an exceptional problem. As an individual you can vote, edit or flag as VLQ. Flagging as VLQ or commenting are not guaranteed to get the response you want but will usually work. Just to be clear, it's because it is a community response that there is no guarantee - others may disagree with you.

Comment: I understand that flagging as VLQ puts it into low quality queue therefore in the hands of the community and sometimes it will be disputed even though I may disagree. I have no problem with that but I'm just looking for an answer to question: Is it considered as VLQ answer, but it just did not work in this case, or not and if not then what quality does it bring to the question?